# Como usar o valor atual de uma variável numa função mais interna?

Tags: javascript, variáveis, escopo-de-variáveis

O seguinte código "imprime" 50 vezes o texto "Mensagem 50" em um `textarea`.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        textArea.value += 'Mensagem ' + i + '\n';
        textArea.scrollTop = textArea.scrollHeight;
    }, 100 * i);
}
```

Veja o exemplo no [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dK2r6/).

Eu entendo que isso ocorre porque o valor de `i` é atualizado na função externa e, no momento da execução da função interna, a referência aponta para o valor atualizado.

Como fazer para imprimir o valor da variável `i` correspondente ao número da iteração? Ou seja, o valor de `i` no momento em que a função interna foi criada na chamado do `setTimeout`, resultando em textos de "Mensagem 0" a "Mensagem 49"

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Nota:**

Na versão moderna de JavaScript (a partir de ES6) este problema já não acontece se usarmos `let` no `for (let i = 0; ...`

[Mais sobre let, cont e var aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/206121/129).

---

### Resposta ao código da pergunta:

O problema no código da pergunta é que o ciclo `for` fica pronto antes de a função `setTimeout()` correr, assim o valor de `i` já é 50 antes do código `textArea.value += 'Mensagem ' + i + '\n';` ser corrido.

Chamando o `setTimeout()` via função extena ao ciclo loop, então o valor de `i` que é passado como parametro é o valor de cada iteração.

**Pode usar assim:**

```
var textArea = document.getElementById('a');
var tempo = function (pTempo) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        textArea.value += 'Mensagem ' + pTempo+ '\n';
        textArea.scrollTop = textArea.scrollHeight;
    }, 100 * pTempo);

}
for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    tempo(i);
}
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/Yw5Mz/)

---

**Outra opção**, parecida, mas em vez de ter uma função externa, usando uma função que se auto-executa dentro do ciclo `for`, e que captura o valor de `i`:

```
var textArea = document.getElementById('a');
for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    (function () {
        var iScoped = i;
        setTimeout(function () {
            textArea.value += 'Mensagem ' + iScoped + '\n';
            textArea.scrollTop = textArea.scrollHeight;
        }, 100 * iScoped );
    })()
}
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/3E2hZ/)

---

**Existe ainda outra maneira,** uma vez que a função `setTimeout()` aceita um terceiro parâmetro para dentro da função.

> var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(func, delay, [param1, param2, ...]);
>
> *Exemplo:*
> **setTimeout**(function(**parametro**){ /* codigo */ }, tempo, **parametro** );

Fonte: [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) <sup>Inglês</sup>

```
var textArea = document.getElementById('a');
for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    setTimeout(function(i) {
        textArea.value += 'Mensagem ' + i + '\n';
        textArea.scrollTop = textArea.scrollHeight;
    }, 100 * i, i);
}
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/gphqJ/)

Comment: Obrigado, Segio. A primeira solução parece ser a mais limpa, embora eu tenha que escrever mais código. O segundo exemplo era um no qual eu havia pensado de forma [ligeiramente diferente](http://jsfiddle.net/kQ2Ys/). O terceiro parece que tem problemas com IE 8 e anteriores.

Comment: Resposta do tipo "compre 1 leve 3".

Comment: @utluiz, :) - Sim, concordo que a primeira é a melhor. Na primeira solução pode ser melhor usar um outro nome de variável como parametro da função, para o caso de haver algum i defenido no mesmo escopo. Corrigi agora a resposta tambem.

Answer (score 12):

O nome do conceito que está te causando confusão é ***closure*** (["clausura"](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausura_%28ci%C3%AAncia_da_computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o%29) em português, mas esse termo é raramente utilizado), e se refere à forma como funções definidas dentro de um "contexto léxico" (i.e. o corpo de uma função, um bloco, um arquivo fonte) acessam variáveis definidas nesse contexto.

Em JavaScript, apenas funções definem um novo contexto léxico (outras linguagens têm regras diferentes - algumas sequer suportam o conceito de *closure*):

```
var a = 10; // Mesmo "a" para script1.js, script2.js, etc (efetivamente, uma global)
function f() {
    var b = 20; // Um "b" diferente para cada invocação de f
    if ( x ) {
        var c = 30; // Mesmo "c" dentro e fora do if (i.e. o contexto é "f", não o bloco if)
```

E cada novo contexto criado dentro (*inner*) de um contexto já existente tem acesso a todas as variáveis definidas no "de fora" (*outer*):

```
function x(a1) {          // "x" tem acesso a "a"
    var a2;
    function y(b1) {      // "y" tem acesso a "a" e "b"
        var b2;
        function z(c1) {  // "z" tem acesso a "a", "b", e "c"
            var c2;
```

É importante observar que não importa **quando** a função interna irá executar, nem qual o valor as variáveis externas tinham no momento em que **o objeto** função foi criado (em contraste com a definição da função, que é em tempo de compilação/interpretação). O que importa é que ambas compartilham a mesma variável, e escritas de um lado refletirão nas leituras do outro e vice-versa.

No seu caso, você está criando uma nova função (anônima) dentro do contexto léxico do código externo (outra função? corpo do script?), e ela compartilha **a variável** `i` (e não **o valor** de `i`). No momento que essa função é executada, o laço `for` já alterou seu valor várias vezes, levando-a ao seu valor máximo (`50`) e é isso que a função interna vai acessar. Se o código externo modificasse ou reutilizasse `i` para outros propósitos, isso também se refletiria na função interna (e da mesma forma, se um dos objetos-função alterasse esse `i` isso interferiria nos outros também).

Existem várias maneiras de se modificar o código para se atingir o comportamento desejado (i.e. um `i` diferente para cada objeto-função) - como já apontado por @Sergio - mas a minha preferida é aquela que torna a natureza do *closure* mais explícita (ainda que pareça visualmente "estranha" para quem não está familiarizado com o conceito):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            textArea.value += 'Mensagem ' + i + '\n';
            textArea.scrollTop = textArea.scrollHeight;
        }, 100 * i);
    })(i);
}
```

Note que o `i` argumento da função anônima não é o mesmo `i` passado como parâmetro para a mesma - uma vez que estão em contextos léxicos diferentes. Também cabe ressaltar que a variável `textArea` ainda está vindo do contexto externo, e dependendo do caso pode ser interessante incluí-la no *closure* também:

```
    (function(i, textArea) { ... })(i, textArea);
```

Isso garante que - ainda que essa variável tenha seu valor alterado (i.e. aponte para um elemento diferente) - a função interna ainda tenha acesso ao valor que ela tinha no momento em que o loop foi executado.

Comment: Seria bom ressaltar o `return` para retornar uma definição de função para o setTimeout

Comment: @Victor Desculpe, não entendi... Você está se referindo ao fato de que o que é passado pro `setTimeout` não é a primeira função [a que recebe parâmetro], mas sim aquela que é retornada por sua invocação? Isso está correto - ainda que nesse caso particular tenha ficado um pouco estranho. Aliás, vou reescrever essa função para ficar mais de acordo com a ideia que eu queria passar.

Comment: Sim, está correto mesmo! Só ressaltei o fato de não ser algo simples e esclarecer um pouco mais para os iniciantes esse fato e explicar melhor. Principalmente para o fato de que `setTimeout` recebe uma **definição** de função.

Answer (score 6):

## Com JavaScript moderno (ES-2015+)

As outras respostas continuam válidas, mas hoje em dia temos uma solução padrão para isso com JavaScript moderno, utilizando [variáveis com escopo de bloco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47165/qual-%c3%a9-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-declara%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-vari%c3%a1veis-usando-let-e-var) declaradas com `let`. Você deve usar esta solução se:

- Estiver rodando o código em Node.js; ou
- Estiver utilizando JavaScript transpilado (com Babel, provavelmente); ou
- Estiver satisfeito com a [compatibilidade atual dos browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=let)

Com variáveis com escopo de bloco, cada iteração do loop irá criar uma nova variável, capturada pela *closure* passada à função assíncrona. O código da pergunta passa a funcionar simplesmente substituindo `var`  por `let`:

```js
const textArea = document.querySelector('textarea');

for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        textArea.value += 'Mensagem ' + i + '\n';
        textArea.scrollTop = textArea.scrollHeight;
    }, 100 * i);
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: Acho interessante adicionar esse link a resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47165/qual-%c3%a9-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-declara%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-vari%c3%a1veis-usando-let-e-var, o que acha?

Comment: Um ano depois... @Costamilam

Comment: Antes ou tarde do que nunca :)