# Como funcionam Closures em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, closures

Sempre quis saber como funcionam Closures em JavaScript, já li algumas definições mas nunca entendi muito bem.

Vocês poderiam me dar uma explicação simples, objetiva mas com conteúdo?

Comment: FWIW um artigo meu a respeito: http://epx.com.br/artigos/closure.php

Answer (score 85):

***Closure*** (["clausura"](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausura_%28ci%C3%AAncia_da_computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o%29) em português, mas esse termo é raramente utilizado), se refere à forma como funções definidas dentro de um "contexto léxico" (i.e. o corpo de uma função, um bloco, um arquivo fonte) acessam variáveis definidas nesse contexto.

Em JavaScript, apenas funções definem um novo contexto léxico (outras linguagens têm regras diferentes - algumas sequer suportam o conceito de *closure*):

```js
var a = 10; // Mesmo "a" para script1.js, script2.js, etc (efetivamente, uma global)
function f() {
    var b = 20; // Um "b" diferente para cada invocação de f
    if ( x ) {
        var c = 30; // Mesmo "c" dentro e fora do if (i.e. o contexto é "f", não o bloco if)
```

E cada novo contexto criado dentro (*inner*) de um contexto já existente tem acesso a todas as variáveis definidas no "de fora" (*outer*):

```js
function x(a1) {          // "x" tem acesso a "a"
    var a2;
    function y(b1) {      // "y" tem acesso a "a" e "b"
        var b2;
        function z(c1) {  // "z" tem acesso a "a", "b", e "c"
            var c2;
```

É importante observar que não importa **quando** a função interna irá executar, nem qual o valor as variáveis externas tinham no momento em que **o objeto** função foi criado (em contraste com a definição da função, que é em tempo de compilação/interpretação). O que importa é que ambas compartilham a mesma variável, e escritas de um lado refletirão nas leituras do outro e vice-versa.

### *Pitfalls*

Um exemplo de erro comum envolvendo *closures* é a criação de uma função dentro de um bloco *for*:

```js
for ( var i = 0 ; i < elementos.length ; i++ ) {
    elementos[i].onclick = function() {
        alert("Esse é o elemento " + i);
    }
}
```

Esse código não funciona como esperado, uma vez que a variável `i` utilizada pela função anônima é o mesmo `i` do contexto externo - o que significa que quando o `i` externo muda, o valor que a função interna vai acessar é diferente. No final, `i` será igual a `elementos.length` (ex.: `10`), de modo que clicar em qualquer elemento sempre imprimirá "Esse é o elemento 10".

Uma possível solução para esse problema é a criação de um novo contexto léxico que "capture" o valor daquela variável no momento desejado:

```js
for ( var i = 0 ; i < elementos.length ; i++ )
    (function(i) {
        elementos[i].onclick = function() {
            alert("Esse é o elemento " + i);
        }
    })(i);
```

Dessa forma, o `i` parâmetro da função não é o mesmo `i` usado pelo laço `for` - e ele possui **o valor** que a variável tinha **no momento da execução**.

### Utilidade

Existem muitas vantagens em se usar *closures*, como exemplificado [na resposta do @Jordão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1859/como-funcionam-closures-em-javascript/1860#1860) (que demonstra um meio de se implementar [*currying*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying)). Um outro exemplo seria simular variáveis privadas - algo que não é normalmente suportado pela linguagem JavaScript:

```js
function MeuObjeto() {
    this.publico = { ... }
    var privado = { ... }
    this.foo = function() {
        return privado.a;
    }
    this.bar = function(x) {
        privado.a = x;
    }
    ...
}
var obj = new MeuObjeto();
obj.publico; // Acessível
obj.privado; // undefined
```

Note que, como não existe nenhuma referência direta para `privado`, esse objeto não pode ser manipulado diretamente (apenas indiretamente por meio de `foo` e `bar`). Mas como `foo` e `bar` foram criados dentro do contexto léxico do construtor, elas têm acesso às variáveis locals do mesmo, podendo acessá-las normalmente.

Um outro exemplo "clássico" é o ***Accumulator Generator***, citado [num artigo](http://www.paulgraham.com/icad.html) do Paul Graham (em inglês) onde se discute o poder de expressividade relativa das diversas linguagens de programação. O requisito é simples:

> Escreva uma função `foo` que recebe um número `n` e retorna uma função que recebe um número `i`, e retorna `n` incrementado de `i`.
>
> Nota: (a) [o argumento] é um número, não um inteiro. (b) é **incrementado de**, não **mais**.

A solução proposta, com exemplos de uso:

```
function foo (n) { 
    return function (i) { 
        return n += i;
    } 
}

var x = foo(10);
x(2); // 12
x(3); // 15

var y = foo(20);
y(5); // 25
y(2); // 27
```

Como os exemplos no final do artigo mostram, linguagens que não suportam *closures* acabam sendo muito mais varbosas (exigindo muito código para se fazer pouco), de modo que demoram mais para serem escritas, lidas, podem conter mais bugs (já que a probabilidade de bugs aumenta com a quantidade de linha de código), etc.

---

<sub>Nota: Incluí aqui parte de [uma resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1237/como-usar-o-valor-atual-de-uma-variavel-numa-funcao-mais-interna/1239#1239) que dei para uma pergunta semelhante (a pergunta não era sobre *closures*, mas a causa raiz do problema era), adaptando para a resposta ficar mais genérica.</sub>

Comment: /* Mesmo "a" para script1.js, script2.js, etc (efetivamente, uma global)*/ Dexa ver se eu entendi, quer dizer que se eu declarar uma variável : var a = "Globlal"; e salvar esse arquivo como meuscript.js e posteriormente eu tiver um arquivo script1.js, essa variável será acessível pelo arquivo script1.js, mesmo estando localizada no arquivo meuscript.js? pls preciso entender...

Comment: @MagicHat Sim. Se ambos os scripts forem incluídos na mesma página, o `script1.js` poderá acessar a variável `a` definida pelo `meuscript.js` normalmente (assumindo que ela foi definida no *top-level*, como no exemplo). É por isso que muitas bibliotecas - tipo o jQuery - colocam o script inteiro dentro de um `(function() { ... })();`, para não criar variáveis globais sem necessidade (ou pior, quando as globais de um script sobrescrevem as globais de outro script).

Comment: Vlw man...Vou ficar atento..

Comment: @mgibsonbr esse ap está off line desde 2014, sendo assim a pergunta fica sem uma resposta aceita para sempre?

Comment: @durtto sim, fica.

Answer (score 53):

"Closures" (algo como "fechamento") são funções que "capturam" variáveis que vêm de fora da função. Em inglês se diz que uma "closure" *closes over* (se fecha sobre) certas variáveis.

Um exemplo típico:

```
function somador(v1) {
  return function(v2) {
    return v1 + v2;
  }
}
```

`somador` retorna uma "closure", uma função que captura o valor de `v1` (note que `somador` não é uma "closure", e sim seu valor de retorno):

```
var soma10 = somador(10);
var total1 = soma10(5); // total1 é 15, já que soma10 capturou o valor de v1 como "10"

var soma20 = somador(20);
var total2 = soma20(5); // total2 é 25, soma20 capturou v1 = 20

var total3 = somador(30)(5); // usando diretamente a "closure"
```

"Currying" é um função que "captura" alguns paramêtros para outras funções e retorna uma função (uma "closure") que aceita o restante dos parâmetros.

Dada a função `soma`:

```
function soma(v1, v2) {
  return v1 + v2;
}
```

E uma simples função de "currying":

```
function curry(fn /*, argumentos parciais para fn */) {
  var args1 = [].slice.call(arguments, 1); // argumentos após fn
  return function(/* o resto dos argumentos para fn */) {
    var args2 = [].slice.call(arguments);
    return fn.apply(null, args1.concat(args2)); // junta todos os argumentos
  }
}
```

Podemos usá-las assim:

```
var soma10 = curry(soma, 10); // soma10 capturou "soma" e "10"
var total = soma10(5);
```

Answer (score 44):

## O que é *closure*?

*Closure* é um conceito em linguagem de programação que, de forma simplificada, permite que uma função acesse variáveis de sua função parente.

Essa técnica é oriunda de linguagens funcionais, mas acabou sendo difundido e implementado também para outras linguagens como JavaScript e C#.

Exemplo:

```js
function start() {
    var message = "hello world";

    function display() {
        console.log(message);
    }

    display();
}
```

No exemplo a função `display` tem acesso a variável `message`, mas note que a variável foi declarada no corpo da função parente `start`. A função *"de dentro"* (inner) tem acesso as variáveis da *"função de fora"* (outer). `display` no exemplo é considerado um *closure*.

Mas, mais ainda, as variáveis referenciadas da função parente continuam disponíveis mesmo ao final de sua execução. Segue outro exemplo:

```js
function getDisplay() {
    var message = "hello world";    
    return function display() {
        console.log(message);
    };
}

var display = getDisplay();
display();
```

Note que agora a exibição do valor de `message` é feito mesmo após sua função (`getDisplay`) já ter terminado sua execução.

## Como funciona

Para que isso seja possível a linguagem tem que prover para função não só a referências de suas variáveis locais e variáveis globais mas também as referências das variáveis *não locais*, que não estão nem em seu escopo e nem no escopo global, mas que de alguma forma se tornaram acessível a ela (como no exemplo pela função que a encapsula).

Falando de JavaScript, na prática, esse "ambiente" da função é chamado de *execution context*. Para cada chamada de função o interpretador monta um *execution context* para ela, e é daí que a mágica acontece :-)

## Mas e o *garbage collector*?

Tradicionalmente, a memória utilizada pela variável é "liberada" para o *garbage collector* assim que termina seu escopo, o que normalmente é assim que a execução sai do bloco que a encapsula (`{ }`).

A diferença no JavaScript é que seu interpretador mantém uma pilha de *execution context* conforme as funções vão sendo chamadas. E é essa pilha que vai fornecer para o interpretador a informação se o escopo da variável terminou ou não.

Vale deixar a nota: essa pilha não é a mesma memória que chamamos de "pilha" (stack) em outras linguagens como C/C++.

## Referência, não valor

Como você deve ter percebido pela maioria dos exemplos que existem por aí, com *closure* é feita a cópia das *referências* das variáveis, e não de seus *valores*.

Isto significa que ao alterar o valor de uma variável dentro de um *closure* todos os outros contextos que possuem referência para essa variável irão obter este valor quando acessá-la. Cuidado com eventuais efeitos colaterais.

Answer (score 32):

Closure tem a ver com o **escopo** de uma variável em JavaScript.

Para não poluir o namespace global, protegendo que as variáveis do seu script se misturem com outras variáveis de outros scripts, você pode usar um grande closure para colocar todo o código de seu plugin, app, ou library...

```
(function($){
    //  aqui vem o teu código
    var contador;
})(jQuery);
```

O escopo de um **closure** sempre vai **começar** com o caracter `{` e terminar com o caracter `}`. Sim, é isso mesmo: um escopo (closure) sempre tem um começo e um fim determinados pelo abre-colchete e fecha-colchete.

O que é interessante é que, ao criar uma função em um ponto determinado do código, você automaticamente cria um **closure**, onde as atuais variáveis locais ficam disponíveis dentro do novo escopo:

```
var crud = (function(){
    var modulo = {},
        contador = 0;

    modulo.update = function() {   // aqui temos o início de outro closure
        contador++;
    };  // e aqui o respectivo final

    return modulo;
})();
```

Repare na variável **contador**. Nós não temos acesso a ela "do lado de fora" do módulo **crud**. E ela também não foi definida dentro da função **update**. Quando chamamos **crud.update()** pela primeira vez, a variável **contador** vai passar a valer `1`. Se chamamos **crud.update()** pela segunda vez, a variável **contador** vai passar a valer `2`.

Você queria uma resposta simples e objetiva: contemple bem o exemplo acima. Se você entender o simples fato de que temos uma variável capturada dentro de um escopo, porém sempre disponível para a função que a "capturou", você vai ter entendido a essência da charada. Não é complicado. Mas é uma *feature* do JavaScript que abre espaço para padrões incríveis.

Answer (score 1):

Closure, em JS, por exemplo - vou dar um exemplo de uma linguagem - é quando o escopo exterior é enxergado *e guardado*, de dentro de um bloco ou função interior.

Por exemplo,

```
var minhaUrl = "Produtos/1";

function ajaxeira() {
  $.ajax({
    url: minhaUrl,
    ...
    success: function (data) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
  });
}
```

No início da execução desse bloco acima, `minhaUrl` contém `"Produtos/1"` e está claro ao observá-lo.

Para fim de ilustração, posso demonstrar o uso desta função `ajaxeira()` e mudar `minhaUrl` como se ela estivesse dentro do escopo da função,

```
minhaUrl = "Pedidos/4";
ajaxeira(); // Imprime o pedido 4 em formato JSON, em um alert, se der boa

minhaUrl = "Produtos/11";
ajaxeira(); // Imprime o produto 11 em formato JSON, em um alert, se der boa
```

No caso acima, `minhaUrl` é uma variável global, mas eu posso ter uma função que abriga `var minhaUrl` e, dentro desta função, ter outra função, que usa `minhaUrl`:

```js
$(function () {
    var minhaUrl = "Produtos/1";
    
    function ajaxeira() {
        alert('Imagine aqui a chamada ajax para ' + minhaUrl);
    }
    
    function pedidos4() {
        minhaUrl = "Pedidos/4";
    }
    
    $('#btnPedidos4').on('click', pedidos4);
    $('#btnAjaxeira').on('click', ajaxeira);

    alert(minhaUrl); // Popup com 'Produtos/1'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" id="btnAjaxeira" value="Ajaxeira" />
<input type="button" id="btnPedidos4" value="Pedidos 4" />
```

No código acima, quando eu clicar no botão Pedido 4, eu altero o valor de `minhaUrl`. A seguir, se eu apertar o botão Ajaxeira, vai aparecer o popup com o conteúdo do *pedido* e não mais do *produto*, que é o padrão.

Note também que estou aqui usando `pedidos4()` e `ajaxeira()` como callbacks e estes também enxergam e guardam o escopo imediatamente externo à suas declarações.

Comment: Sua edição melhorou muito a resposta. A primeira vez que a li, na primeira versão, fiquei muito confuso

Comment: Valeu @JeffersonQuesado, eu tava meio desconfiado que ninguém ia entender :D

Answer (score 0):

Uma **Closure** é um recurso disponível em algumas linguagens de programação em que uma função consegue acessar todo o escopo do ambiente léxico ao seu redor.

Um exemplo didático comum de closure é uma função dentro de outra função no qual a **função interna** consegue acessar  todo o **escopo** da **função mais externa**.

No caso acima, a **função interna da closure** guarda as referencias do **ambiente léxico** ao seu redor e consegue acessar as respectivas variáveis mesmo que a **função externa** já tenha sido executada.

Entretanto, não é necessário estar dentro de outra função para ser closure, uma vez que a função consegue acessar o escopo global.

O ambiente léxico se refere ao escopo da função em que algum componente (variável, objeto, função, etc...) está ou o escopo do contexto global.

Em JS, a closure sempre acontece com todas as funções, sem a necessidade de **keywords** especiais.

```
function outer() 
{
    //Variável no Ambiente Léxico da função interna.
    //Linha executada somente na atribuição de closureFunc.
    const outerVar = 10; 

    // função interna
    function inner() 
    { 
        console.log(outerVar) 
    }
    return inner
}

//Criação da Closure
const closureFunc = outer(); 

//Execução da Closure
closureFunc(); // Saída: 10
```

Comment: Não precisa ser uma função dentro de outra – aliás você mesmo diz isso implicitamente quando fala do escopo global. O que define closure é simplesmente o acesso ao escopo externo. Nesse sentido, em JS, toda função é closure, na medida em que "enclausura" o ambiente léxico onde ela está (mesmo que não haja mais nada nele, só a própria função). Imagino que tenha sido a causa do negativo que deram na sua resposta. E talvez também o fato de você não estar dizendo nada que já não tenha sido mencionado em outras respostas...

Comment: Tem razão. Me limitei a uma das possibilidades. Corrigido. Obrigado!