# Objeto global auto-referente: para que serve e por que existe?

Tags: javascript

O objeto `window` em browsers possui uma propriedade `window` que é [auto-referente](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autorrefer%C3%AAncia):

```
window.window === window; // true
```

E ainda há outras propriedades equivalentes nos browsers:

```
self === window; // true
top === window;  // true
self === top;    // true
self.top.window === window.top.self; // true
```

No Node.js, o objeto global também é auto-referente:

```
global.global === global; // true
```

Qual é a utilidade dessas propriedades, e qual é o motivo de sua existência?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A necessidade da propriedade `window.window` advém da forma como JavaScript referencia suas variáveis. Toda vez que uma expressão é criada envolvendo um **identificador** (i.e. um nome) a *engine* do JS procura em um objeto especial - chamado ***Variable Object*** - pela chave correspondente àquele identificador. (esse objeto recebe esse nome provavelmente pela sua função: um objeto que armazena variáveis)

```js
console.log(x + 1); // Procura por <<Variable Object>>['x'] 
                    // e depois por <<Variable Object>>['console']
```

Quando o código a ser executado está no *top-level*, o Variable Object é equivalente ao ***Global Object*** (que, no *browser*, seria o `window`, mas em outros ambientes pode ser diferente). Ou seja:

```js
console.log(x + 1); // Procura por window['x'] 
                    // e depois por window['console']
```

Já quando esse código está dentro de uma função, o Variable Object é chamado ***Activation Object***, e é diferente para cada invocação da função:

```js
function foo() {
    console.log(x + 1);
}

foo(); // Procura por <<Activation Object 1>>['x'] 
       // e depois por <<Activation Object 1>>['console']
foo(); // Procura por <<Activation Object 2>>['x'] 
       // e depois por <<Activation Object 2>>['console']
```

O programador não possui acesso direto ao Activation Object, apenas indireto através da tentativa de acessar uma propriedade por nome. Um Activation Object define um **contexto de execução**, ou seja, um conjunto de variáveis que estão acessíveis para serem utilizadas por aquele trecho de código. Um contexto de execução pode "herdar" de outro contexto, que pode herdar de outro, e assim por diante (para mais detalhes, ver [essa minha outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1859/como-funcionam-closures-em-javascript/1862#1862) na pergunta ["Como funcionam closures em javascript?"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1859/como-funcionam-closures-em-javascript)). Exemplo:

```js
function foo() {
    var x;
    function bar() {
        console.log(x + 1);
    }
    bar();
}
foo(); // Procura por <<Activation Object "bar" 1>>['x']
       //         ... <<Activation Object "foo' 1>>['x'] (encontrou)
       // e depois por <<Activation Object "bar" 1>>['console']
       //          ... <<Activation Object "foo" 1>>['console']
       //          ... window['console'] (encontrou)
```

Pois bem, de posse dessa explicação, pergunto: o que acontece quando escrevemos simplesmente:

```js
window

// ou

function foo() {
    window
}
foo();
```

? A engine JavaScript vai fazer o mesmo que sempre faz quando encontra um identificador: procurar no Variable Object:

```
window   // Procura por window['window']

function foo() {
    window
}
foo();   // Procura por <<Activation Object "foo" 1>>['window']
         //         ... window['window'] (encontrou)
```

Ou seja: para que o programador consiga acessar o Global Object (`window`), ele precisa ter uma referência para si próprio (`window['window']` ou simplesmente `window.window`). O mesmo vale para o node.js (`global.global`) e para qualquer outra implementação de JavaScript que exponha o objeto global aos programadores (se isso é obrigatório ou não de acordo com a especificação ECMAScript, não verifiquei).

A variável `self` (global) também se refere ao objeto `window`, conforme [a especificação do w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/Window/#window-basic-attributes). E quanto a `top`, ela pode ou não se referir a `window`, como explicado por @hernandes.

> **Fonte:** a maior parte dessa resposta se baseou no artigo (em inglês) ["Understanding delete"](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/).

Comment: +1 porque acho que responde melhor à pergunta, mas daria +10 pelo link para *"Understanding delete"*. Tem uns pontos na resposta que achei meio confusos, mas eu não posso dizer nada porque na maioria das vezes eu sou uma pessoa confusa. De qualquer forma, vale muito a pena ler esse artigo em Inglês.

Comment: Excelente! Só um detalhe: esse artigo do kangax (todos dele são ótimos, né?) está um pouco desatualizado, usa a terminologia do ECMAScript 3. Em ES5, *variable object* e *activation object* passaram a ser tratados como *declarative environment records*.

Answer (score 4):

`self` é definida no ambiente JavaScript e aponta para o `objeto global`, porém não faz parte da especificação do `DOM`, e pode não estar presente no navegador. Enquanto `window` é parte da especificação do `DOM`. Na maioria dos navegadores, `window` é usado como `objeto global` mas isso pode variar.

`self == window.self` não é uma coisa estranha, pois eles são na verdade, o mesmo objeto (quanto `self` é usada, é encontrado como sendo uma propriedade do objeto global (`window`)), então, isso é o mesmo que usar `window.self == window.self`.

Para ter uma referência **concisa** do objeto global, você deve definir por conta própria da seguinte forma (quando estiver no contexto global):

```
var global = this;
```

Por sua vês, `top` (`window.top`) é usada pra referenciar o objeto `window` mais superior, por exemplo, se você tiver vários frames aninhados, `window.top` irá referenciar a página principal e não os frames, `top` é usado para dectar se você está ou não dentro de um frame:

```
if(window.top != window.self) {
    alert("Estamos em um frame");
}
```

---

O Porquê de termos `window.window` (propriedade `window` do objeto `window`) é para facilitar referenciar o `objeto global`, chamando apenas `window` dentro de frame, estamos referenciando o frame, `window.window` estamos referenciando o objeto global, independente de onde

Comment: Certo, `self == window.self` pode não ser estranho, mas e `window.window == window`?

Comment: vou editar a resposta

Comment: respondi após o < hr >

Comment: onde vcs aprendem td isso? livros avançados?

Comment: @JoaoPaulo Não sei como o Hernandes aprendeu, mas geralmente esse tipo de coisa você vai pegando com um misto de experiência, pesquisa em documentações, fóruns como este, artigos e livros, além de muita curiosidade. Dificilmente vai existir uma fonte definitiva sobre qualquer assunto de tecnologia.

Comment: @utluiz exatamente, e a Internet tem muito mais conteúdo que qualquer livro avançado.