# O que é e como funciona o contexto (this) no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, contexto, this, use-strict

Parte essencial do JavaScript, toda função tem contexto (`this`). Como funciona ele, como manipulá-lo e o que muda no [modo estrito](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2746) (`'use strict'`)?

Comment: Vai rolar gratificação pra melhor resposta.

Comment: Por "contexto" você quer dizer o valor de `this`? Pergunto porque "contexto" é um termo muito usado para isso, mas não é o termo usado na especificação da linguagem.

Comment: @bfavaretto Interessante observação, sim, falo do `this` nesta pergunta, o termo contexto é usado pelo *Douglas Crockford* e acabou derivando em outros livros conceituados como a *Javascript O Guia Definitivo* por *David Flanagan*

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Em JavaScript, o [**contexto de execução**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3) de um trecho de código - que define qual o seu escopo léxico, dentre outras coisas - possui uma propriedade chamada `ThisBinding`, que pode ser acessada a qualquer momento através da palavra-chave [`this`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.1). Essa propriedade - presente mesmo quando não se está dentro de uma função e/ou essa função não é método de um objeto - é popularmente conhecida como o **contexto** [da função].

Inicialmente (i.e. no "*top-level*") o `this` corresponde a uma referência para o [**objeto global**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1). Nos browsers, ele é chamado `window`, e é [auto-referente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2427/215). Ao se interpretar um código através de `eval`, ele é mantido como está.
Ao se chamar uma função, ele muda da seguinte forma:

- Caso essa função seja chamada na forma de um método (i.e. nome, ponto, nome, parênteses) o `this` torna-se uma referência para o objeto que foi "alvo" da chamada:

  ```
  obj.f(); // Dentro de "f", this === obj
  ```

  Como apontado por @bfavaretto, se o objeto for um tipo primitivo (como um número), então o `this` [pode sofrer coerção para um objeto](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.3). Isso não ocorre no modo estrito.

  ```
  Number.prototype.foo = function() { 
      console.log(typeof this);
  }
  10.0.foo(); // "number" no modo estrito, "object" caso contrário
  ```
- Caso se use um dos métodos `call`, `apply` ou `bind`, o `this` é atribuído explicitamente:

  ```
  f.call(obj, foo, bar); // Dentro de "f", this === obj
  f.apply(obj, [foo]);   // idem
  f.bind(obj);           // idem
  ```

  Isso vale ainda que a função tenha sido referenciada na forma de "método de um objeto":

  ```
  obj.f.call(bar); // Dentro de "f", this === bar
  ```

  No modo estrito, o que for passado como primeiro parâmetro será o `this`, sem modificação. Caso contrário, pode haver a mesma coerção a objeto mencionada anteriormente ou, se o valor passado como parâmetro for `null` ou `undefined`, o `this` volta a ser o objeto global:

  ```
  f.call(20);   // 20 no modo estrito, Number(20) caso contrário
  f.call(null); // null no modo estrito, window caso contrário
  f.call();     // undefined no modo estrito, window caso contrário
  ```
- Caso a função seja chamada na forma "normal" (i.e. nome, parênteses), então das duas uma:

  - No modo estrito, `this` será `undefined`:

    ```
    "use strict";
    f(); // Dentro de "f", this === undefined
    ```
  - Nos demais casos, `this` volta a ser uma referência para o objeto global:

    ```
    f(); // Dentro de "f", this === window
    ```

    ...o que muitas vezes causa confusão:

    ```
    var obj = {
        f:function() {
            function g() {
                console.log(this); // this não é obj, e sim window ou undefined
                                   // (conforme o modo, estrito ou não)
            }
            g(); // Espera-se que imprima "obj", mas não é o que ocorre
        }
    }
    ```

A principal forma de manipulação do contexto, como já foi visto, é atraves dos métodos `call`, `apply` e `bind`. Este último cria uma "visão" da função original onde o `this` está "amarrado" ao parâmetro utilizado, e não pode ser modificado (uma espécie de [currying](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), também permitindo fixar os primeiros N argumentos) - nem mesmo pelos demais métodos:

```
function f() {
    console.log(this);
}
var x = f.bind(10); // this está amarrado a 10
x.call(20);         // não muda o this, ainda imprime 10
```

Quanto ao modo estrito, o principal impacto nesse contexto é aquele exposto acima - onde o `this` não se refere ao objeto global quando omitido (i.e. quando não atribuído explicitamente). Isso tem impacto na segurança, pois facilita o isolamento (*sandboxing*) de código não totalmente confiável. Há [muitos outros impactos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode) que o modo estrito exerce sobre contextos de execução e escopo, mas nada que afete o funcionamento do `this` (mesmo o `eval` continua se comportando da mesma maneira nos dois modos).

[**jsFiddle com todos os exemplos acima**](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/q8BP7/).

Comment: Nem vou mais responder :)

Comment: Acho que só faltou um detalhe, do qual lembrei lendo seu último exemplo: se `this` for um valor primitivo, ele sofre coerção para objeto (no caso do seu exemplo, para `Number`); no *strict mode*, porém, não ocorre coerção.

Comment: Complementando, isso está na [seção 10.4.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.3) da especificação.

Comment: @bfavaretto hehe se a pergunta fosse sobre contextos de execução (e não só sobre o `this`), eu ia deixar pra quem sabe mais... :P (P.S. bem lembrado quanto à coerção! eu sabia que isso era feito no modo normal, mas não que no modo strict era diferente)

Comment: +1 você escreve muito bem, sua explicação está sucinta e bem completa. Eu ia auto-responder, mas depois dessa não vejo necessidade hehe