# Declarando variável com let

Tags: javascript, variáveis, declaração-de-variável, escopo-de-variáveis

No código a seguir, porque não é retornado `João` ao tentar `this.pessoa`? Onde a `let` foi declarada deveria ir pro global, ou não?

```
let pessoa = 'João'
console.log(this.pessoa) //undefined
```

Comment: Chegou a ler [Qual é a diferença entre declaração de variáveis usando let e var?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47165/5878)

Comment: E se está definindo `pessoa`, por que utilizou o `this`?

Comment: Comecei a pouco tempo e minha dificuldade está sendo no this. Como nesse caso o this representa o escopo global e let foi criada no global, eu fui confirmar com this. Vi um exemplo desse uma vez, mas no exemplo retornava correto o nome, já no meu dá undefined.

Comment: Relacionada: [O que é e como funciona o contexto no Javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8975/5878)

Comment: @Jonatas A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Exatamente o oposto, o `let` deixa local, mais ainda, tem escopo de bloco, é mais restrito que `var`. O `var` ainda tem esse problema de não considerar todo o escopo. O `this` não tem escopo tão específico.

Se você puder garantir que seu código rodará em navegadores novos, ou puder rodar um [transpilador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/189894/101) antes que compatibilize versão só o `let` deveria ser usado (todo uso do `var` ou sem ele deveria ser considerado gambiarra).

Veja que há diferença em cada forma de declarar e se acessar pelo `this` ou não.

```js
let x = 'João';
var y = 'João';
z = 'João';
console.log(this.x);
console.log(this.y);
console.log(this.z);
console.log(x);
console.log(y);
console.log(z);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Syntax/Let.js).

Veja mais em [Qual é a diferença entre declaração de variáveis usando let e var?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47165/101) e também [O que é e como funciona o contexto no Javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8975/101).