# Contexto da propriedade this no TypeScript + Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Tenho uma classe XPTO com os métodos abaixo, no método de login eu tento chamar o método de tratamento da resposta, contudo, o `this` está undefined no contexto da função, pelo que pude entender eu teria que usar a função `.bind()`, mas como eu faria isso se minha função de tratamento de resposta recebe parâmetros?

Naturalmente, eu poderia fazer tudo em uma função só (eu testei e funcionou), mas ai a função ficaria muito grande, já li [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8975/o-que-%C3%A9-e-como-funciona-o-contexto-no-javascript), mas não ficou claro.

Código das duas funções:

```
import AutenticacaoDAO from '../daos/autenticacao.dao'
import MailController from './email.controller'
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'
import TokenSecret from '../config/token-secret'
import crypto from 'crypto'
import { Request, Response } from 'express'
import { Usuario } from '../models/usuario.model';

class AutenticacaoController {
    constructor() {

    }  

    public async login(req: Request, res: Response) {
        let usuario;
        try {
            usuario = await AutenticacaoDAO.login(req.body)
            this.tratarResposta(crypto.createHash("md5").update(req.body.senha).digest("hex"), usuario, res)  //this está undefined           
        } catch (error) {
            res.json(error)
        }
    }

    private tratarResposta(senhaEnviada: any, usuario: any, res: Response){ //função que eu quero chamar
        if (usuario && usuario.length > 0 && senhaEnviada === usuario[0].usuario.senha && !usuario[0].usuario.bloqueado) {
            res.json({
                usuario: usuario,
                token: jwt.sign({ usuario: usuario[0] }, TokenSecret, { expiresIn: '7d' })
            })
        } else if (usuario && usuario.length > 0 && senhaEnviada !== usuario[0].usuario.senha) {
            res.status(403).json({
                mensagem: `Não foi possível efetuar o login, sua senha está incorreta.`, erro: res.statusCode
            })
        }
        else if (usuario && usuario.length > 0 && usuario[0].usuario.bloqueado) {
            res.status(403).json({
                mensagem: `Não foi possível efetuar o login, seu usuário encontra-se bloqueado. Converse com seu gestor.`, erro: res.statusCode
            })
        }
        else {
            res.status(404).json({
                mensagem: `Não foi possível efetuar o login: Usuario não encontrado.`, erro: res.statusCode
            })
        }
    }

}

export default new AutenticacaoController()
```

Comment: Esses métodos fazem parte de uma classe?

Comment: Sim, vou colocar a classe toda, acho que fica melhor.

Comment: @luizfelipe, coloquei a classe toda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você vai executar o login em outro lugar, o this.tratarResposta será referenciado para aquele outro lugar, e não para essa classe. Estranho não? Mas JS é assim. haha

Pra isso, dentro do construtor, coloque: `this.login = this.login.bind(this)`

Isso vai fazer o this.tratarResposta referenciar ao this.tratarResposta de AutenticacaoController, e não da classe que ele estará chamando. Sempre que der undefined, é preciso fazer um bind, e o melhor lugar para isso é no constructor.

Não cheguei a fazer testes de código, mas acredito que seja isso. Caso não funcionar, crie um código online (no codepen ou outro lugar) simulando exatamente como você está fazendo ai.