# typescript: is not a function

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, typescript, classes

No meu controller eu pretendia ter um método para validar os tipos dos dados que entravam no controller, para fazer um tratamento de erros mais adequado, assim sendo, o método responsável por chamar o serviço que executa a criação da instância (que está em outra classe) também chamaria o método para fazer a validação das entradas, o problema é que se eu tento fazer isso um o erro `this.validate is not a function` é sempre retornado. Gostaria de saber o porque isso acontece...

O código do meu controller está mais ou menos assim

```
class CreateAddressController {
  public validate(): void {
    console.log(`ok`);
  }

  async handle(request: Request, response: Response): Promise<Response> {
    const {
      place,
      number,
      complement,
      district,
      city,
      state,
      zipcode,
      client_id,
    } = request.body;

    this.validate();

    const createAddressUseCase = container.resolve(CreateAddressUseCase);

    await createAddressUseCase.execute({
      place,
      number,
      complement,
      district,
      city,
      state,
      zipcode,
      client_id,
    });

    return response.status(201).send();
  }
}
```

Comment: Como você está invocando a função `handle`? Se você desacoplou a função do objeto, o `this` não terá irá referenciar a instancia do `CreateAddressController`, logo seu código não irá encontrar nenhuma função com o nome `validate` dentro do `this`.

Comment: nas minhas rotas eu instancio o controller e invoco a função, mais ou menos dessa forma:

```const create = new Controller()

router.post("/", create.handle)
```

Comment: Abel, utilize `router.post("/", (req, res) => create.handle(req, res))` ou `router.post("/", create.handle.bind(create))`. Você pode ler a explicação para esse comportamento [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8975/o-que-%c3%a9-e-como-funciona-o-contexto-this-no-javascript).