# Como deletar uma variável em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, variáveis, escopo-de-variáveis

Programo em outras linguagens, ainda estou começando no JavaScript. Estava testando o [código da resposta do mgibsonbr a esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13034/o-que-sao-escopo-lexico-e-escopo-dinamico-e-quais-sao-suas-principais-diferencas) e encontrei uma dificuldade que talvez seja trivial.

Se eu definir `var x = 0` no ambiente global como depois faço para deletá-la? Em outros lugares, vi como "resposta" definir `var x = null`, mas isso não remove a variável, apenas atribui o valor null a ela.

Também testei o `delete` o com seguinte código dentro de um HTML:

```
<script>
var x = 10
console.log(x)
delete window.x
console.log(x)
</script>
```

E quando abro o console do Chrome aparecem 10 e 10, ou seja, a variável não foi deletada.

Perguntas:

1. Como deletar uma variável definida com `var`? Se não é possível, de preferência explicar o porquê, a lógica disso.
2. Se houver, quais as diferenças entre deletar uma variável em um ambiente local (de uma função, um objeto, por exemplo) e um ambiente global?

Comment: Não dá pra deletar variáveis declaradas com `var` na frente.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Não há como deletar variáveis declaradas com `var`

A função do operador `delete` é excluir propriedades de objetos, e não variáveis. Portanto em princípio ele não serviria para excluir variáveis.

*Mas se eu declaro `var x = 10` e posso acessá-la como `window.x`, então `x` não é uma propriedade do objeto `window`?* Sim. *E mesmo assim não posso excluí-la?* Não. *Por quê?*

### *Environment records*

No JavaScript, as variáveis são consideradas propriedades de objetos internos (*environment records*) que representam determinado escopo e não são expostos para a linguagem – o fato do objeto global ser [exposto como `window`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2427/objeto-global-auto-referente-para-que-serve-e-por-que-existe) nos browsers é um caso especial. Propriedades de objetos, por sua vez, também possuem [atributos internos](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.1) que definem certos aspectos do seu comportamento. Um deles, chamado [[Configurable]] na especificação, define se a propriedade pode ser excluída ou não (entre outras restrições).

Nos browsers, variáveis globais criadas são sempre propriedades de `window`. As que são criadas com declaração (`var`) recebem valor `false` para o atributo [[Configurable]], e isso impede que elas sejam excluídas com `delete window.varname`. Já as globais implícitas, criadas sem `var`, [seguem um caminho diferente](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7.2) pelas operações internas da linguagem, a acabam recebendo valor `true` para [[Configurable]], permitindo que sejam excluídas com `delete window.varname`. Isso pode ser considerado uma brecha na linguagem. É bom registrar que [é recomendável evitar ao máximo as globais implícitas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2513/quando-se-deve-usar-var-no-javascript), que inclusive são [proibidas no modo estrito](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2746/quando-por-que-e-como-utilizar-a-diretiva-use-strict-em-javascript) da linguagem (a tentativa de criá-las lança uma exceção).

### Variáveis não globais

Não há como excluir variáveis não globais, por dois motivos:

- O objeto interno que as contém não é exposto pela linguagem
- Mesmo que ele fosse exposto, as variáveis são representadas como propriedades com [[Configurable]]: false, não podendo ser excluídas com `delete`.

### Para que excluir variáveis?

Um bom motivo para excluir variáveis seria liberar memória. Se esse for o seu objetivo, simplesmente defina o valor da variável como `null`, e o *garbage collector* irá liberar a memória correspondente caso não haja nenhuma referência sobrando ao valor que a variável continha (no caso de valores do tipo `Object` ou derivados, pode haver múltiplas variáveis apontando para o mesmo objeto ou partes dele).

Answer (score 11):

De acordo com a MDN, [o `delete` serve para remover propriedades de um objeto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete):

```
x = 42;     // cria a propriedade x no objeto global
var y = 43; // declara a variável y

delete x; // retorna true  (x é uma propriedade global de um objeto e pode ser deletada)
delete y; // retorna false (delete não afeta nomes de variável)
```

Na declaração `x = 42`, o `x` não parece ser a propriedade de um objeto, o que pode causar alguma confusão. Na verdade estamos atribuindo um valor a uma propriedade `x`, que pertence um objeto global.

`var`'s e nomes de função também são propriedades, mas com atributos internos diferentes, [conforme explicado na resposta do @bfavaretto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/14209/4402). Nesses casos o `delete` não funciona.

**Resumindo: ao utilizar o `var` na declaração, a variável nunca poderá ser deletada.**

Exemplo: sem utilizar o `var`, é possível (pelo menos no Chrome) apagar a variável com ou sem o uso do `window`:

```
// Não apaga
var w = 789;
delete w;

// Não apaga
var x = 123;
delete window.x;

// Apaga
y = 123;
delete window.y;

// Apaga
z = 456;
delete z;
```

Fazendo o mesmo teste, mas dentro do escopo de uma função, o resultado é o mesmo. Se o objetivo é obter o erro `Uncaught ReferenceError: <alguma-coisa> is not defined`, não existe outra forma. Senão, como você já comentou, dá para definir a variável em questão como `null` ou `undefined`.

### Referências:

- http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Comment: complemento: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16963066/javascript-how-to-delete-a-variable

Comment: Michael, não é possível remover uma variável definida com `var` em nenhuma circunstância? Por quê?

Comment: Porque o delete não é aplicável a nomes de variáveis e nomes de função. Ele só é aplicável a propriedades de objetos. Dei uma complementada na resposta.

Comment: Toda variável ou função global (incluindo o que é declarado com `var`) é sim propriedade do objeto global. Porém não podem ser excluídas devido a um atributo interno (ver minha resposta, e a primeira referência que você mencionou, que explica isso de maneira bem detalhada).

Comment: Entendi. Vou corrigir minha afirmação na resposta.