# Quando e porque usar window antes de funções?

Tags: javascript

Existem inúmeras funções predefinidas em JavaScript que podem ser utilizadas com ou sem o objeto `window` como prefixo. Exemplo:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {

});

setTimeout(function() {

});
```

Qual a regra para utilizar este objeto antes das funções? E qual a forma recomendada de se trabalhar com ele?

Comment: [Escopo, talvez?](http://jsfiddle.net/45ke3jk5/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As funções nativas em JavaScript (do Browser) fazem parte do Objeto `window` e são globais. Isto é o mesmo que dizer que as propriedades de `window` estão acessíveis no escopo global. Ou seja, podem ser usadas em qualquer escopo.

Porem, elas podem ser sobrescritas, e portanto não estarem mais disponíveis dentro de um certo escopo/função. Por exemplo:

```
console.log(window.location.hostname); // pt.stackoverflow.com
(function () {
    var location = {};
    location.hostname= 'fooooo';
    console.log(location.hostname); // fooooo
    console.log(window.location.hostname); // pt.stackoverflow.com
})();
```

neste caso `window.location.pathname` vai aceder à propriedade `location` do `window`. Mas se, dentro de outro escopo, declararmos uma variável de nome `pathname` então nesse escopo, `pathname` não vai ser o mesmo que `window.pathname`.

Então, se necessário podemos sempre aceder ao "original" via `window`. A razão para não se usar `window.pathname` sempre é para poupar caracteres basicamente.

Comment: "sobrescritas" não é um bom termo. Em inglês se diz *shadowed*, mas não sei qual seria uma boa tradução. Talvez "sobrepostas" ou algo nessa linha.

Comment: Neste caso, é correto afirmar que o objeto `window` é imutável?

Comment: @Kazzkiq não. As propriedades de  `window` podem ser sobrescritas também. Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/pz3eazpv/

Comment: Mas o window em si, não pode, correto? (ex.: `window = 1`)

Comment: @bfavaretto em português europeu _sobrepostas_ dá ideia que a outra ainda está por baixo. Eu escreví sobreescritas como quem diz _escrever por cima_. Mas se calhar nenhuma serve para pt do brazil e europeu :P

Comment: Mas não é isso mesmo? A outra ainda está por baixo, no escopo mais de fora (neste caso, o global).

Comment: @Kazzkiq exato. No caso de se querer recuperar funções nativas sobreescritas pode criar-se uma iFrame e ir buscar a "essa window" o que se precisa.

Comment: @Kazzkiq Sobrescrever o objeto inteiro, aí não dá mesmo. Por curiosidade, ver http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2427/74