# "Desclosurar" um closure

Tags: javascript, closures

Eu entendo [os grandes poderes e as grandes consequências dos closures](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1859/como-funcionam-closures-em-javascript).

Mas suponhamos que eu tenha o seguinte código...

```
function foo () {
    var x = 1;
    function bar () {
        return x++;
    }
    return bar;
}
```

... E que eu não deseje manter o contexto de `foo` na memória, porque na vida real ele pode ser uma função (ou varias) que utilize uma quantidade muito grande de memória. Mas ainda assim, desejo utilizar os valores processados por `foo` no contexto de `bar`.

Se fosse `x` uma variável global, ainda seria formado um closure? Caso `x` fosse externo a `foo`, como em...

```
var x = 1;
function foo () {
    function bar () {
        return x++;
    }
    return bar;
}
```

...Ainda haveria closure?

Existe alguma forma sã de se alcançar o objetivo que descrevi anteriormente? E independente disso, existe alguma forma de se destruir um contexto de execução que eu não precise mais utilizar?

Comment: Você quer um `x` local a `foo` que não interfira no `x` global?

Comment: @AndréLeria eu gostaria de copiar os valores das variáveis de `foo` para dentro de `bar`... para ter os valores conforme processados por `foo`, mas não segurar um contexto de execução na memória.

Comment: Só não entendi a última parte de segurar um contexto. Sua preocupação é memória?

Comment: @AndréLeria exatamente. Desejo utilizar o absoluto mínimo de memória possível a cada momento.

Comment: Eu te entendo e já estive no seu lugar. Estou torcendo por boas respostas, mas depois de um tempo pesquisando respostas desse tipo, minha conclusão é que se você quer bom uso de memória, use C/C++/ASM. Mas como eu disse, espero que você consiga uma boa solução, porque eu também a busco a um tempo. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, você precisa de *parte* das variáveis de determinado contexto de execução, mas não quer manter todas na memória. Uma solução é gerar sua função em outro contexto, passando como parâmetro os dados que você quer manter:

```
function foo () {
    var x = 1;
    var naoQuero = 2;
    return criaBar(x);
}
function criaBar(x) {
    return function() {
        return ++x;
    }
}
var bar = foo();
bar(); // retorna 2
bar(); // retorna 3
```

Mas atenção: o `x` dentro da função retornada será uma cópia do original, no momento em que foi passado para `criaBar`. Não adianta tentar alterá-lo dentro de `foo`, após a chamada a `criaBar`, e esperar que `bar()` incremente esse valor alterado.

E repare que alterei o `return x++` para `return ++x`, caso contrário o código retorna o valor atual e depois incrementa, e imagino que o objetivo seja retornar o valor já incrementado.

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript (JS) não possui um gerenciado de memória explicito, o browser decide quando deve limpa-lo. Às vezes pode acontecer uma perda de eficiência na renderização do JS devido a uma pausa para coleta de lixo (GC - Garbage Collection).

Há técnicas para superar falhas causadas pelo GC.

Suponha que você tem um algoritmo escrito em JS, e a cada segundo você está criando um novo objeto, é óbvio que a após certa quantidade de tempo o GC irá atuar liberando mais espaço para a sua aplicação.

Para aplicações em tempo real, que requer muito espaço, a coisa mais simples que você pode fazer é reutilizar a mesma memória. Depende de como você estrutura o seu código. Se ele gera muita lixo, então ele pode com o passar do tempo experimentar uma lentidão provocada pelo GC., aqui eu enumero 3 itens iniciais de estudo para melhorar o seu código.

Usar procedimentos simples: Sempre que possível, você deve tentar reutilizar o mesmo objeto, adicionando ou modificando suas propriedades. Reciclagem de objeto é uma maneira muito boa de evitar-se criar sempre objetos novos enchendo a "memória" do browser.

Em caso de array: geralmente é atribuindo [] com intuito de retira-lo da memória, mas é um erro, pois, ele cria uma nova matriz e deixa a antiga como lixo. Para reutilizar o mesmo array você deve usar `vararray.Length = 0` Isto tem o mesmo efeito da anterior mas reutiliza o objeto de array em vez de criar uma nova. Ainda pode-se usar o operador `delete` que eu irei explicar mais abaixo.

Em caso de funções: Às vezes é necessário chamar uma função específica em um determinado tempo ou em intervalos usando setInterval ou setTimeout.

```
setTimeout(function() { function(){ ... código ... } }, 10);
```

Você pode otimizar esse código, atribuindo a função a uma variável permanente em vez de criá-la a cada intervalo.

```
var minhafuncao = function(){ ... código ... }
setTimeout(minhafuncao, 10);
```

Tenha cuidado ao usar as funções `slice()` essa cria um novo array deixando o anterior intocado, `substr()` também deixa a string inicial intacta, gerando uma nova na "memória", há ainda outras (que não me vem a cabeça) que geram novos objetos deixando os anteriores ocupando espaço, forçando o GC a entrar em atividade mais vezes.

Você ainda tem a opção de usar o operador [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) que serve para remover propriedades dos objetos:

```
x = 42;         // craindo uma propriedade C do objeto global
var y = 43;     // declarando uma nova variável 'y'
meuObj = {
    h: 4,
    k: 5
};

delete x;        // retorna true  (x é uma propriedade do objeto global e pode ser deletado)
delete y;        // retorna false (delete não funciona com variáveis)
delete Math.PI;  // retorna false (delete não funciona com propriedade pré definidas)
delete meuObj.h; // retorna true  (propriedade definida por usuário pode ser deletada)

delete meuObj;   // retorna true  (meuObj é uma propriedade do objeto global, não é uma variável, nesse caso pode ser deletado)
```

Outro exemplo agora usando prototype

```
function Foo(){}
Foo.prototype.bar = 42;
var foo = new Foo();
delete foo.bar;           // retorna true, mas não tem efeito, bar é uma propriedade herdada
console.log(foo.bar);     // mostra 42, propriedade herdada
delete Foo.prototype.bar; // deleta propriedade no prototype
console.log(foo.bar);     // mostra "undefined"
```

Em relação a array quando você remove um elemento, o comprimento do array não é afetado. Isso vale mesmo se você excluir o último elemento. Quando o operador delete remove um elemento da matriz, esse elemento não é mais acessível. No exemplo a seguir, meuArray[3] é removido com delete.

```
var meuArray= ["zero","um","dois","três","quatro","cinco"];

delete meuArray[3];
if (3 in meuArray) {
    //esse bloco nunca será executado
}
```

Se você quiser que um elemento da matriz não deixe de existir, mas apenas tenha um valor indefinido, use `undefined` em vez do operador `delete`. No exemplo a seguir, meuArray[3] é atribuído `undefined`, mas o elemento do array ainda existe:

```
var meuArray= ["zero","um","dois","três","quatro","cinco"];

meuArray[3]=undefined;
if (3 in meuArray) {
    // esse bloco será executado
}
```

Evitar lixo em JS é uma arte, diria que é (ao menos hoje) impossível, mas os browsers têm evoluído para melhorar a colata destes. O que temos que ter em mente é que todo código deve ser feito de forma a otimizar o desempenho do sistema para que depois de milhares de linhas não seja necessário refazê-lo.

Comment: Esta é uma boa resposta, que comenta sobre vários assuntos relativamente complexos. Só não sei se atende ao que foi perguntado.

Answer (score 3):

Sim, não use closures. Use objetos simples com NEW ou objetos literal com {}. A closure, por definição vai manter todo o escopo: a função interna + a externa.

A sua segunda solução é ainda pior, porque vai garantir que o objeto tenha referência à variável 'global' x, não permitindo que o GC entre pra limpá-la da memória.