# Qual a diferença entre uma expressão lambda, um closure e um delegate?

Tags: c#, java, terminologia, groovy, closures

Pelo que eu andei lendo os três conceitos são bastante parecidos, mas eu fiquei confuso quanto a definição clara e exata deles.

Pelo que eu sei, uma expressão lambda por ser entendida como uma *função inline*, ou um procedimento que se passa para outro procedimento, como no pseudo-código abaixo:

```
func(lambda (Type arg1, Type2 arg2) {
    doSomethingWithArgs()
}, anotherArg);
```

Entretanto o conceito que eu tenho de Closure é exatamente o mesmo de cima, com duas diferenças:

- Por alguma razão, parece importante destacar que um Closure referencia uma variável fora de seu escopo.
- Closures podem ser atribuídos a variáveis e manipulados como se fossem objetos.

Entretanto, recentemente andei aprendendo Groovy, que me apresentou um conceito de Closure ligeiramente diferente:

> A Groovy Closure is like a "code block" or a method pointer. It is a piece of code that is defined and then executed at a later point. It has some special properties like implicit variables, support for currying and support for free variables (which we'll see later on). We'll ignore the nitty gritty details for now (see the formal definition if you want those) and look at some simple examples.
>   ([Fonte](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Closures))

Em palavras mais simples: Um Closure é um objeto Groovy (aliás: É um objeto Java) que se comporta como um bloco de código e um cidadão de primeira classe, que pode ser passado como parâmetro para métodos, atribuído a variáveis e ter sua assinatura de método redefinida.

Coincidentemente, o C# apresenta exatamente o mesmo conceito, que ele chama de Delegate. No entanto, a descrição dessa *feature* destaca que um delegate pode ser atribuído a outro método já existente que se conforme com sua assinatura.

> A delegate is a type that safely encapsulates a method, similar to a function pointer in C and C++. Unlike C function pointers, delegates are object-oriented, type safe, and secure. The type of a delegate is defined by the name of the delegate. The following example declares a delegate named Del that can encapsulate a method that takes a string as an argument and returns void.
>   [Fonte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173172.aspx)

Quais as diferenças entre uma expressão lambda, um closure e um delegate?

Comment: Na prática, nenhuma.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Não vou entrar em detalhes sobre o funcionamento já que a dúvida é mais relacionado com a terminologia.

## Introdução

Cada linguagem pode ter sua própria definição. Em termos gerais há uma definição mais aceita sobre o que é cada um. Há alguma controvérsia mas existem fontes confiáveis formais sobre alguns termos que expressam os conceitos referidos.

Alguém que venha de outra linguagem pode achar estes termos errados. Em geral é interessante usar os termos que a comunidade que você está inserido usa para facilitar a comunicação. Mas é bom entender todos os termos e como funciona o recurso. Se encontrar alguém com viés mais acadêmico ela vai expressar da forma mais correta, se preocupando em usar o termo mais correto em cada situação. Mas a maioria das pessoas vão se preocupar mais em apenas comunicar a ideia.

## Termos

Você pode encontrar também os termos *function pointer*, *functor*, *anonymous function*, *first class function*, *function object*, *high order function*, *nested function* (este acho um pouco enganador), *callback* (que também é possível sem ser exatamente uma *lambda*), *inline function* (acho este termo mais ambíguo ainda) e outros para nomear o mecanismo ou conceito. Sem esquecer das traduções destes termos que podem ser usados também, é comum falar em "função anônima". Alguns destes termos tratam de coisas ligeiramente diferentes. Eles podem estar definindo algum detalhe específico.

## Delegate

Podemos dizer que o *delegate* é o mecanismo usado para implementar o conceito de *lambdas*. Em C# por exemplo, o termo *lambda* é usado para indicar uma sintaxe mais simples, mais tersa de um [*delegate*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). *Delegates* costumam ser objetos em linguagens orientadas a objeto. Normalmente criados à partir de uma classe/estrutura com a infraestrutura necessária para tratar esses delegados conforme as regras da linguagem. [Exemplo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.delegate?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0).

## Code Block

Uma *lambda* é uma função definida como um bloco de código a ser executado futuramente, por isto em algumas linguagens usa-se o termo *code block*.

## Lambda

Provavelmente uma termos mais usados para expressar o conceito. Estritamente uma *lambda* **seria** a *closure* que não tem capacidade de capturar variáveis mas nem sempre é interpretado desta forma. Note que usei preferencialmente este termo em toda resposta.

Elas se diferenciam da funções nomeadas normalmente conhecidas que são "fixas".

## Closure

O termo *closure* costuma ser usado quando a *lambda* captura, enclausura, um estado, possivelmente uma variável, do escopo externo ao seu corpo mas dentro do escopo em que a *lambda* foi definida. Estas variáveis podem receber vários nomes: *non local*, *free variables* ou *upvalues*. Se você terminar a execução de uma função onde uma *lambda* foi definida e o retorno desta função for justamente a *lambda* que enclausurou uma variável local, esta variável será destacada e irá junto com a *lambda* podendo ser acessada em outro momento quando ela for invocada para execução.

Um exemplo simples (fiz em JavaScript que é mais universal):

```
function funcao() { 
    var x = 1;
    return function (n) { 
        return x + n; //sempre vai retornar o argumento usado na chamada desta lambda + 1
    } 
}
var func = funcao();
func(2); //retorna 3
```

Há quem use o termo *closure* mesmo quando esta captura não ocorre. E acho que não deixa de estar certo. Eu entendo que a *lambda* não precisa capturar a variável para poder usar o termo *closure*, senão fica muito efêmero. Eu acredito que o fato da *lambda* ter a capacidade de fazer esta captura, mesmo que não o faça em uma instância específica, é o que importa. E quase sempre (em quase todas as linguagens) uma *lambda* tem essa capacidade, por isto é frequente usar apenas um único termo para qualquer situação.

O termo *closure* costuma ser usado para indicar *lexical closure*. Existe também o termo *syntatic closure* que se aproxima mais de uma macro encontrada em linguagens como Lisp.

Um exemplo do C#:

```
public static Func<int,int> Func() {
    var x = 1;
    Func<int, int> inc = p => {
                                x++;
                                return p + x;
                            };
    return inc;
}
```

Seria compilado para algo mais ou menos assim:

```
private class Closure { 
    public int x;
    public int AnonymousFunction(int p) {
        this.x++;
        return p + this.x;
    }
}
public static Func<int,int> Func() {
    Closure c = new Closure();
    c.x = 1;
    Func<int, int> inc = c.AnonymousFunction;
    return inc;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Lambda/ClosureCompiled.cs)

## Miscelânea e conclusão

Note que qualquer que seja o nome que está usando, o conceito de *lambda* pressupõe que ela seja tratada como um valor de alguma forma, portando ela deve poder ser guardada em uma variável ou passada como argumento de uma função para ser executada mais tarde possibilitando *lazy evaluation*, por exemplo. Desconheço *lambdas* que não possam ser atribuídas a um outro objeto. E acho que se isto não for feito, perde completamente o sentido de sua utilização. Normalmente espera-se que uma *lambda* possa ser retornada como resultado de uma função. Mas nem todas linguagens permitem isto e acho uma grande limitação. Isto ocorre principalmente nas linguagens que não possuem um *[garbage collector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science))*. Sem ele é muito difícil implementar *closures* nas linguagens.

A capacidade de redefinição da assinatura depende mais da linguagem ter [tipagem dinâmica ou estática](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21508/101).

Use o termo que for ou a forma que é implementado, eu acho um recurso fundamental em qualquer linguagem. Aprendi seu uso muito cedo e consigo simplificar enormemente muitos códigos com ele.

Veja o [artigo na Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) (lembrando sempre que em inglês sempre dá mais detalhes e costuma ser mais correto).

[Definição bem acadêmica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) se tiver paciência. Entender tudo isto é importante em determinados softwares mas o entendimento da ideia geral e os conceitos básicos deste recurso é suficiente para fazer seu controle de estoque, seu site de imobiliária, seu *app* de lista de compras.

Algumas respostas relacionadas ao assunto:

- [Como funcionam Closures em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1859/101)
- ["Desclosurar" um closure](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3112/101)
- [Qual o benefício e em que casos usar closures no PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23943/101)
- [O que são closures e qual sua utilização?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31414/101)
- [Como funcionam funções anônimas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9936/101)
- [Qual a diferença entre as funções var name = function() e function name()?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13364/101)

Comment: Excelente resposta. Em resumo: Na prática (e na teoria, inclusive), é tudo a mesma coisa. Mas cada linguagem implementa e explica isso de um jeito. Groovy e C# parecem implementar exatamente do mesmo modo: as [insira seu nome preferido aqui] são objetos, cidadãos de primeira classe e podem capturar referências para funções que conformem-se com sua assinatura. Mas outras linguagens como Java (a partir da versão 8) implementa isso como interfaces funcionais.

Comment: @Sid é quase a mesma coisa, é importante salientar que existem diferenças no uso de alguns termos, mas raramente essas diferentes são relevantes de tão pequenas na maioria dos casos. Muitas vezes, mas não todas, a explicação é diferente mas o resultado prático é o mesmo. Java tem uma dificuldade, eles não implementaram este recurso no início, aí ficou mais difícil fazer da melhor forma sem quebrar compatibilidade. E não é a primeira vez que isto acontece. Na verdade tem um outro problema mas vou evitar levantar polêmica :P

Comment: Sim, de fato, mas acho que o jeito que o Java implementou isso quebra o galho, não? Aliás, eu penso que o pessoal do Java poderia ter sido mais cara de pau: "importar" os closures do Groovy e definir um literal pra esse objeto como um bloco de código que é uma expressão lambda. Na hora de compilar, o literal podia simplesmente expandir para a classe anônima.

Comment: Certamente. Não conheço o Groovy mais que superficialmente mas me lembro de ter boas ideias nele. Várias linguagens que rodam na JVM fizeram melhor que o próprio Java.

Answer (score 9):

**Delegate** é equivalente a um ponteiro de função/método.
Ou seja, é uma maneira de você transformar uma chamada de método em um objeto.

```
Func<string, int> fn = int.Parse;
MetodoX( fn );
```

Ao chamar a o método *MetodoX* este poderá usar o delegate como uma função normal.

**Lambda** comumente se refere a métodos anônimos, ou seja, um método que é declarado dentro de outro método.
Em C# e em JavaScript lambda está mais associado ao formato da expressão:

```
Func<int,int> fn = (x,y) => x + y;
```

A única forma de se chamar um método anônimo (que pode ser declarado por uma expressão lambda sem qualquer prejuízo), é através do *Delegate* com assinatura compatível.

**Closure** ocorre quando uma variável de escopo acima é "capturada" por um método anônimo:

```
int z = 0;
Func<int,int> fn = (x,y) => (x + y) * z;
```

No exemplo acima a variável *z* estará disponível no método anônimo definido em *fn*.
O método anônimo pode alterar essa variável, de forma que essa alteração será refletida no contexto pai.

```
int z = 0;
Func<int,int> fn = (x,y) => { z = 9; return (x + y) };
fn(1,2);
Console.WriteLine(z);
```

No exemplo acima será impresso o valor 9, pois a variável *z* foi alterada dentro do método anônimo em *fn*.