# HTML Helpers em ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, .net, expressões-lambda

Vi alguns HTML Helpers assim: `@Html.LabelFor(x => x)` e `@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Propriedade)`, porém, não entendo esse parâmetro que devo passar, `x => x`, o que é isso?

Comment: Entendi, mas aonde o DisplayName entra nisso? O resultado em HTML não devia ser: 
<label for="SuaPropriedade">Propriedade do model</label>?

Comment: Adicionei uma resposta mostrando como o `LabelFor` chega até o `DisplayName` da propriedade indicada pela lambda. Se sobrar alguma dúvida é só falar! Abç

Comment: Continuo sem entender o uso do lambda, para mim, faria mais sentido assim:
@Html.LabelFor(Model.Propriedade)

Comment: Dessa forma, você estaria passando o valor da propriedade para o helper. Imagine que exista essa propriedade na classe do modelo: `[Display(Name="Nome da pessoa")] public string Name { get; set; }`, com o valor `"Miguel Angelo"` atribuido a ela... Se fosse da forma que você disse, não haveria diferená entre `@Html.LabelFor(Model.Name)` e `@Html.LabelFor("Miguel Angelo")`. Não é o valor da propriedade que queremos passar, mas sim, algo que seja capaz de identificar **de qual propriedade** obter o `DisplayName`, que é informação dada através do atributo `Display`: `"Nome da pessoa"`.

Comment: Eu consegui entender o resultado disso, porém, não consigo entender a sintaxe do lambda, oque quer dizer x => x.Propriedade, por que X? por que não Y? Como o C# reconhece X como o Model?

Comment: O nome da variável, é você que inventa. Pode ser `x`, `y`, `m`, `model`... qualquer coisa. O C# sabe qual é o tipo, pois ele é capaz de "adivinhar" através de um processo de inferência de tipo. Eu vou editar a minha resposta mostrando como o C# faz isso passo a passo.

Comment: @andré Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 6):

## Objetivo do parâmtero `x => x.`...

Esse parâmetro é usado para que o helper, no caso `LabelFor` saiba qual é a propriedade do seu objeto `Model` para a qual ele deve renderizar uma label. A partir desse momento, o `LabelFor` é capaz de obter os metadados da propriedade indicada. No caso ele vai estar interessado em uma metadado chamado `DisplayName`.

- caso 1:

  ```
   @Html.LabelFor(x => x)
  ```

  Isso quer dizer: renderize um label para o objeto `Model` como um todo. A regra para obter os metadados do model raiz depende de uma hierarquia de renderização. Essa forma é mais comum dentro de *Editor Templates* e *Display Templates*, pois dentro dos templates essa hierarquia está disponível.
- caso 2:

  ```
   @Html.LabelFor(x => x.MinhaPropriedade)
  ```

  Isso quer dizer: renderize um label para a propriedade `MinhaPropriedade`. O método `LabelFor` sabe como extrair essa informação a partir dos metadados da propriedade, sendo que uma das formas é colocar o atributo `Display(Name = "Label da propriedade)"` na propriedade.

## Como o `LabelFor` obtem o display name?

Agora que já expliquei o objetivo da lambda sendo passada para o helper, vou explicar o funcionamento, ou seja, como um helper faz para chegar até os metadados da propriedade em questão.

O helper, quando chamado, terá acesso ao objeto `HtmlHelper<TModel>`, e à lambda passada por parâmetro. Eis a definição do método `LabelFor`:

```
public static MvcHtmlString LabelFor<TModel, TValue>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
```

- **`HtmlHelper<TModel>`:** esse objeto é o `Html` (da expressão `@Html.`...) sobre o qual o extension-method `LabelFor` está sendo aplicado (vale para outros html-helper quaisquer). Este é um objeto genérico, em que `TModel` é o tipo do modelo sendo usando pela view.

  Esse objeto possui em sua estrutura, todos os metadados do modelo sendo trabalhado: `html.ViewData.ModelMetadata`.
- **lambda:** esse parâmetro é passado como uma lambda, mas na verdade o tipo do objeto que o `LabelFor` recebe é `Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>>`. Esse tipo é capaz de representar a lambda passada na forma de uma [AST (Abstract Syntax Tree)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) que irá conter em sua estrutura a propriedade deve ser usada na forma de um [`PropertyInfo` (reflection)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo(v=vs.110).aspx). A partir daí, o helper é capaz de associar o `PropertyInfo` aos metados disponíveis no objeto `html.ViewData.ModelMetadata` e obter o `DisplayName`.

### Como o C# faz para saber o tipo da lambda?

O C# faz isso através de um processo de inferência de tipos.

Sabemos que o método `LabelFor` é genérico com os tipos `TModel` e `TValue`, e também que ele recebe dois argumentos, ambos utilizando esses tipos genéricos:

- `this HtmlHelper<TModel> html`
- `Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression`

Imagine a seguinte view contendo cshtml, cujo tipo do modelo seja `MeuModelo` e tenha uma propriedade `MinhaProp` do tipo `string`:

```
@model MeuModelo
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.MinhaProp)
```

O C#, sabe que o `LabelFor` é um método de extensão, e vai traduzir a chamada do método para:

```
System.Web.Mvc.Html.LabelExtensions.LabelFor(Html, x => x.MinhaProp)
```

Como o código acima não define os tipos genéricos `TModel` e `TValue` para o método `LabelFor`, então o C# vai ter que inferir ("adivinhar") quais são os tipos. Isso é feito através dos argumentos sendo passados para o método:

- O argumento `html` está recebendo o valor de `Html`. Isso quer dizer que `HtmlHelper<TModel>` é igual a `HtmlHelper<MeuModelo>`. É possível ver que `TModel` tem que ser `MeuModelo`.

  ```
  parâmetro      |  html  |  HtmlHelper<TModel>
  valor passado  |  Html  |  HtmlHelper<MeuModelo>

  conclusão: TModel = MeuModelo
  ```
- O argumento `expression` é do tipo `Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>>`... só que como o C# já sabe que `TModel` é igual a `MeuModelo`, então pode substituir no tipo do parâmetro que fica assim:

  `Expression<Func<MeuModelo, TValue>>`

  Esse tipo significa **"expressão que recebe `MeuModelo` e retorna `TValue`"**. Agora só falta saber qual é o tipo de `TValue`.

  O parâmetro está recebendo `x => x.MinhaProp`. Essa lambda recebe `x` e retorna `x.MinhaProp`. Então é possível construir a seguinte tabela para analisar os tipos:

  ```
            |  Expression<Func<MeuModelo, TValue>>  |  x => x.MinhaProp
  ----------+---------------------------------------+---------------------
    recebe  |              MeuModelo                |     x
    retorna |              TValue                   |     x.MinhaProp
  ```

  Na primeira linha é possível ver que `x` é d tipo `MeuModelo`. Sendo assim, `x.MinhaProp` é do tipo `string`. E finalmente `TValue` é do tipo `string`.

A inferência de tipos acabou, com as seguintes conclusões:

- `TModel` é o tipo `MeuModelo`
- `x` é do tipo `MeuModelo`
- `TValue` é o tipo `string`

E agora é possível preencher os tipos genéricos do `LabelFor`:

```
System.Web.Mvc.Html.LabelExtensions.LabelFor<MeuModelo, string>(Html, x => x.MinhaProp)
```

Comment: Entendi. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

LabelFor usa o seu Model configurado na View para renderizar um Label.

Exemplo:

// Model

```
public class SeuModel
{
    [DisplayName("Propriedade do model")]
    public string SuaPropriedade { get; set; }
}
```

Gera um Label na sua View relacionado a propriedade do seu Model:

// View

```
@model SeuModel
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.SuaPropriedade)
```

O "m" é o SeuModel. O parâmetro em forma `m => m.SuaPropriedade` é uma **expressão lambda**.

Resultado em html:

```
<label for="SuaPropriedade">Propriedade do model</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

A ideia aqui foi dar uma ideia geral sobre *lambda* que o que foi usado no parâmetro referido. Leia as outras respostas para obter informações mais completas sobre todo o recurso, especial a do Miguel Angelo.

Isso chama-se [lambda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function). Veja a [documentação do C# sobre o assunto](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Ela é uma função sem nome que é usada como uma expressão. É uma forma de passar ações que devem ser realizadas por algum outro algoritmo em determinado momento. Desta forma quando você declara a *lambda* você não está executando nada, está apenas definindo o que ela deve fazer. O código que ela a recebe em momento adequado a chamará como se fosse um método normal e neste momento é que aquela ação será executada. A execução exata disto é um pouco diferente de uma chamada normal, mas desta forma fica fácil você entender. Desta forma você passa informações de uma forma um pouco mais rica, você não está passando simplesmente valores, você passa toda uma estrutura de dados.

Neste caso você está dizendo que simplesmente está pegando o parâmetro `x` que a *lambda* está recebendo e usado este valor como `Label` naquele lugar. Este `x` receberá um valor passado pelo *engine* do ASP.Net MVC. Ele sabe o que passar e ele sabe quando usá-lo, ele só não sabe o que fazer com esta informação antes de usá-lo. No caso nem está fazendo nada importante mas poderia executar uma série de coisas com ele.

No segundo exemplo já faz um pouquinho mais. O parâmetro é `model` mas você não que usar o `model` pura e simplesmente, provavelmente nem daria, você está pegando um membro de `model`. Você está pegando `model.Propriedade` e é o valor deste membro que será usado no `Label`.

[Lambda pode receber outros nomes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/34915/101).

Comment: No C#, uma lambda pode ser convertida em duas coisas: `Delegate` ou `Expression<TDelegate>`. Sua explicação considera o primeiro caso, e é totalmente válida para entender lambdas. Ocorre que `LabelFor` (do `ASP.NET MVC`) se utiliza do segundo caso, no qual a lambda é convertida em uma AST, da qual metadados podem ser extraídos (e.g. label, se é required, formato, etc.), sendo que `x` é do tipo do próprio modelo, que é definida pelo usuário dentro do arquivo da view. P.S. Odeio ser crítico, ainda mais de alguém que ajuda tanto! No mais, gostei da referência à origem matemática das lambdas.

Comment: @MiguelAngelo você tem razão, dei uma melhorada. Você deve ser crítico, isto é qualidade e não defeito. De qualquer forma vou deixar mais como um complemento, a sua está bem melhor para o contexto.