# Método de listar não retorna objetos

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Método com EF
    Listar

```
internal List<Arquivo> GetAllArquivo()
    {
        using (var ctx = new TESTEntities())
        {
            var arquivos = (
                    from ver in ctx.ARQUIVO
                    select new Arquivo()
                    {
                        ARQUIVO_GUID = ver.ARQUIVO_GUID,
                        XARQUIVO = ver.XARQUIVO,
                        TAG = ver.TAG,
                        URL = ver.URL,
                        EXTENSAO = ver.EXTENSAO,
                        IS_STREAM = ver.IS_STREAM,
                        ULT_ARQUIVO_VERSAO_GUID = ver.ULT_ARQUIVO_VERSAO_GUID,
                        TIPO_DE_ARQUIVO_GUID = ver.TIPO_DE_ARQUIVO_GUID,
                        DIRETORIO_GUID = ver.DIRETORIO_GUID
                    }
                ).ToList();

            return arquivos;
        }
    }
```

Eu quero acessar os dados do método para retornar um objeto especifico:
 ex:

```
meuDal.GetAllArquivo().XARQUIVO
```

Porem não encontra nada, eu tenho outros métodos de lista que funcionam, e esse não.

Comment: Infelizmente não consigo ajudar nesta, pelo que está apresentado não vejo nada errado (mas pode estar me escapando algo) e não tenho como testar este trecho). Mas eu tenho uma curiosidade e uma dica. Por que você gosta de usar estes identificadores em maiúsculo? Você sabia que para casos assim você pode usar um `foreach` comum? LINQ não foi feito para fazer o que você faz com ele. Se é para pegar os dados sem manipulá-los de nenhuma forma e materializá-los em seguida e depois só trabalhar com o materializado, é melhor montar a lista sem LINQ. É mais fácil e mais rápido.

Comment: Quando você chama meuDal.GetAllArquivo() ele retorna uma lista de Arquivo, se quiser pegar 1, faça assim meuDal.GetAllArquivo().FirstOrDefault().XARQUIVO

Comment: Infelizmente é projeto pronto que peguei não posso opinar ainda(Depois vou questionar sobre isso).

Comment: Funcionou @PauloHDSousa vlw, como faço para pegar em um determinado indice? em java uso o get(i)

Comment: coloca como resposta a solução.

Comment: @bigown a unica coisa que vejo de o porque dessas sintaxe errada nesse projeto c#, é que esse sistema é um webservice, que será consumido por clientes antigos(programadores delphi) e talvez eles estejam acostumados com essa forma, e fizeram esse c# com os  Atributos assim, talvez so pra facilitar os outros,está totalmente errado mas não posso opinar ainda(Depois vou procurar saber)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você chama `meuDal.GetAllArquivo()` ele retorna uma lista de Arquivo, se quiser pegar 1, faça assim `meuDal.GetAllArquivo().FirstOrDefault().XARQUIVO`

Ele irá retornar o primeiro registro da lista,

Caso queira um especifico, pode fazer assim:

```
meuDal.GetAllArquivo().Where(a => a .ARQUIVO_GUID == 'uid').FirstOrDefault().XARQUIVO
```

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado!

Comment: esse a=> significa o que?

Comment: É o modo de fazer consultas no ENTITY com LAMBDA, eu prefiro assim do que do modo que você faz.
http://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-csharp-orientacao-objetos/linq-e-lambda/

Link comparando LAMBDA e LINQ:https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/jj128159.aspx

Comment: valeu vou da uma olhada.

Comment: @WarLock quando você tem alguma dúvida sobre algo que leu em alguma resposta, tem uma grande chance de já ter uma outra resposta no SOpt sobre isto. E se não tiver, provavelmente você deveria fazer a pergunta para alguém receber. Neste caso veja: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34907/101 E lembre-se que você pode votar em tudo o que existe no *site*, nas respostas que deram para você, em outras respostas, em perguntas. A aceitação não é a única forma de recompensar o conteúdo postado por todos.

Comment: beleza, vou me ligar nisso...