# Diferenças entre readonly Func<> e método normal

Tags: c#, .net, expressões-lambda, método

Esquecendo um pouco questões como legibilidade, qual seria as diferenças entre as seguintes chamadas?

#### Usando `readonly Func<T1, T2, TResult> = (T1, T2) => { return default(TResult); }`

```
private readonly Func<int, int, int> Soma = new Func<Func<int, int, int>>(() => {
    var total = default(int);
    return (numA, numB) => {
        total += numA + numB;
        return total;
    };
})();
```

#### Usando `Method(T1, T2) { return default(TResult); }`

```
private int total = 0;
private int Soma()
{
    total += numA + numB;
    return total;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basicamente o primeiro é um método anônimo definido por um [delegado](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/reference-types?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) ([guia de uso](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)). No caso o delegado é [pré definido com a assinatura usada](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-3?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0). Então o seu "conteúdo" pode ser "armazenado" em uma variável, como foi feito.

O `readonly` foi usado para não permitir que o seu conteúdo possa ser trocado. Uma das grandes vantagens do uso de delegados (no caso usando uma sintaxe de *lambda*) é poder trocar o conteúdo (o que deve ser executado) e dar flexibilidade para a aplicação. Neste caso específico onde isto não é possível, não vejo tanta vantagem, claro que depende do contexto onde for usado, tem situações que pode ser interessante, inclusive evitar alguns padrões de projeto como o Strategy, por exemplo.

O `return` é desnecessário ali no cabeçalho, poderia ter escrito assim:

```
(numA, numB) => total += numA + numB;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/LambdaSyntax.cs).

O segundo é um método normal tratado pela linguagem. Tem um suporte melhor pelo compilador podendo ser usado em mais situações.

O primeiro tem algumas limitações de uso de genéricos que o segundo não tem. O segundo, de forma geral, será chamado pelo `Soma()` e terá que estar disponível no contexto. O primeiro será chamado pelo nome da variável que estiver segurando uma referência para este corpo de código. E isto pode ser passado para outros contextos. Até é possível jogar o método normal em uma variável que espere um método com a mesma assinatura, mas é menos comum.

Em termos de resultado não muda nada. A performance do primeiro é ligeiramente inferior porque há uma [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101) e tem uma infra de [*closure*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34907/101). Também consome um pouco mais de memória.

Um delegado é uma tipo que possui um ponteiro para o código a ser executado e para as variáveis que ela enclausura (no caso a `total`, mas no outro exemplo tem esse custo também). É um dado, é um objeto, e todo objeto ocupa memória. A chamada do método tem que consultar este endereço armazenado antes, causando a indireção e um custo de processamento extra. Além disso, por ser uma indireção é mais complicado, se não impossível fazer certas otimizações. O método direto é todo resolvido pelo compilador e não tem *overhead*. [Veja um teste](http://blog.avangardo.com/2011/02/method-call-vs-delegate/).

As variáveis locais de um método normal são colocadas na [*stack*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101). No método delegado elas ficam no [*heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101) (dentro desse objeto criado para suportar o delegado/*closure*) já que precisam estar disponíveis em outros contextos.

O primeiro tem dificuldade maior para escolha de *overload* no caso de ter métodos com assinaturas diferentes/*default arguments*. A decisão é melhor em métodos normais.

Posso estar enganado, mas vejo pouca necessidade da sintaxe ser complexa assim. Acho que o código poderia ser simplificado. Me parece que o primeiro está tentando simular uma classe também. Também não precisa do `return` no segundo caso.