# Finalidade da sintaxe de lambda em função/método

Tags: c#, funções, expressões-lambda, característica-linguagem, método

Em alguns casos uma função/método contem apenas uma linha em seu escopo, veja o exemplo ilustrativo:

```
static int Soma(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

Entretanto, a uma [nova característica no C# 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/24/c-sharp-6-0-features/44/expression-bodied-properties-and-methods#t=201607221702139608572) que permite declarar uma função/método em expressão lambda em apenas uma linha, veja no exemplo ilustrativo:

```
static int Subtrai(int a, int b) => a - b;
```

E a maneira de chamar essas funções e a mesma:

```
var resultadoSoma = Soma(10, 5);
var resultadoSubtracao = Subtrai(10, 9);

WriteLine($"Resultado da soma = {resultadoSoma}\nResultado da subtração = {resultadoSubtracao}");
```

Saída:

> Resultado da soma = 15
> Resultado da subtração = 1

[Dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AvU7v6) completo do exemplo.

---

## Dúvidas

Isso me gerou as seguintes dúvidas:

1. Existe alguma limitação em uma função/método em sintaxe lambda, se
   sim quais?
2. Essa função/método em sintaxe lambda pode ser chamada de delegate?
3. Qual é a finalidade desta nova característica?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Existe alguma limitação em uma função/método em sintaxe lambda, se sim quais?

Apenas que ela só pode ser "uma linha" com uma expressão que é seu retorno. Até o C# 6 não podia ser usado em qualquer método. Agora até construtores, destrutores e acessadores de propriedade podem usar.

> Essa função/método em sintaxe lambda pode ser chamada de delegate?

Não, ela é uma função normal, só a sintaxe é semelhante a *lambda*, não tem as mesmas características de uma função anônima. A semântica é de função "pura".

> Qual é a finalidade desta nova característica?

Tornar o código mais curto e mais agradável de ler, nada mais.

Leitura complementar: [Diferenças entre readonly Func<> e método normal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125936/101) e [Qual é a finalidade do operador => no uso de listas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/99379/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).