# Quais as diferenças entre local functions, delegates e expressões lambdas?

Tags: c#, expressões-lambda, delegate

As funções locais estarão presentes no C# 7. Dado isto, gostaria de saber as principais diferenças entre *local functions*, *delegates* e expressões *lambdas*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A diferença entre *delegate* e *lambda* já foi [respondida em outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34907/101).

Uma [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/142150/101) talvez ajude entender que função é uma coisa e *lambda* é outra, mesmo que a sintaxe possa ser parecida.

Uma função local não pode ser confundida com uma função delegada porque não há [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101) extra nela.

A função local para todos efeitos é uma função como outra qualquer, mas tem um escopo local à função onde ela foi definida. Ninguém pode chamar essa função local a não ser a função que a contém.

A função local não sai de dentro de onde ela foi criada, ao contrário de uma *lambda* que pode ter seu tempo de vida estendido retornando uma referência para ela, ou mesmo podendo colocar uma referência em algum objeto que tem [tempo de vida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101) maior que a função.

Já dei [uma resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/130240/101) dando um exemplo de função local e como ela é diferente de uma *lambda*.

A função local não acrescenta nada revolucionário na linguagem, só permite encapsular um pouco algum código. Antes você podia proteger uma função para não ser acessada de fora de seu tipo (classes, estrutura, etc.). Mas mesmo uma função privada poderia ser chamada por qualquer função daquele tipo. A função local internaliza-a em apenas uma função que poderá chamá-la. Sempre deu pra viver sem isso, mas agora podemos organizar melhor.

Exemplo:

```
static void mostraNome(string nome) {
    string transformaMaiuscula(string str) { //não pode ser chamada fora de mostraNome
        return str.ToUpper();
    }
    Console.WriteLine(transformaMaiuscula(nome));
}
```

Ou em sintaxe simplificada:

```
static void mostraNome(string nome) {
    string transformaMaiuscula(string str) => str.ToUpper(); //isto não é lambda
    Console.WriteLine(transformaMaiuscula(nome));
}
```

Se fosse uma *lambda* seria bem diferente:

```
static Func<string, string> mostraNome(string nome) {
    Func<string, string> transformaMaiuscula = (string str) => str.ToUpper();
    Console.WriteLine(transformaMaiuscula(nome));
    return transformaMaiuscula; //poderá executar a lambda fora daqui
}
```

Depois pode fazer isto:

```
Func<string, string> funcao = mostraNome("João");
string maiusculo = funcao("José"); //está chamando a lambda
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Lambda/LocalFunc.cs).

Então concluímos que são coisas que não tem nenhuma relação.