# O que são os métodos anônimos e qual a principal finalidade deles?

Tags: c#, .net, função-anônima

Sei que são usados pra trabalhar em conjunto com `delegates`, mas as fontes que encontrei se mostraram um pouco confusas na minha opinião.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Método anônimo é um método sem nome, é um método que não tem um símbolo associado a ele em tempo de compilação.

Você tem apenas uma referência para o código e esta referência pode ser atribuída para uma variável de qualquer tipo, passado como argumento para outro método ou retornado de um método.

O delegado é apenas uma sintaxe para definir um método anônimo. Mas o delegado pode ter um nome associado também. O delegado em uso direto é praticamente obsoleto em aplicações normais.

```
delegate(string i) { WriteLine(i); };
```

Hoje usa-se a sintaxe da *lambda* que sempre é anônima.

```
(i) => WriteLine(i);
```

Por exemplo pode fazer:

```
public Action<string> Metodo() {
    Action<string> func = (i) => WriteLine(i);
    func("teste"); //imprime teste
    return func;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/Anonymous.cs).

Desta forma o método não tem nome, mas a variável que o suporta tem. Obviamente que no momento que retorna o método anônimo ele provavelmente será atribuído para outra variável, então o nome é provisória, está ligado ao seu suporte e não ao método.

Mais detalhes em [Qual a diferença entre uma expressão lambda, um closure e um delegate?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34907/101).

Answer (score 5):

É uma forma de criar um delegate, assim como expressões lambda.

O C# ao longo de sua evolução foi introduzindo novas formas de criar delegates, o que praticamente torna as versões anteriores pouco utilizadas, quase inutilizadas eu diria... é o caso aqui.

Um método anônimo é chamado assim, pois não é referenciável via um nome estático (quero dizer, um nome em tempo de compilação, estaticamente analisável =D ).

No [site da Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/anonymous-functions) tem exemplos sobre essa evolução.

**C# 1:**

```
// Sintaxe original de delegate requer a
// inicialização com um método nomeado.
TestDelegate testDelA = new TestDelegate(M);
```

O `M` acima é um método nomeado:

```
static void M(string s)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}

// Chamando o delegate.
testDelA("Delegate criado com argumento, usando um Method Group.");
```

**C# 2:**

```
// C# 2.0: Um delegate pode ser inicializado com
// código inline, chamado da "método anônimo."
// Nesse formato, o tipo dos argumentos é explícito.
// Note que o método não possui um nome.
TestDelegate testDelB = delegate(string s) { Console.WriteLine(s); };
```

**C# 3:**

```
// C# 3.0. O delegate pode ser inicializado a partir
// de uma expressão lambda. Neste caso, já se evoluiu para haver
// inferência de tipos. O tipo de `x` é inferido a partir do
// tipo de delegate TestDelegate.
TestDelegate testDelC = (x) => { Console.WriteLine(x); };
```

O tipo `TestDelegate`:

```
delegate void TestDelegate(string s);

testDelB("That's nothing. I'm anonymous and ");
testDelC("I'm a famous author.");
testDelD("I'm a famous author.");
```

**C# 7:**

E agora o C# 7, possui funções locais, o que avança mais um pouco nas formas de se definir um delegate, que não esta nesse documento da Microsoft (está desatualizado pelo visto).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    testDelD(Exemplo usando função local.");

    void testDelD(string x) { Console.WriteLine(x); }
}
```

O interessante é que funções locais trazem de volta os nomes... deixados de lado para métodos anônimos e expressões lambda.

Comment: Função local nada tem a ver com `delegate` ou métodos anônimos, ou qualquer coisa do tipo. É o equivalente a um método normal só que privado ao método onde foi declarado, com algumas limitações óbvias. Já respondi sobre isto em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181290/101

Comment: No próprio site está dito que funções anônimas são o conjunto de métodos anônimos + expressões lambda. Eu usei o link como referência para mostrar a evolução da linguagem e justificar o que disse sobre estar ultrapassado, só isso. =D

Comment: Tem referência disto? Porque está claramente errado, não tem nada de expressão *lambda* ou método anônimo em função local, são mecanismos muito diferentes (na superfície ou internamente), com compromissos diferentes, com objetivos diferentes, a única coisa em comum é que eles tem parâmetros, código no corpo e possível retorno.

Comment: Acho que você se referia a funções locais... mas mesmo assim, não são apenas funções no escopo local. Elas podem capturar variáveis do escopo externo (ao dela própria), e podem ser posteriormente armazenadas em um delegate.

Comment: Não podem, elas acessam variáveis de escopo externo até porque elas estão no mesmo escopo, para todos os efeitos é como se ela fosse um `while`ou um `if` ou só `{ ... }`, mas sem captura e se forem usadas em uma *closure* é outra coisa totalmente distinta não associado ao fato de ser uma função local.

Comment: Como não podem... coloca uma função local dentro de um for. Usa o iterador dentro dela, fazendo uma cópia antes, para outra variável. E ai você vai ver que a variável é capturada.

Comment: `Action<string> lista = null; for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) { var i2 = i; void testDelD(string x) { Console.WriteLine(i2 + x); } lista += testDelD; } lista(" -
 X");`

Comment: Pelo que eu entendo, função local é a definição sintática do recurso. O que o compilador ou o JITTER faz por traz é desconectado. Assim como quando o assunto é se um objeto qualquer está na pilha ou na heap, baseando-se no fato de ser struct ou class.

Comment: Não teve captura na função local, apenas acessou a variável que estava no escopo vigente. A captura ocorreu no método anônimo que delega a execução para a função local. Sem um delegado não tem como fazer isto. A não ser que tenhamos definições diferentes de captura. Ter acesso à variável do escopo externo pra mim não é captura, embora eu vi artigo usando este termo, mas ele está errado, a captura depende de uma infraestrutura para carregar a variável para onde quiser e só um delegado tem isto.

Comment: E não foi o que ocorreu? Ela não apenas acessou a variável, mas também copiou o valor e levou junto. O mesmo ocorreria com uma lambda atribuída a um delegate. Acho que estou entendendo o que você quer dizer... da mesma forma que uma expressão lambda não é nem delegate nem ExpressionTree até ser usada, uma função local não é nada também até que seja usada. Beleza! ... entretanto, o foco da minha resposta é na evolução das formas como criar delegates. Para mim, essa parece ser uma nova forma. Assim como foi a forma usando expressões lambda quando ela surgiu.

Comment: Vai que daqui a pouco resolvem que funções locais podem ser usadas para criar ExpressionTrees. A questão então é que todas as coisas são qualquer coisa, basta que o compilador dê suporte para tal.

Comment: Função local não é uma evolução do `delegate`, não vou repetir o que eu já disse sobre isto, tanto que teve criar ambos para obter o que queria. Sobre o futuro eu não sei, sei que hoje são coisas distintas, com infraestrutura diferente para obter resultados finais e comprometimento de processamento e memória diferentes. Mas deixa pra lá, fica aqui a ressalva que isto está errado, já disse o que tinha pra dizer, ficará repetitivo.