# Isso é uma property, atributo de classe ou o quê?

Tags: c#, sintaxe, propriedade

Tenho isso em meu código:

```
public ICommand ChangePositionCommand => new Command((obj) =>
        {
            _positionIndex++;
            if (_positionIndex >= Positions.Count)
                _positionIndex = 0;
            Position = Positions[_positionIndex];
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Position));
        });
```

posso afirmar que isso é um atributo de classe, uma property ou o que?

Comment: Veja a edição da resposta.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A resposta original está abaixo e está errada porque a forma nova de escrever deu margem para entender errado (ninguém mais percebeu - curioso como coisas certas recebem negativos e as erradas não). A certa é:

Isso é uma propriedade. É bem óbvio, não tem parênteses, e todo método tem seu identificador seguido de parênteses. Como isto poderia ser um método?

Essa é uma propriedade que está sendo inicializada com um valor, no caso uma *lambda* e que você só pode pegar este valor já que não foi criado nem um *getter* nem um *setter*. Neste caso o compilador cria o *getter* para acessar este valor, caso contrário seria melhor eliminar tudo já que seria inacessível.

Veja como [realmente é assim no **SharpLab**](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgzAAhgJiQRgOwIN4FgBQAkPOgGwJgB2w6AHABQCUCAvAHwJoDcBxiVNAMIALAIaUA5gFMACgHsAzmGBg5lQXIC2m8QBNWHbgQC+QA).

Não deixa de se transformar em um método `get`, mas no seu código é uma propriedade.

Eu ainda acho que poderia ser feito de forma mais simplificada, mas deve ser exigência de algum *framework*.

---

Isso é um método. O uso da [notação `=>`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/142150/101) neste caso não é adequada já que existe mais de uma linha efetivamente, embora seja um único *statement*.

Tenho dúvidas se o código assim é necessário ou deveria ser desta forma, mas não é possível afirmar sem contexto.

Mais legível:

```
public ICommand ChangePositionCommand {
    return new Command((obj) => {
        _positionIndex++;
        if (_positionIndex >= Positions.Count)
            _positionIndex = 0;
        Position = Positions[_positionIndex];
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Position));
    });
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/OneStatementMethod.cs)

[Atributo garanto que não é](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101).

Comment: Maniero, a minha dúvida surgiu devido ao "**;**" ao final com parêntesis após chaves.

Comment: É para finalizar o *statement* da declaração da *lambda*.

Comment: Marquei duas vezes a resposta e não foi. Essa será a terceira.

Answer (score 1):

Isso é um método GET introduzido nas versões mais recente do C#:

```
public int X { get {return A + B;}}
```

Equivale a isso:

```
public int X => A + B;
```