# Expression-bodied é recomendado? Tem diferença de performance?

Tags: c#, desempenho, expressões-lambda, sintaxe

Até que ponto é recomendado, ou até mesmo é boa prática utilizar *expression-bodied*?

Eu sei que as *expression-bodied* permitem que as propriedades, métodos, operadores e outros membros de função tenham corpos definidos com a utilização expressões *lambda* (`=>`) ao invés de blocos de instrução, o que ajuda a reduzir a quantidade de código e dá uma visão mais clara sobre as expressões.

Essa prática impacta no desempenho ou é somente "visual", deixando o código mais enxuto?

Exemplo abaixo:

Sem *expression-bodied*:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Quantidade { get; set; }
    public double Preco { get; set; }
    public double Total
    {
        get
        {
            return Quantidade * Preco;
        }
    }
}
```

Com *expression-bodied*:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Quantidade { get; set; }
    public double Preco { get; set; }
    public double Total => Quantidade * Preco;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Foi criado, então é recomendado. De forma geral não há contraindicações no uso que ele foi projetado, que é algo que apenas tem uma expressão simples e já a retorna.

Eu gostaria que as pessoas entendessem que a linguagem coloca essas coisas porque ela quer ser menos verbosas e quer reduzir o número de linhas. E que assim as pessoas pensassem que outras coisas que fazem que aumentam o número de linhas e não é tão adequando quanto pensam, porque elas aprenderam que aquilo era "boa prática" (que eu crítico sempre aqui no site e [palestrei](https://www.meetup.com/SoroCodigos/photos/29174486/473841731/?_locale=pt-BR) sobre isto).

Não é o mesmo que um [`var`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47383/101) por exemplo, que tem casos que há dificuldades no seu uso. Este só não usa quem não quer, e gosto não se discute, apenas lamenta-se :)

Desempenho muda nada. Semântica também não, ou qualquer outro critério, é só mais legível na segunda forma, a não ser que a pessoa não saiba programar. Mas a solução para isto é a pessoa aprender.

[Veja no **ShapLab** como fica a forma *expression bodied*](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgzAAhgJgQSWAUwLYFgBQA3gQqUomAHbAICKArgIbVgAmjrmChCA5psADcCAM4DhAXxJl4CVgHt6AIwhcACgCdMAY3nc+40Yan4y5OYpVcAKvOCMICALwA+OkxbtOCAFQJNOvKCBBJAA==) e a [forma mais verbosa](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgzAAhgJgQSWAUwLYFgBQA3gQqUomAHbAICKArgIbVgAmjrmChCA5psADcCAM4DhAXxJl4CVgHt6AIwhcACgCdMAY3nc+40Yan4y5OYpVcAKvOCMI00sVNmy/YE7cu3vpAHY6JhZ2TgQAKgRNHXlBLzMTBIIJIA===).

Só não ache que isto tem a ver com expressão *lambda*, não é, a semântica disto e [*lambda* é muito diferente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/142150/101) e tem diferença de desempenho. Apenas a sintaxe é a mesma, mas é outro mecanismo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação! Eu estava utilizando bastante justamente por ajudar na diminuição do número de linhas e também deixar o código mais simples, em minha opinião. Só queria tirar essas dúvidas ali mesmo, obrigado!!

Answer (score 3):

Como o objetivo é substituir as estruturas clássicas (`{  .. }` por exemplo) e deixar o código mais legível e conciso, não há razão para não usar.
Seu exemplo em específico irá compilar da mesma forma em *Intermediate Language*, o que vai gerar o mesmo resultado em tempo de execução, o que não irá ter diferença na performance.

Claro que, corpos de métodos ou mesmo propriedade mais complexes, com várias linhas de código e estruturas aninhadas, como `if` e `while` por exemplo, podem não ficar mais legíveis usando *expression bodied*, dai a boa e velha sintaxe deve cair melhor.

Neste link sobre o que há de novo no `C#`6.0, diz: [msdn.microsoft.com/](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/Dn802602.aspx)

> Expression bodied functions are another syntax simplification in C#
>   6.0

Ou seja,  são outra simplificação de sintaxe no C # 6.0, que vem para simplificar e não prejudicar.