# Diferença entre closures e functions

Tags: funções, groovy, grails, closures

*Closures* é uma *function* em Groovy ? Existe alguma diferença entre eles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma função é algo muito mais simples. A *closure* pressupõe mais coisas.

Ela certamente usa uma função, mas esta precisa ser de primeira ordem, ou seja, precisa poder ser usada como dados, pode ser usada em qualquer ponto onde faça sentido, incluindo armazenar em variáveis ou passar como argumento ou retorno de função.

Mas isto ainda só seria uma função anônima, possivelmente com uma sintaxe de *lambda*.

Ainda precisa capturar variáveis locais de onde ela foi definida e estas variáveis precisam fazer parte do escopo da função clausura, mesmo que ela seja usada fora do escopo onde foi declarada.

Mais pode ser visto em [Qual a diferença entre uma expressão lambda, um closure e um delegate?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34907/101), apesar de ser outra linguagem.