# Toda função anônima é uma closure?

Tags: funções, terminologia, programação-funcional, função-anônima, closures

Toda função anônima é considerada uma closure ou são consideradas apenas aquelas que referenciam o contexto onde foram criadas?

Gostaria de saber isso para distingui-las corretamente. Eu conheço os conceitos e as funcionalidades, mas a impressão é que muitos tratam ambas como se fossem iguais.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não, são mecanismos totalmente independentes. Embora tecnicamente seja possível ter um mecanismo de clausura em uma função que não seja anônima, só conheço implementações de *closure* em funções anônimas. Mas uma função anônima não tem obrigação de ter uma *closure*. Então na teoria não há necessidade de vinculação de ambas nos dois sentidos e na prática o que ocorre é haver vinculação em um sentido apenas.

O mecanismo da clausura é só capturar um valor contido em outro escopo para o [escopo da função anônima ampliando seu tempo de vida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101). Então se você não capturar esse valor dessa forma em uma função anônima não incluiu o mecanismo de enclausuramento.

Cada tecnologia pode implementar isso da forma que quiser internamente. Então pode ser que uma determinada linguagem faça com que todas as funções anônimas paguem o preço de poder ter uma clausura mesmo sem a captura de um valor. Isso não quer dizer que tem uma *closure* ali, apenas que tem a capacidade de ter. Mas reforço que é detalhe de implementação e só vale a pena saber por questões de otimização.

De fato as pessoas tendem achar que é a mesma coisa, mas não é. Existem diferenças sutis para os termos *lambda*, [funções de primeira classe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/227485/101) ou de [alta ordem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/150499/101).

Algumas tecnologias podem chamar do mesmo nome, por exemplo dizer que uma função anônima simples é uma *closure*, mas estritamente isso é errado. A linguagem que faz isso normalmente passa uma imagem de ignorância, ou arrogância ou ambos.

Uma função anônima pode ser implementada de forma muito simples só com um ponteiro para provocar [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101) e poder armazenar em alguns lugares. Uma *closure* precisa de um objeto um pouco mais complexo para manter os valores ou referências para as variáveis capturadas.

Pode ver mais em:

- [Qual a diferença entre uma expressão lambda, um closure e um delegate?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34907/101)
- [Como funcionam Closures em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1859/101)
- [O que caracteriza a programação imperativa e funcional?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/127121/101)
- [Linguagem imperativa incorporando elementos funcionais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/344162/101)
- [Diferença entre closures e functions](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/280715/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: "*só conheço implementações de closure em funções anônimas*", os decoradores no Python, em teoria, podem definir uma *closure* com funções nomeadas quando o decorador retorna uma função que é definida pelo contexto do próprio decorador.