# Quais são as principais diferenças entre Arrow Function e Closures (funções anônimas) no PHP?

Tags: php, funções, característica-linguagem, php-7.4

Na versão 7.4 do PHP, foi implementado *Arrow Functions*.

Exemplo:

```
$double = fn($x) => $x * 2;
var_dump($double(4)); // int(8)
```

Que poderia ser feito da seguinte forma em versões anteriores:

```
$double = function ($x) { 
   return $x * 2; 
}
```

Sei que isso ajuda bastante a melhorar a escrita para *callbacks* mais simples, no caso de funções como `array_map` ou `usort`.

Mas, além disso, existe alguma diferença de funcionamento, ou mesmo interna, entre *Arrow Functions* e *Closures*?

Comment: Relacionada: [Toda função anônima é uma closure ?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/453782/toda-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-an%c3%b4nima-%c3%a9-uma-closure#453786)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Influência da moda que as *arrow functions* no JavaScript se tornaram, sem dúvidas.

Em resumo, as diferenças são:

- Diferença sintática (as funções anônimas são sintaticamente diferentes das novas funções em flecha).
- Ao contrário de funções anônimas, que aceitam declarações **e** expressões (dentro de um bloco (`{ ... }`), *arrow functions* só podem possuir uma única expressão. Uma *arrow function* não tem um bloco, de modo que só pode avaliar (e retornar) uma única expressão.
- Diferenças em relação ao escopo (leitura e modificação de nomes de escopos superiores comportam-se de modo diferente).

### Leitura de variáveis de escopo superior

As *arrow functions* herdam todos os nomes de escopos superiores automaticamente. Na ciência da computação, esse comportamento chama-se [clausura](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausura_(ci%C3%AAncia_da_computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)) (do inglês *closure*). As *arrow functions* do PHP implementaram esse sistema de modo bem similar às [*closures* do JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1859/69296).

Só tome cuidado para não confundir esse nome com a classe [`Closure`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.closure.php), que o PHP já possui há algum tempo!

Desse modo, com as *arrow functions* você pode utilizar qualquer tipo de nome de algum escopo pai sem indicações explícitas. Já com as antigas funções anônimas, você deve "declarar" que está usando uma variável de escopo superior utilizando a [diretiva `use`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-180).

Veja um exemplo de código que utiliza função anônima:

```php
<?php
$exp = 3;
$nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

// Função anônima.
// Note que preciso declarar o uso de `$exp` explicitamente.
$result = array_map(function ($num) use ($exp) {
  return pow($num, $exp);
}, $nums);

print_r($result); //=> [1, 8, 27, 64, 125]
```

No exemplo acima, se a diretiva `use ($exp)` não tivesse sido utilizada, tal variável estaria indefinida no escopo da função. Receberia um aviso como:

> ```
> PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $exp in /Users/luiz/Dev/.Scripts/arrow-fn.php on line 9
> ```

Essa declaração de uso explícita não é necessária em *arrow functions*. Veja:

```
<?php
$exp = 3;
$nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

// Arrow function.
// Escopo léxico parente é "herdado":
$result = array_map(fn($num) => pow($num, $exp), $nums);

print_r($result); //=> [1, 8, 27, 64, 125]
```

Aproveito o exemplo anterior para ressaltar o fato de que *arrow functions* só podem retornar o resultado da avaliação de uma única expressão. No exemplo acima, a expressão que retornamos é o resultado da aplicação da função `pow` (potenciação).

### Impossibilidade da modificação de variáveis de escopo superior

Uma variável de escopo externo não pode ser modificada por uma *arrow function*. De você tentar realizar alguma modificação, será ignorada. Veja o exemplo da documentação<sup>[[1]](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php#example-188)</sup>:

```php
<?php
$x = 1;

$fn = fn() => $x++; // Não tem efeito
$fn();

print_r($x); //=> 1 (Não foi modificada!)
```

Sem dúvidas outro exemplo da influência que PHP está mostrando ter da programação funcional, que prega pela imutabilidade de valores. No entanto, fica o questionamento: será que PHP realmente precisa de aderir a esses princípios?

Comment: +1, mas tenho que destacar que a única parte problemática da resposta é essa afirmação: *"As arrow functions herdam todos os nomes de escopos superiores automaticamente. Isso se chama closure"*. Não digo um problema da resposta em si, mas o nome que o PHP deu, pois ele usa `Closure` para referenciar-se a função anônima [a função anônima das versões 7.3 <=]. Porém, as mesmas **não incluem as variáveis de escopos superiores automaticamente**. Tinha uma colega meu que falava que o PHP nomeou errado, já que `Closure` deveria herdar as variáveis, porém em PHP só funciona com `use($var)`

Comment: ... Apenas com a implementação de *Arrow Function* que isso se tornou verdadeiro. Agora fica a dúvida se isso foi mais uma bagunça interna do PHP.

Comment: Obrigado pelo comentário, @WallaceMaxters. Editei esse trecho para tentar clarificar um pouco mais. Melhorou? :)