# Definir critérios para ordenar uma lista de listas

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, classificação

Eu tenho uma lista de listas de strings.
Por exemplo uma lista, no qual as listas internas tem tamanho *n=3*:

```
listEx =  [['verde','preto','laraja'], ['rosa','lilás','azul'], ['bordô','cinza','branco'], [preto, roxo, amarelo]]
```

Se eu quiser ordenar a lista `listEx`, definindo como critério a posição 0 das listas interiores eu faço:

```
 lista = sorted(listEx, key = lambda x: x[0])
```

Porém o que eu desejo é definir um critério de desempate. Assim sendo, caso hajam duas listas com elementos iguais na posição 0, o critério de desempate deve ser a posição 1. Caso ainda assim persista o empate, tome por critério de desempate a posição 2. O mesmo vale até a posição `n`.

O impasse é que `n` é variável. Ou seja, dependendo da instância do problema, as listas internas tem cardinalidade diferentes. Porém, eu garanto que não haverão listas de tamanhos diferentes.

Talvez exista algo no Python como o `qsort` da linguagem C, em que crio uma função `compara_elementos`, podendo definir os meus critérios em forma de código.

Comment: Isso? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/347634/101

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma forma é criar uma função de comparação "à moda antiga" ([usada no Python 2](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#the-old-way-using-the-cmp-parameter)), que recebe 2 elementos e retorna um número negativo se o primeiro é "menor", um número positivo se o primeiro é "maior", ou zero se forem "iguais".

Depois você usa [`functools.cmp_to_key`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cmp_to_key), que converte esta função de comparação para uma [*key function*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-key-function), compatível com [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
def compare(list1, list2):
    for e1, e2 in zip(list1, list2):
        if e1 != e2:
            return 1 if e1 > e2 else -1
    return 0

import functools

listEx =  [
  ['verde','preto','laraja'],
  ['rosa','lilás','azul'],
  ['bordô','cinza','branco'],
  ['preto', 'roxo', 'amarelo'],
  ['azul', 'vermelho', 'roxo'],
  ['azul', 'vermelho', 'cinza']
]    
lista = sorted(listEx, key = functools.cmp_to_key(compare))
print(lista)
```

Eu uso [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) para percorrer as listas ao mesmo tempo, e vou comparando seus elementos (detalhe que `zip` vai parar quando a menor das listas tiver terminado, mas como você garante que todas têm o mesmo tamanho, isso não é uma preocupação). Se todos os elementos forem iguais, eu retorno `0`. Se eles forem diferentes, eu retorno o respectivo resultado (`-1` se o primeiro for menor, `1` se for maior).

O resultado é:

```
[['azul', 'vermelho', 'cinza'], ['azul', 'vermelho', 'roxo'], ['bordô', 'cinza', 'branco'], ['preto', 'roxo', 'amarelo'], ['rosa', 'lilás', 'azul'], ['verde', 'preto', 'laraja']]
```

Answer (score -1):

Um jeito de realizar essa comparação é você juntar os elementos das listas internas em uma única string antes de comparar. Essa ordenação só será valida se o critério de desempate for ordem alfabética, assim quando os dois primeiros elementos for azul, ele vai comparando os próximos elementos pela ordem alfabética.

```
listEx =  [['cinza', 'roxo','amarelo'], ['azul','laranja','verde'],['bordô','cinza','branco'],  ['azul','amarelo','preto'], ['azul','amarelo','verde']]
cores_ordenadas = sorted(listEx, key = lambda x: str().join((x)))
print(cores_ordenadas)
```

Saída:

```
[['azul', 'amarelo', 'preto'],
 ['azul', 'amarelo', 'verde'],
 ['azul', 'laranja', 'verde'], 
 ['bordô', 'cinza', 'branco'], 
 ['cinza', 'roxo', 'amarelo']]
```