# Ordenar uma lista baseado em dois critérios diferentes usando sorted

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, classificação

Eu tenho uma lista de tuplas e eu quero ordenar elas, o porém é que são dois critérios diferentes.

Cada tupla tem a seguinte configuração: `(peso, beneficio)`

A ordenação que eu quero fazer é da seguinte forma:

Do elemento com maior benefício para o com menor benefício. Caso duas tuplas tenham o mesmo valor de benefício o critério de desempate é o peso. A tupla com o menor peso ganha.

Portanto, dada a lista de tuplas:

```
[(4,2),(5,2),(7,3),(9,4),(6,4)]
```

A lista ordenada será:

```
[(6,4),(9,4),(7,3),(4,2),(5,2)]
```

Para utilizar dois elementos como critério de ordenação eu encontrei [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212870/sorting-a-python-list-by-two-fields) solução. Mas tentando usar retorna os dois campos com o mesmo critério.

```
listaqq = [(4,2),(5,2),(7,3),(9,4),(6,4)]
sortedLista = sorted(listaqq, key=operator.itemgetter(1,0), reverse=True)
```

> [(9, 4), (6, 4), (7, 3), (5, 2), (4, 2)]

Dando uma outra procurada aqui encontrei [esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/454624/definir-crit%c3%a9rios-para-ordenar-uma-lista-de-listas) possível solução, mas não consegui entender para aplicar da forma que preciso.

Teria alguma forma de fazer isso usando `sorted`?
Talvez usando lambda, mas como seria a expressão?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema de usar [`itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) ou tuplas (como sugerido em [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/478866/112052)) é que ambos os elementos serão ordenados pelo mesmo critério (ou ambos em ordem crescente, ou ambos em ordem descrescente). Mesmo se você usar `reverse=True`, isso será aplicado em ambos.

Se a ideia é que um seja em ordem decrescente e outro em ordem crescente, uma alternativa é inverter o sinal de um deles:

```
def comp(item): # primeiro item em ordem decrescente, segundo em ordem crescente
   return -item[1], item[0]

listaqq = [(4,2),(5,2),(7,3),(9,4),(6,4)]

sortedLista = sorted(listaqq, key=comp)
print(sortedLista) # [(6, 4), (9, 4), (7, 3), (4, 2), (5, 2)]
```

Ou, usando *lambda* em vez de uma função:

```
sortedLista = sorted(listaqq, key=lambda item: (-item[1], item[0]))
```

Nesse caso não precisa usar `reverse=True`. Como eu inverti o sinal do segundo elemento da tupla, eles serão ordenados em ordem decrescente. No caso de empate, será usado o valor do primeiro elemento (em ordem crescente).

O resultado será a lista `[(6,4),(9,4),(7,3),(4,2),(5,2)]`.

---

Já usando a [outra solução](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/454631/112052) que você viu:

```
def compare(t1, t2):
    # compara o segundo elemento de cada tupla, em ordem decrescente
    cmp = t2[1] - t1[1]
    if cmp == 0: # se forem iguais, compara o primeiro elemento de cada tupla, em ordem crescente
        cmp = t1[0] - t2[0]
    return cmp

import functools

sortedLista = sorted(listaqq, key = functools.cmp_to_key(compare))
print(sortedLista)
```

A ideia é que a função de comparação retorne um número negativo se o primeiro elemento é "menor" (ou seja, se deve vir antes na ordenação), `0` se forem iguais e um número positivo se for "maior" (se deve vir depois na ordenação).

Então eu posso simplesmente subtrair o segundo elemento da segunda tupla pelo segundo elemento da primeira: se o resultado for positivo, quer dizer que a primeira tupla deve vir depois na ordenação (ou seja, os elementos são ordenados em ordem decrescente).

Se o resultado da subtração é zero, quer dizer que o segundo elemento das tuplas são iguais, e aí eu faço o desempate pelo primeiro elemento (mas agora subtraindo o elemento da primeira tupla antes, para que seja em ordem crescente).

Por fim, eu uso [`cmp_to_key`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cmp_to_key) para que a função de comparação seja convertida para uma [*key function*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-key-function) e possa ser usada em `sorted`.

Answer (score 3):

O parâmetro "key" aceita qualquer função, que vai receber um elemento da sequência que vai ser ordenada, e deve retornar um elemento que possa ser comparado direto com ">" e "<" pelo Python.

O padrão de usar o "itemgetter" é para aproveitar essa função que já existe, de forma que o código fique mais elegante - mas eu, pessoalmente, acho que complica a legibilidade. (o itemgetter também pode ter um pequeno ganho de performance - mas teria que ser um trecho de código muito específico para isso realmente dar diferença - por exemplo, se for uma ordenação em milhões de resultados.)

Em suma, é só você criar sua própria função de chave. Como o Python consegue comparar tuplas, comparando o primeiro item, e se der empate, comparando o segundo item. No seu caso específico, é só inverter a tupla - devolver uma tupla em que o benefício seja comparado antes do peso:

```py
def comp(item):
   return item[1], item[0]

sortedLista = sorted(listaqq, key=comp, reverse=True)
```

Como as funções desse tipo são em geral simples, é comum se escrever a função de compararação como uma uma função "lambda" - funciona exatamente como uma função, mas pode conter uma única expressão, e não precisa do comando "return":

```py
sortedLista = sorted(listaqq, key=lambda item: (item[1], item[0]), reverse=True)
```

Comment: Acho que isso não produz o resultado esperado, pois no caso vai ordenar por `item[1]` em ordem decrescente, e o desempate com `item[0]` também será em ordem decrescente (mas o desempate deve ser em ordem crescente) - deixei [uma resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/478907/112052) com uma alternativa (mas não sei se foi gambiarra demais ou se tem um jeito mais elegante - fique à vontade para comentar lá)

Comment: ah - na verdade é só fazer `lambda item; -item[1], item[0] ` e tirar o reverse.

Comment: isso - como voce fez lá - eu mesmo usei sesse pattern nos últimos tempos - nem lembro onde.

Answer (score 3):

Para resolver esta questão podes utilizar o seguinte código:

```
listaqq = [(4, 2), (5, 2), (7, 3), (9, 4), (6, 4)]
print(sorted(listaqq, key=lambda c: (-c[1], c[0])))
```

Observe que neste código a função lambda está ordenando **listaqq** em função do **segundo** valor da `tupla` e, em caso de `empate`, o desempate se dará pelo **primeiro** valor da respectiva tupla.

Agora se você deseja trabalhar com quaisquer listas de tuplas, com valores inteiros, podes utilizar o seguinte código:

```
n = int(input('Quantos tuplas? '))
listaqq = list()
for d in range(1, n + 1):
    listaqq.append(tuple(map(int, input(f'Digite a {d}º tupla: ').split())))
print(sorted(listaqq, key=lambda c: (-c[1], c[0])))
```

Quando executamos este segundo código devemos digitar a quantidade de tuplas que queremos montar. Em seguida devemos digitar **todos** o valores de cada tupla, na **mesma** linha, **separados** por um só espaço e pressionar `enter`.

Posteriormente o código irá realizar a ordenação das tuplas em função do último índice de cada tupla.

Comment: Faltou fazer o desempate quando `c[1]` é igual, o seu código resulta em `[(9, 4), (6, 4), (7, 3), (4, 2), (5, 2)]` mas o resultado deve ser `[(6, 4), (9, 4), (7, 3), (4, 2), (5, 2)]` - deixei [uma resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/478907/112052) com uma alternativa para o desempate