# Diferença entre function factory e closure

Tags: r, terminologia

No livro [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/), aos capítulos [10](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html#closures) e [11](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functionals.html), o autor define *function factory* como:

> "a factory for making new functions"

**Tradução Google Translate**: uma fábrica para fazer novas funções.

E *closure* como:

> "functions returned by another function"

**Tradução Google Translate**: funções retornadas por outra função.

Então, uma *function factory* é uma função que cria *closures*? Por exemplo:

```
myfun <- function(x) {
  funs <- c(mean, median, sd, mad, IQR)
  lapply(funs, function(f) f(x, na.rm = TRUE))
}
```

pode ser considerada uma *function factory*. Enquanto que: `myfun` pode ser considerada uma *closure*, pois:

```
abc <- 1:10

myfun(abc)
```

Fiquei com dúvida em relação a estes conceitos, que parecem estar relacionados.

**[Informação complementar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/34907/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-uma-express%C3%A3o-lambda-um-closure-e-um-delegate?rq=1)**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Isso mesmo. Considere o exemplo:

```
power <- function(exponent) {
  function(x) {
    x ^ exponent
  }
}
square <- power(2)
```

Neste caso a função `power` é uma *function factory* e `square` é uma *closure*.
O nome *closure* vem porque elas incluem (*enclose* em inglês) o ambiente em que foram criadas. Neste caso, a *closure* `square` vai incluir o nome `exponent` no seu ambiente e quando for chamada usará o valor de `exponent`.

Fábricas de funções são abstrações legais, mas não tem muito mais utilidade do que uma função com múltiplos argumentos. Muito dos códigos com funções fábricas podem ser transformados usando a função `partial` do purrr, por exemplo:

```
power <- function(x, exponent) {
  x^exponent
}

square <- purrr::partial(power, exponent = 2)
```