# Conceito de delegate no Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, delegate

Vi que não existe suporte a *delegate* no flutter, há alguma forma de implementar algo do tipo? Acredito que um *callback* funcione, tentei formular alguns exemplos mas não estou conseguindo entender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vou falar de Dart e não de Flutter porque Flutter não é para ter isto, este é um mecanismo de linguagem e a linguagem é Dart, então pode usar isto em Flutter. Parece que as pessoas que estão aprendendo Flutter nem entendem o que estão usando.

Você sabia que *callback* é o nome da técnica que o *delegate* usa? Ou seja, está falando da mesma coisa. Acho que só porque o Flutter ou Dart não usa o termo *delegate* está com dificuldade. Ele tem sintaxe de *lambda*, portanto tem *delegate* sim, mesmo sem usar o nome. Veja [Qual a diferença entre uma expressão lambda, um closure e um delegate?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34907/101).

```
metodo(() => print('Hello, World!'))
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Dart/Delegate.dt).

Pronto está usando um *delegate* em Dart (considero que este `metodo()` fará alguma coisa e em determinado momento chamará uma execução parametrizada).

Comment: Obrigado maniero, como é bastante informação que estou tentando absorver ao mesmo tempo acabo por me atrapalhando um pouco.