# O que são escopo léxico e escopo dinâmico e quais são suas principais diferenças?

Tags: escopo-de-variáveis

O que são escopo léxico e escopo dinâmico e quais são suas principais diferenças?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

O escopo de uma variável determina em que partes do programa essa variável pode ser acessada. O exemplo mais simples (e mais conhecido) de escopo é o **escopo global** e o **escopo local**:

```
var x = 10;       // Escopo global - pode ser acessada em qualquer lugar, inclusive em f
function f() {
    var y = 20;   // Escopo local - pode ser acessada somente dentro de f
}
```

As linguagens de programação modernas suportam o conceito de **estruturas aninhadas**. Ou seja, uma estrutura de código contida em outra estrutura de código (em vez de estar no *top-level*):

```
class Foo {
    int x;
    void bar() { 
        int y;
    }

    class Baz { ... }
}
```

É nesse momento que surge uma dúvida: as estruturas "de dentro" têm acesso às estruturas "de fora" ou não? Cada linguagem implementa isso de uma forma.

```
var x = 0;

function foo() {
    var x = 10;
    return function() {
        return x;
    }
}
var bar = foo();

function baz() {
    var x = 20;
    bar();
}
baz(); // O que é retornado?
```

### Escopo dinâmico

Nas linguagens com escopo dinâmico, as funções podem acessar qualquer variável presente na [**pilha de execução**](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilha_de_chamada). No exemplo acima, como `baz` definiu `x = 20` e depois chamou `bar`, `bar` pode acessar esse `x`, e seu valor será `20`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse tipo de escopo está em desuso, já que é difícil acompanhar quais variáveis estão visíveis em cada momento, além de prejudicar o encapsulamento (i.e. uma chamada de função qualquer poderia a princípio modificar qualquer variável local da função chamadora). A grande maioria das linguagens modernas não utiliza esse tipo de escopo.

### Escopo léxico

Nas linguagens com escopo léxico, o que conta é a estrutura "gramatical" do programa, ou seja, se no código-fonte uma estrutura está aninhada em outra, a de dentro pode acessar variáveis na de fora. No exemplo, `bar` está aninhada a `foo`, então ela pode acessar sua variável `x` - mesmo que `foo` já tenha retornado e não esteja mais na pilha.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A figura acima é uma simplificação da [**Árvore Sintática Abstrata**](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81rvore_sint%C3%A1tica_abstrata) (*Abstract Syntax Tree* - AST) do código de exemplo. Repare que - num código bem identado - o nível de cada instrução nessa árvore correponde ao seu nível de identação no código-fonte. Na função anônima aninhada a `foo`, a variável `x` correponde à definição mais "próxima" na hierarquia de escopos (em verde).

A função anônima não define variáveis, `foo` define um `x`, e o *top-level* define `x`, `foo`, `bar` e `baz`. Como o `x` do `foo` está "mais próximo" que o `x` do *top-level*, ele é quem está acessível na função anônima. O `x` do `baz` nem é considerado - uma vez que ele não faz parte da hierarquia léxica - *ainda que* seja ele quem **chama** a função anônima (salva em `bar`).

Ou seja, é possível determinar com precisão quais variáveis estão acessíveis pela simples **leitura do código-fonte**, sem ter de visualizar mentalmente quem chama o quê e em que ordem.

Esse tipo de escopo é o mais comumente utilizado em linguagens modernas. Naquelas que permitem funções aninhadas (como no exemplo acima, em JavaScript), o acesso de uma função interna às variáveis locais da função externa é chamado [***closure*** (clausura)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1859/215), e exige uma ["pilha espaguete"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_stack) para ser possível. Outras, que não permitem funções aninhadas (como Java), ainda utilizam escopo léxico para determinar que as classes internas (*inner classes*) tenham acesso aos campos das classes externas (no segundo exemplo dessa resposta, a classe `Baz` tem acesso ao campo `x` da classe `Foo`).

Answer (score 14):

A partir do texto da [`Wikipedia`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29#Lexical_scoping_vs._dynamic_scoping)(*Lexical scope vs. dynamic scope*):

### O que é?

Em Ciência da Computação escopo é um contexto delimitante aos quais valores e expressões estão associados. Linguagens de programação têm diversos tipos de escopos. O tipo de escopo vai determinar quais tipos de entidades este pode conter e como estas são afetadas, em outras palavras, a sua semântica. Normalmente, o escopo é utilizado para definir o grau de ocultação da informação, isto é, a visibilidade e acessibilidade às variáveis em diferentes partes do programa.

### Escopo léxico vs. Escopo dinâmico

O escopo **léxico**(ou **estático**) foi introduzido pela linguagem ALGOL 60. O escopo é assim denominado, porque pode ser determinado estaticamente, ou seja, antes da execução.

O escopo léxico define o escopo em termos da estrutura léxica do programa.
Com escopo léxico, um nome sempre se refere ao seu ambiente léxico (mais ou menos) local. Esta é uma propriedade do texto do programa e é feita independente da pilha de chamadas em tempo de execução pela implementação da linguagem. Ou seja, O escopo léxico de uma declaração é a parte do texto do programa, onde a utilização do identificador é uma referência a essa declaração particular do identificador.

Pelo fato de esta correspondência só exigir a análise do texto do programa estático, este tipo de delimitação de escopo é também chamado de escopo estático.

O escopo estático é padrão em todas as linguagens baseadas na ALGOL, tais como Pascal, ADA e C, pois permite que o programador possa elaborar raciocínios sobre valores, parâmetros e referências a objetos (ou seja, variáveis, constantes, funções etc), como substituições de nome simples. Isso torna muito mais fácil fazer o código modular e se raciocinar sobre ele, já que a estrutura local de nomeação pode ser entendida isoladamente. Devido ao entendimento de que o escopo estático torna a programação mais confiável, há uma tendência a se rejeitar o escopo dinâmico.

Em contraste, o escopo dinâmico força o programador a antecipar todos os possíveis contextos dinâmicos nos quais o código do módulo pode ser invocado.

Com escopo dinâmico, cada identificador tem uma pilha global de vinculações. Introduzindo uma variável local com o nome de ***`x`*** empilha uma vinculação na pilha global ***`x`*** (*que pode estar vazia*), que estará desempilhada quando o fluxo de controle deixar o escopo. Avaliar ***`x`*** em qualquer contexto sempre produz a vinculação mais ao topo.

Em outras palavras, um identificador global refere-se ao identificador associado com o ambiente mais recente. Note-se que isso não pode ser feito em tempo de compilação, porque a pilha de vinculação só existe em tempo de execução, razão pela qual este tipo de delimitação é chamado de *escopo dinâmico*.

Considere esse exemplo feito em Pascal:

```
program A;

var I:integer; // Variável global
    K:char; --------------------------
                                      |  
    procedure B;                      |  
    var K:real; -----------------------
        L:integer;                    |
                                      | 
        procedure C;                  |
        var M:real;                   | 
        begin                         |
         (*escopo A+B+C*)             |
        end;                          |
                                      |
        procedure D;                  |
        var K:integer; ----------------
        begin
         (*escopo A+B+D*)
        end;

    begin
     (*escopo A+B*)
    end;
begin
 (*escopo A*)
end.
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A variável **`I`** é visível em todos os pontos, porque nunca é encoberta por outra variável de mesmo nome. A variável char **`K`** *é visível apenas no programa principal*, porque ela está encoberta pela variável **`K`** real visível no procedimento *B*, *C* e *D* apenas.

A variável **`L`** também é visível apenas nos procedimentos *B*, *C* e *D*, mas não esconde qualquer outra variável. 
A variável **`M`** é visível apenas no processo *C* e, portanto, não é acessível quer a partir do procedimento *B*, do procedimento *D*, ou do programa principal.

Além disso, os procedimentos *C* e *D* só são visíveis nos procedimentos *B*, *C* e *D* (*C e D são procedimentos com o mesmo pai estático e portanto, enxergam uns aos outros*), e, portanto, não podem ser chamados a partir do programa principal.

Além disso, poderia haver ainda outro procedimento *C* declarado no programa, fora do processo *B*. O lugar exato no programa em que *C* é chamado então determina qual procedimento *C* é chamado, e isto é precisamente análogo ao escopo de variáveis.

Answer (score 10):

**O que significa escopo de uma variável?**

O escopo de uma variável representa a área do programa onde esta é visível.

- Uma variável é visível em um comando se puder ser referenciada naquele comando.
- Uma variável é local a uma unidade de programa se for declarada nela.
- Uma variável é não-local a uma unidade de programa se for visível mas não tiver sido declarada nela.

A vinculação do tipo de dados de uma variável pode ser especificada de forma **estática** (**léxica**) ou **dinâmica**.

**Escopo estático (léxico)**

Em linguagens de programação com escopo estático (ou léxico), o escopo é determinado através da estrutura textual do programa. Usando escopo estático (léxico), a vinculação de um nome no ambiente é determinada pelo seguinte algoritmo:

1. Se o nome foi declarado no bloco de execução, aquela vinculação será
   usada. Caso contrário,
2. Se o nome não foi declarado no bloco em execução, ele deve ser
   buscado nos blocos que o envolvem, do imediatamente envolvente até o
   mais distante. Se todos os blocos envolventes tiverem sido
   verificados e a declaração não encontrada,
3. Se o nome está no ambiente global, aquela vinculação será usada,
   caso contrário não há vinculação para aquele nome no ambiente.

Pode-se informalmente dizer que o trecho de código onde um nome é visível é o bloco onde foi declarado e todos os blocos aninhados dentro dele, e por este motivo muitas vezes utiliza-se **"escopo léxico"** como sinônimo de **"escopo estático"**.

**Escopo dinâmico**

Em linguagens de programação com escopo dinâmico, o escopo é determinado através da linha de execução do programa, sendo dependente portanto da ordem de execução das rotinas. Usando escopo dinâmico, a vinculação válida para um nome é a criada mais recentemente durante a execução do programa, baseado em sequências de chamadas de unidades de programas, não no layout textual.

**Exemplo**

```
x: integer
procedure print_x()
begin
    print(x);
end
procedure p2
x: integer;
begin
    x= 4;
    print_x();
end
begin
    x = 3;
    p2();
end
```

Se o escopo for dinâmico o programa imprime 4.
Se o escopo for estático, o programa imprime 3.

Fonte: http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~inf1621/escopo.pdf

Comment: Para mim foi a resposta que definiu com mais clareza e objetividade o que é cada uma e a diferença. +1