# Como funciona o gerenciamento de métodos na memória em C#?

Tags: c#, .net, memória, gerenciamento-de-memória, clr

Em C# existe uma distinção clara entre tipos valor (structs) e tipos referência (classes), sendo essa distinção basicamente a forma com que o CLR gerencia instâncias de cada tipo. Instâncias de tipo valor são colocadas na pilha diretamente e instâncias de tipo referência são colocadas no heap, contendo uma referência na pilha.

Basicamente, isso é fácil de entender com tipos primitivos e classes simples que contém só campos. Nesses casos estamos falando de armazenar dados na memória e isso é algo simples de entender.

O problema é o fato de métodos também serem armazenados na memória. Classes podem conter métodos, e dessa forma, esses métodos devem ficar armazenados na memória de alguma forma quando criamos uma instância.

Além disso, usando delegates podemos apontar para métodos, o que novamente sugere que os métodos são armazenados na memória assim como dados.

Mas isso é estranho: o que viria a ser armazenar um método na memória? Um método não contém um "dado" que pode ser guardado, ele pode conter várias variáveis, vários comandos, etc. Não consigo entender como o CLR gerencia isso.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## Resumo

- Estado (campos) e comportamento (métodos) são coisas distintas e estão em áreas da memória diferentes.
- Um método não faz parte da composição interna de dados de uma classe ou estrutura.
- Método é apenas um conceito abstrato de linguagens orientadas a objeto. Na verdade eles são funções ordinárias.
- Métodos são códigos em uma posição fixa da memória e independem de suas instâncias.
- O código do método é, portanto, compartilhado por todas as instâncias de forma semelhante aos dados estáticos em uma classe. Ou seja, só existe uma vez e está disponível para toda aplicação.
- Para quem conhece linguagens que possuem alguma forma de funções e *structs*, como C, o método é a função, e os dados são as *structs* ficando em locais da memória diferentes, tendo apenas uma relação indireta.

## Detalhes

Você entende como funciona um computador, a memória, o processador? Tem noção de como um programa comum (nativo) funciona? Se não souber, outras perguntas podem ser necessárias para entender tudo.

Vou simplificar algumas coisas para facilitar o entendimento. Se for analisar profundamente alguns pequenos erros serão cometidos por esta simplificação, mas que não compromete nada, a não ser que deseje virar um *expert* no assunto.

#### Funcionamento do [CLR](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51281/101)

Primeiro é preciso entender alguns pontos de como o .Net funciona:

- Toda a memória de uma aplicação escrita para rodar no .NET é gerenciada pelo [CLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime). Não há nada que esta aplicação possa fazer que corrompa a memória (escrever ou acessar), exceto por algum *bug* no CLR. A memória é gerenciada por um coletor de lixo (*[garbage collector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science))*) que ao contrário do que o nome indica, não é usado só para desalocar memória, mas também para garantir a adequada alocação dos objetos (objetos em um sentido amplo, significando um conjunto de dados que fazem parte de uma coisa só, não só no conceito do paradigma de orientação a objeto). Na verdade há uma área não gerenciada, mas este é outro assunto.
- O CLR conta com um [JITter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101). Ou seja, um programa em qualquer linguagem compatível com .NET é compilada e gera um código intermediário, chamado [CIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language). Este código é uma forma de *[bytecode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode)*, que, grosso modo, é criado através de uma linguagem *Assembly* própria do .NET como pode ser vista no artigo em inglês da Wikipedia sobre a CIL.

  O JITter normalmente é executado quando um programa é iniciado, ou sob demanda em certas circunstâncias. Ele é uma espécie de compilador deste *bytecode*. Ele gera o código nativo, que é o código que o processador realmente entende, é o código que de fato será executado. No fim deste processo o código resultante é muito eficiente porque roda direto no processador da forma que ele espera. Se o compilador da linguagem que você está programando e o JITter forem muito eficientes, é **possível** ter um código tão rápido quanto ele tivesse sido escrito em C ou mesmo usando um Assembler. Mas em geral não é o que acontece na prática.
- Um método é um conceito análogo a uma função. Antes do paradigma OOP nós tínhamos apenas o conceito de função. E o processador costuma ter facilidades para lidar com funções. Mas um método nada mais é que uma função. **Concretamente um método não existe**, ele é um conceito abstrato para programadores entenderem melhor a organização da aplicação e não se preocupar com o mecanismo.

#### Métodos internamente

Um método em uma linguagem .NET é gerado mais ou menos desta forma na CIL:

```
.method private hidebysig static int32 Add(int32 x, int32 y) cil managed 
{ 
 // Code size 9 (0x9) 
 .maxstack 2 
 .locals init ([0] int32 CS$1$0000) 
 IL_0000: nop 
 IL_0001: ldarg.0 
 IL_0002: ldarg.1 
 IL_0003: add 
 IL_0004: stloc.0 
 IL_0005: br.s IL_0007 
 IL_0007: ldloc.0 
 IL_0008: ret 
}
```

Note que isto é uma representação para um humano entender, na prática apenas *bytes* que só o CLR entende determinam o código efetivo.

#### Gerando código nativo

Quando o JITter gera o código nativo que será executado ele precisa ser colocado na memória. Esta área da memória é controlada pelo CLR, sua aplicação não tem acesso direto a ela. Simplificadamente, apenas o JITter pode escrever lá e apenas o CLR pode permitir qualquer acesso de leitura a ela. A leitura evidentemente ocorre quando a execução está em andamento.

Um método quando já está em sua forma nativa é apenas um conjunto de *bytes* que o processador entende em uma parte da memória cujo endereço inicial está guardado em uma tabela de símbolos com os nomes de todas as funções (lembre-se que método não existe concretamente) disponíveis para sua aplicação.

Neste ponto não importa nem mesmo se a função (este endereço na tabela de símbolos) é de código não gerenciado (mas seu acesso é gerenciado), escrito em C, C++, Assembly ou outra linguagem, inclusive funções que fazem parte da API do sistema operacional. Os símbolos desta tabela precisam ser únicos. Não pode haver duas funções com mesmo nome.

#### Funções são únicas e imutáveis

O código nativo gerado pelo JITter é imutável, ou seja, ele nunca será alterado durante a execução do programa. Até existe a possibilidade de um método/função ter seu código alterado durante a execução em uma técnica avançada, mas o que ocorre é a mudança do endereço do código na tabela de símbolos para indicar um novo código e não a mudança do código em si. Não vou entrar em detalhes sobre [imutabilidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/101) aqui, mas isso vale para código também, não só para dados.

#### Evitando colisão de nomes

Existe uma técnica uma garantir que funções que parecem ter o mesmo nome sejam diferentes. Você faz uma "decoração" no nome das funções com outras "palavras" que os tornem únicos, criando "sobrenomes" para as funções, adiciona-se o nome:

- da DLL antes do nome da função;
- do namespace que a função faz parte;
- da classe que ela foi declarada (há variação aqui se a classe usar um [tipo genérico](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming));
- dos tipos dos argumentos da função (para o caso de [*overload* de métodos diferenciados apenas pelos seus tipos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101));

Como um método é apenas uma função com um código a ser executado pelo processador (**ele não contém dados, apenas as instruções do processador**), ele **existe apenas uma vez na memória**.

**Em hipótese alguma ele é replicado para as instâncias das classes** (os objetos, falando na terminologia OOP). Você pode ter milhares, milhões de objetos de uma classe acessando o mesmo código do método até mesmo de forma simultânea. Para executá-lo você está fazendo internamente apenas leitura nesta área da memória para mandar p/ o processador e a área é imutável, portanto nenhum problema de [concorrência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/166032/101).

Portanto um método `int TotalizarInscritosDaLetra( string )` da classe `Concurso` no namespace `Aplicacao` e contida na DLL `MinhaApp` provavelmente teria como seu nome interno algo parecido com `MinhaApp_Aplicacao_Concurso_TotalizarInscritosDaLetra_int_string` (depende da implementação, isto foi apenas um exemplo).

Então se você criar o código:

```
var concurso1 = new Concurso();
var concurso2 = new Concurso();
```

tanto as variáveis `concurso1` quanto `concurso2` quando chamarem o método `TotalizarInscritosDaLetra` que manda um argumento `string` (em C# o retorno não importa, o *overload* não o considera, mas o CLR sim, por isso o nome concreto nativo considera isso), vão executar exatamente o mesmo código (fisicamente), iniciado no mesmo endereço da memória.

Se você quiser ver os nomes internos na CIL, pode usar o utilitário [ILASM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/ilasm-exe-il-assembler?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que vem com o .NET ou softwares mais sofisticados de terceiros para fazer *reflection* do código como o [.NET Reflector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Reflector) e o [DotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/). É possível também ver as funções mais em baixo nível mas nunca tentei e vou me abster de sugerir como.

#### Métodos genéricos

Note que se você usar programação genérica, complica um pouco mais: um método `void Add( T )` da classe `List<T>` poderá gerar na memória (não na CIL) várias funções diferentes. Se sua aplicação usar um objeto da classe `List<int>` você terá uma função `Add` com nome semelhante a `mscorlib_System_Collections_Generic_List_Add_void_**int**`.

Isto vale para qualquer tipo chamado [*value type* (por valor). Mas todos os tipos *reference type* (por referência)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/101) possuem apenas uma versão compartilhada dessas funções, afinal o valor efetivo que as funções terão que lidar é a referência para o objeto em si. E todas as referências têm o mesmo tamanho e mesma semântica. O .NET faz este truque para economizar memória e não gerar versões de funções para todos os tipos usados pela classe genérica.

#### Propriedades

Propriedades, que nada mais são que métodos com sintaxe diferenciada, usam variações de nome também. As propriedades costumam ter duas funções geradas, uma para [`get` e outra para `set`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15467/101) ([veja a CIL como eles ficam](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108516/101)).

Existem diversas outras formas de métodos em que o nome da função interna acaba sendo um pouco diferente do que você vê no seu código.

#### *Delegates*

***Delegates* não deixam de ser métodos normais como os demais**, apenas possuem algumas características próprias. Eles existem durante toda a execução da aplicação (ou pelo menos enquanto ele estiver carregado no [Application Domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_domain)<sup>(en)</sup>. Não vou entrar em detalhes sobre carga e descarga de "módulos").

*Delegates* também são chamados funções sem nome. Portanto, abstratamente não existindo um nome, internamente um nome concreto será gerado para ser colocado na tabela de símbolos. Algo como `dll_ns_classeDoDelegateExemplo_InternalMethod_etc_etc` (o padrão de nome real é diferente, este é só um exemplo para facilitar o entendimento).

Um método *delegate* está encapsulado em uma classe, mesmo que não pareça, até porque o mecanismo interno realmente não é importante quando estamos criando nossas aplicações. E nesta classe é possível ter referências a dados externos ao *delegate*, neste caso o *delegate* usa o conceito de *[closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming))*

Uma nota extra é que *delegates* são tão rápidos quanto métodos virtuais. Essencialmente o único *overhead* real que um *delegate* tem em relação a um método não virtual é a indireção do ponteiro, assim como ocorre em métodos virtuais.

Você pode ter **referências para *delegates* destruídas** quando elas não mais estão sendo usadas, porém **o código da função *delegate* nunca é destruído** (exceto no *unload* do AppDomain), ele está em uma área imutável e não acessível para escrita para sua aplicação.

## Métodos e dados

Portanto **métodos são armazenados na memória, mas não como dados**, há profundas diferenças na forma que é armazenado.

Os dados que você encontra dentro de um método (as variáveis locais), via de regra, se encontram no *stack*, uma área mutável da memória organizada em forma de pilha como o próprio nome sugere, onde os dados vão sendo empilhados em cada novo escopo de execução ([não confundir com escopo léxico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13034/101)) e desempilhados no seu término.

Os tipos por referência ainda possuem os dados dos objetos referenciados dentro dos métodos [(no *stack*) na área da memória chamada *heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101), que é gerenciado diretamente pelo *garbage collector*.

## Métodos estáticos X métodos de instância

Entenda a diferença entre métodos estáticos e métodos de instância de uma classe (lembrando que classes estáticas só possuem métodos estáticos).

Para fins de entendimento da sua pergunta, internamente as funções são geradas de forma idêntica nos dois casos. Métodos de instância são praticamente *syntax sugar* para os métodos estáticos. Podemos dizer que concretamente só existem métodos estáticos.

Abstratamente temos os métodos de instância cuja única diferença real é que eles possuem um parâmetro extra que você não vê na sua declaração. Por exemplo, um método de instância `int Calcular()` da classe `Imposto` na verdade tem sua assinatura real `int Calcular( Imposto this )`. Quando você usa o `this` implícita ou explicitamente dentro de um método, na verdade é como se estivesse acessando uma variável local chamada `this` que possui uma referência para uma instância da sua classe.

Isto explica de forma concreta porque você não consegue acessar membros de instância de dentro de um método estático, ele não possui esta "variável".

## Conclusão

Existem outras implicações e situações mais avançadas sobre o assunto, mas acho que isto dá uma visão geral. Quer saber mais e de forma tecnicamente precisa? Veja o [artigo na MSDN Magazine](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2005/may/net-framework-internals-how-the-clr-creates-runtime-objects?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) (em inglês).

Ressalto que a maioria do que eu falei aqui, apesar de ser em termos bastante genéricos, é detalhe de implementação e não faz parte de nenhuma especificação e pode mudar a forma de funcionar no futuro.

O livro do Jefferey Ritcher [CLR via C#](http://www.wintellect.com/Resource-CLR-Via-CSharp-Fourth-Edition) é muito bom para aprofundar-se sobre o assunto (está um pouco defasado, mas ainda ajuda (veja também o [Book of Runtime](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/tree/master/Documentation/botr)).

Veja mais sobre o assunto de gerenciamento de memória (inclusive sobre a afirmação equivocada que tipos por valor são armazenados no *stack*) em [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/14492/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 10):

Algumas concepções que você formulou estão erradas.

1. **Structs não existem obrigatoriamente na pilha**. Uma struct é um conjunto de dados que é armazenado na forma de valor, ao invés de uma referência que aponta para outro lugar. Ela é codificada diretamente no contexto ao qual está associada, ou que será utilizada (quem decide isso é a CLR):

- se for uma variável local, vai ser colocada diretamente na pilha, e vai deixar de existir automaticamente quando o contexto do método deixar de existir, ou seja, quando ocorrer uma exceção ou o método retornar.
- se for um campo de instância de uma classe, será colocada diretamente no corpo da classe, que vai ficar no "heap", alocado diretamente na estrutura do objeto, com um certo offset em relação ao início do mesmo
- se for um campo estático, então será armazenado estaticamente, e não constará no layout de memória do objeto como instância
- se uma struct for atribuida a uma variável que seja do tipo referência, como `object`, `Enum` ou alguma interface qualquer que a struct implemente, será armazenada no "heap", através de uma operação chamada **boxing**, que consta em alocar espaço no heap managed, e copiar o valor para lá.
- **otimizações** podem fazer com que uma **variável local do tipo struct**, **não exista nem na pilha**, por exemplo um `int` utilizado como iterador de um for.
- uma **variável local pode acabar na heap**, caso seja capturada em uma closure, ou necessite de viver por mais tempo que o contexto local (quem decide isso é a CLR)

2. Métodos não fazem parte da instância de um objeto. **O código compilado é armazenado estaticamente**, em uma posição fixa de memória. Quando o método é chamado o compilador JIT entra em ação e compila o método, em um lugar fixo, e a partir daí tudo que fizer referência ao método apontará para um endereço fixo de memória que contem o código compilado.

- o código do método sendo estático, toma conhecimento do objeto ao qual está sendo aplicado através de um parâmetro especial, o qual se chama carinhosamente de `this` no C#, ou `Me` no VB.NET.
- Todo código que é compilado, fica associado a um **Application
  Domain**. A única forma de descartar métodos compilados, é eliminando o Application Domain.

3. **Delegates apontam sim para os métodos compilados, mas que por sua vez são estáticos**... portanto quando um delegate é destruido o método compilado continua existindo. Além de apontar para um método, um delegate pode conter dados, por exemplo, quando é feita uma closure.

- Nota: delegates são classes, e **fazem referência para os dados capturados em uma closure**... portanto para que o garbage-collector disponha dos dados capturados é necessário desfazer todas as referências ao delegate

**Referências e mais material de estudo:** infelizmente tudo em inglês

- [The Truth About Value Types](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/the-truth-about-value-types): Eric Lippert falando sobre structs
- [The Stack Is An Implementation Detail, Part One](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx): Eric Lippert falando sobre a pilha
- [.Net Garbage Collection in depth](https://web.archive.org/web/20160821011303/http://www.dotnet-tricks.com:80/Tutorial/netframework/0L3P131012-.Net-Garbage-Collection-in-depth.html): mostra esquematicamente como funciona garbage-collection no .Net
- [Short-lived objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631919/short-lived-objects): questão no SOEN, contendo informações sobre alocação de objetos que vivem muito pouco
- [Fundamentals of Garbage Collection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals): MSDN

Answer (score 5):

Não posso falar especificamente do CLR, mas o raciocínio deve ser igual: toda vez que você define uma classe, essa classe é representada na memória de alguma forma. Há uma única representação para essa classe - ao contrário de suas instâncias (objetos), que pode ter várias. Todas as instâncias de um classe **compartilham** então a referência para essa classe:

```
Foo a = new Foo();
Foo b = new Foo();
a.GetType() == b.GetType(); // true
```

É ali - junto da classe - que fica a representação em memória dos seus métodos. Quando você chama um método em um objeto:

```
a.bar(10, 20, 30);
```

O que está sendo feito é o método *da classe* de `a` ser chamado usando como parâmetros o próprio `a` e os `10`, `20` e `30`.

Ok, mas e quanto às referências para métodos? Você diz que 'um método não contém um "dado" que pode ser guardado', e muitas vezes isso é verdade. Entretanto, se você quiser chamá-lo, você precisa de uma referência para ele. Essa referência é, grosso modo, um ponteiro para o lugar na definição da classe onde está representado esse método. Usando essa referência, você pode chamá-lo sem usar um valor "engessado" no código-fonte (*hardcoded*).

No mais, há situações em que há sim dados a serem guardados: no caso de um método "amarrado" a um objeto específico (*bound method*), ou no caso de uma função que é um *closure* de outra função (i.e. definida dentro da outra - e portanto com acesso às variáveis locais da função "de fora"). De novo, não tenho familiaridade com .Net, posso ter simplificado demais/tomado algumas liberdades, por isso sugiro que você aguarde por uma resposta mais precisa. Mas o que eu escrevi deve dar uma ideia básica da lógica por trás disso.