# Alocação de memória em C# - Tipos valor e tipos referência

Tags: c#, .net, gerenciamento-de-memória, tipagem, clr

Em C# há uma diferença entre a forma que a memória é alocada pelo CLR para tipos referência (classes) e tipos valor (estruturas). A diferença, pelo que sempre ouvi falar, seria o fato de tipos valor serem armazenados na pilha e tipos referência no heap. Ocorre, porém, que tipos valor também podem ser armazenados no heap através de boxing, ou sendo membros de um tipo referência.

Dessa forma, a distinção entre tipos valor e tipos referência passa a ser não exatamente o local onde cada qual está armazenado. Dessa forma, como se diferencia de forma mais correta tipos valor e tipos referência? Como realmente o CLR gerencia a alocação de memória para instâncias e classes e estruturas separadamente? Além disso, por quê existe essa distinção? Afinal, classes e estruturas, apesar de possuirem diferenças são bem parecidos um com o outro.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

O local em que a alocação da memória é feita é somente determinado pelo seu tempo de vida e não pelo tipo de dado.

- Em C# existem instâncias de duas formas de valores: *value types* (o valor em si) e [referências](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56470/101) para outras instâncias.
- Existe o conceito de "locais de armazenagem" que podem armazenar valores.
- Todo valor manipulado por um programa está em um "local de armazenagem".
- Toda referência, exceto as nulas, apontam para um "local de armazenagem".
- Todo "local de armazenagem" tem um tempo de vida onde seu conteúdo é válido.
- O código de um método pode requisitar um "local de armazenagem".
- Se o "local de armazenagem" é necessário somente durante o tempo de ativação (simplificadamente, período em que o método está em execução), ele é chamado de "vida curta". Se o "local de armazenagem" é necessário por um tempo mais longo que esse, ele é chamado "vida longa".

## Reference types

[Tipos que são por referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16181/101) (*reference types*) realmente tem seus dados (o objeto em si) no *heap* (memória comum à toda a aplicação gerenciada pelo *[garbage collector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science))*). Isso é um detalhe de implementação, mas é certo que funciona assim nas versões atuais. E claro, esses tipos possuem uma referência (um ponteiro, um endereço de memória) que é guardada em algum lugar ("local de armazenagem").

A referência em si (não o objeto que ela aponta) é um tipo de valor (*value type*) também.

Quando o compilador ou o [JITter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101) não pode determinar ao certo o tempo de vida de um "local de armazenagem", o caminho mais seguro é usado, portanto o *heap* é utilizado.

## Value types

Tipos por valor deveriam ser [imutáveis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). Portando qualquer transporte do seu valor deve ser feito através de cópia integral dos seus membros, exceto se for explicitamente determinado que isso deva ser feito por referência (notadamente com modificador `ref` em argumentos de métodos, e retorno a partir de de C# 7).

#### Uma curiosidade:

```
struct Textos {
    private string Texto1;
    private string Texto2;
    ... aqui vão os construtores e métodos/propriedades de acesso e alteração dos membros, garantindo a imutabilidade ...
}
```

`string` é tipo por referência. Você acha que há algum erro ou "má prática" na criação dessa estrutura que é *value type*?

Nenhum problema. A estrutura é curta (8 bytes em 32 bits ou 16 bytes quando está em 64 bits), é imutável, e possivelmente tem outras características desejáveis para um tipo por valor (como o exemplo não é completo, só podemos imaginar isso).

Dentro desta estrutura guarda-se apenas duas referências para `strings`. Nada mais que isso. Os textos que são os valores destas `strings` ficam guardados no *heap* (até isto é um pouco mais complicado por causa do *[interning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning)*<sup>(en)</sup>). Para todos os efeitos `Textos` é uma estrutura que apenas guarda duas referências (ponteiros).

#### Utilização de memória

Uma estrutura não tem [*overhead*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/198252/101) de memória. O tamanho de uma estrutura é sempre a soma dos tamanhos de seus membros (lembrando que no exemplo acima o tamanho dos membros é o tamanho da referência), levando em consideração também o [alinhamento de dados](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment)<sup>(en)</sup>. O tamanho dela não é o mesmo que o espaço ocupado na memória.

Os tipos que são armazenados por valor podem estar em diversos lugares.

Se procurar [fontes confiáveis](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/the-truth-about-value-types?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)<sup>(en)</sup> verá que a alocação destes tipos é um pouco mais complicada do que a maioria dos programadores .NET entendem.

- O valor (que é o próprio objeto) pode estar em um registrador por otimização do [JITter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101). O [CLR](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51281/101) sabe como lidar com isso. Enumeradores costumam ser colocados em registrador para otimizar *loops*.
- O valor pode estar na pilha como todo mundo imagina, isso é bem comum. Estes são os dados que estão diretamente vinculados aos métodos (você os acessa através de variáveis locais).
- O valor pode estar no *heap* por estar envelopado em algum outro tipo, uma classe, um *array*, etc.

O último ponto merece maiores detalhes.

- Se um *value type* faz parte de um outro *reference type* como membro, onde esse valor vai ser armazenado?

  Ora, se uma classe (um tipo por referência) é montada como uma sequência de membros de outros tipos, o conteúdo real desta classe (o objeto e não a sua referência) está no *heap*.
- Se um tipo por valor faz parte de outro tipo que certamente está armazenado no *heap*, como ele pode estar armazenado na pilha?

  Simples, ele não está. Veja:

  ```
  public class Carro {
      public string Nome;
      public int Status;
      public bool EhNovo;
      public DataTime DataDaVenda;
      public Decimal ValorDaVenda;
  }
  ```

  O exemplo possui falhas mas o que é importante é que cada instância desta classe possuirá armazenado:

  - 4 bytes da referência do membro `Nome`;
  - 4 bytes do membro `Status`;
  - 1 byte (em tese, desconsiderando alinhamento) do membro `EhNovo`;
  - 8 bytes do membro `DataDaVenda`;
  - 16 bytes do membro `ValorDaVenda`.

  Todos estes espaços permitem armazenar os seus valores no *heap*, onde uma instância da classe `Carro` estará armazenada. No caso do membro `Nome` possivelmente terá ainda uma outra parte armazenada no *heap* - desde que ela não seja uma referência nula - mas que poderá estar em qualquer outro lugar da memória e não junto com o objeto instanciado do tipo `Carro`, apenas por coincidência podem estar em sequência.
- E se a classe for uma lista de inteiros? Algo como:

  ```
   var notas = new List<int> { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
  ```
- Esses inteiros, que são *value types*, fazem parte do conteúdo da coleção. Onde eles ficarão armazenados?

  No *heap* também. Internamente, em última análise, todos os elementos desta lista são armazenados em um *array*, que é apenas uma sequencia de dados do tipo definido. O `List` é uma classe, portanto um *reference type* e todos os seus dados ficam no *heap*.
- E se eu capturar uma variável local do tipo `int` de um método em um *delegate* que será exposto para outras partes da aplicação. Onde este `int` **local** ficará armazenado?

  No *heap* também. É a única forma de manter um dado vivo que era local e sobreviveu através de um *delegate*. Quando esse dado local é capturado por um *delegate*, formando uma *closure*, ele passa fazer parte da classe que encapsula o *delegate*, através de uma referência, portanto faz parte de algo que está no *heap* e seu tempo de vida é controlado pelo *garbage collector* (poderá ser coletado quando o *delegate* não for referenciado pela aplicação).

Como se vê, existem várias formas em que um dado por valor pode estar no *heap*.

A referência em si para objetos (o dado concreto) são valores também. Acho que já ficou claro que a referência propriamente dita também pode estar nestes três locais.

Por exemplo, quando você tem uma lista de `strings` (`List<string>`), o que é armazenado nesta lista são as referências para cada uma das `strings`, para cada um dos textos.

- Se você quiser calcular o tamanho de um `List<string>` com 1000 elementos nulos, a grosso modo - esquece os outros membros do objeto `List` e o *overhead* que todo objeto por referência tem - qual seria o tamanho ocupado no *heap* por esta lista em uma arquitetura 32 bits?

  Cada referência ocupará 4 bytes (32 bits == 4 bytes) por elemento na lista. 4 x 1000 elementos = 4000 bytes. Só isso.

  E os dados das `strings` em si? Se todas são nulas, não há mais nenhum consumo. Mas se você inicializar todas as 1000 `strings` com algum texto, o consumo geral da memória certamente vai aumentar porque 1000 objetos do tipo `string` deverão ser alocados. Mas o consumo do objeto do tipo `List` não mudará nada. As referências continuam ocupando o mesmo espaço. Claro que o conteúdo de todas essas referências eram 0 (o endereço convencionado para indicar nulo) e passam a ter outros valores da posição de memória onde cada `string` foi alocada (algumas já poderiam até já estar alocadas por *interning*, mas isso é outra estória).

Podemos concluir que *value types* que sobrevivem à execução de um método são armazenados no *heap*. Esta é a conclusão correta. E é impressionante como sobrevive o mito da relação entre alocação e forma de representação do objeto.

## Memória virtual

A coisa fica um pouco mais complicada porque qualquer dado pode nem estar na memória RAM, pode estar em uma forma de armazenamento de massa. Há um outro equívoco comum em achar que tudo o que mandamos alocar na memória vai parar na memória física. Ela vai para a memória virtual que pode estar fisicamente em um disco rígido, por exemplo. Mas isso é outro assunto.

#### Records

C# 9 e 10 introduziram [`record`s](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) por referência e por valor respectivamente.

## Conclusão

"Todo mundo" "sabe" onde o dado é alocado e isto costuma ser irrelevante. Saber que o importante é o tempo de vida do objeto nem sempre faz parte da ciência do programador.

Outras estratégias são possíveis. Ressalto que tudo isso é detalhe de implementação atual do CLR.

Lembre-se sempre que a forma ou tipo de um valor e o "local de armazenagem" são conceitos distintos.

Veja [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101) para entender melhor a *stack* e o *heap*.

Referências:

[Parte 1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) e [parte 2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/04/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-two.aspx?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) do artigo do Eric Lippert.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Memory/ValueXReference.cs).

Comment: Saber que o importante é o tempo de vida do objeto nem sempre faz parte da ciência do programador, acredito nisso. Já fiz algumas perguntas relacionadas a essa a outros programadores e não souberam me responder =/

Answer (score 10):

A resposta aceita é muito boa, mas um mergulho mais fundo em alguns pontos abaixo.

Editado: Removi a recomendação sobre a string na struct, não fazia sentido.

> Dessa forma, como se diferencia de forma mais correta tipos valor e tipos referência?

Tipos de valor são considerados os literais ou os tipos que implementam deep copy. O número 3 a string "xpto" são valores, eles não podem ser mudados, não existe a necessidade de se criar uma nova representação para o valor 3, só existe uma representação, logo ao ser atribuído, uma copia é feita gerando outro espaço de memória.

A string tem uma particularidade, ela é imutável, as pessoas se esquecem que só existe uma representação dela na memória, por isso a atribuição da string para evitar a perda de tempo, copia o seu endereço de memória e não uma nova cópia dela. Atente que "cat" + "dog" implica em "catdog" que é uma  representação completamente diferente (outra memória), fazendo com que concatenar muitas strings em série seja uma operação onerosa.

O C# trouxe a struct do C++, fazendo com que a struct tenha a mesma semântica dos value types, ou seja, é um shallow copy que pretende ser um deep copy, a responsabilidade é do programador garantir que nenhuma referência seja copiada de forma shallow, o compilador se responsabiliza por copiar a struct durante a atribuição criando um novo espaço de memória.

Regra de ouro: Structs são compostas apenas de tipos de valor, copiar uma struct é gerar uma deep copy da mesma e de seus membros.

Structs são usadas normalmente para tipos puramente de valor, usar referencias dentro de struct é considerado uma pratica ruim, pois da struct espera-se que a copia gere novos endereços de memória e não referencias ao mesmo.

Nos demais casos use a classe para representar suas entidades.

> Como realmente o CLR gerencia a alocação de memória para instâncias e classes e estruturas separadamente?

Atente, o C# é altamente influenciado pelo C++, mas sem alguns recursos que foram considerados inseguros ou não práticos.

Perceba o uso da struct sem new, ela é um valuetype está na assinatura da classe:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Linq
{
    struct Teste
    {
        public int t;
    }

    class Xpto
    {
        public int t;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Teste t;
            Teste x = new Teste();
            Xpto xpto = new Xpto();

            // Ok, compilador inicializou por nós.
            Console.WriteLine(x.t);

            // Exception, valor sendo usado sem ser inicializado.
            Console.WriteLine(t.t);
        }
    }   
}
```

Perceba como é permitido usar a struct na stack sem criar uma nova instância, mas nesse caso o compilador não inicializa os fields. A maioria dos programadores prefere o new, que continua colocando na stack (nesse contexto). Vamos olhar a cereja do bolo, o CIL.

```
.method private hidebysig static 
    void Main (
        string[] args
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2058
    // Code size 27 (0x1b)
    .maxstack 1
    .entrypoint
    .locals init (
        [0] valuetype Linq.Teste x
    )

    IL_0000: ldloca.s x
    IL_0002: initobj Linq.Teste
    IL_0008: newobj instance void Linq.Xpto::.ctor()
    IL_000d: pop
    IL_000e: ldloca.s x
    IL_0010: ldfld int32 Linq.Teste::t
    IL_0015: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
    IL_001a: ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

O new não criou um newobj como ele faz com as classes, essa foi uma decisão do C#, se olharmos calmamente a assinatura das structs elas não derivam do Object diretamente, mas sim do ValueType. Mesmo que esse derive de Object nova semântica foi inserida para diferir dos objetos, sem retirar deles o comportamento do Object.

```
.class private sequential ansi sealed beforefieldinit Linq.Teste
    extends [mscorlib]System.ValueType
{
    // Fields
    .field public int32 t

} // end of class Linq.Teste
```

O problema surge quando se traz a máxima a tona: Todos os tipos de valor ficam na Stack. Aí não irei chover no molhado, leia o post do Moderador, porque no C# é permitido que o compilador decida como preferir, a linguagem não usa ponteiros raw e não interessa para o programador aonde foi alocado. Curiosamente, a CIL é uma linguagem STACK based, mas o compilador do C# pode fazer box/unbox em value types, e esse comportamento deve ser evitado por questões de performance. Fields fazem parte da entidade e obviamente ficam junto com ela no heap.

Um bom compilador ao criar um value em escopo local sempre irá alocar na stack, a não ser que algum fator maior exista, mas isso realmente não cabe na preocupação do programador de C#. O uso de garbage collector tira dos ombros do programador ter medo de perder o valor da stack ao fim de escopo, esse problema existe no C++. O C# é compilado em CIL, na CIL é transitação de valor de uma stack para outra, e a memória é recolhia em momento oportuno.

> Além disso, por quê existe essa distinção? Afinal, classes e
>   estruturas, apesar de possuirem diferenças são bem parecidos um com o
>   outro.

Parecidas sim, iguais não! É muito útil usar structs quando pensamos na direção da programação funcional e imutabilidade. Quando que você quiser que uma cópia de valores seja uma copia e não apenas mais um ponteiro para a mesma memória, use struct, mas respeite o citado acima para manter comportamento correto esperado.

Se você comparar que no C++ elas são praticamente iguais, o C# deu mais função para a struct. A struct no fundo é uma herança do C puxada pra o C++ por compatibilidade e incorporada no C# para representar uma agregação de valores.

Comment: Sua resposta é boa mas tem alguns problemas. Coloca `string` como tipo de valor e ela é apenas imutável mas é um tipo por referência (depois até mostra isto). Tipos de valor podem e é muito comum serem alocados no *heap*. Mesmo  depois mostrando que pode, faz esta afirmação que é falsa. O tempo de vida/local de armazenamento de deus dados interessam ao programador que quer entender e usar corretamente os recursos da linguagem sem comprar mitos.

Comment: O conceito da CIL ser *stack based* não tem relação com o armazenamento dos valores, é a mesma palavra usada para coisas diferentes (ficaria longo explicar aqui). Há um entendimento errado sobre o funcionamento e a relação entre *stack* e GC/CIL, mas já está ficando muito longo para explicar aqui. Só para deixar claro (não está dizendo o contrário mas nem sempre as pessoas interpretam o texto corretamente): classes podem ser usadas em programação funcional e imutável.

Comment: Diz que é má prática colocar tipos de referência dentro de *structs*. Má prática é fazer algo que não se sabe fazer. Um dos integrantes d equipe do .Net/C# não considera má prática se você soube o que está fazendo. http://stackoverflow.com/a/945681/221800. O .Net vive fazendo isto. Este *site* é todo baseado nisto. Porque não há esta recomendação em C++ e algumas pessoas recomendam não fazer isto em C#? Porque espera-se do programador C++ que ele saiba o que está fazendo. O normal é contar que o programador C# não sabe.