# Qual o comportamento de variáveis estáticas no .NET?

Tags: c#, gerenciamento-de-memória, stack, clr, heap

Qual o comportamento de variáveis estáticas no .NET? Estas são armazenadas no *heap* ou na *stack*?

Comment: Relacionado: [o que são e onde estão o stack e heap](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/91)

Comment: Editei para retirar a parte que era duplicada. A parte que restou ainda não tem resposta no site e vou responder. A edição não invalidou a resposta existente porque ela já era inválida. Uma resposta sobre Java em uma pergunta de C# não ajuda nada. Mesmo que a pergunta fosse sobre Java, a resposta tem erros conceitas, o que é preocupante já que a fonte indireta é um guia de estudo da Sun para certificação Java. Talvez isto ajude explicar um pouco porque tem tantos programadores Java ruins.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Dados estáticos, não só variáveis, constantes e códigos também, são armazenados em um *heap* especial, chamado de *High Frequency Heap*. É uma área gerenciada pelo .NET, mas seu conteúdo não é coletado. Ali é armazenado o que a aplicação precisa por toda sua vida. Dados estáticos são armazenados lá desde sua primeira utilização até a aplicação terminar, ao contrário do *heap* normal onde os dados são coletados quando não há mais referências para eles no momento que uma das gerações dispara uma coleta.

Na verdade há uma coleta desta área quando um `AppDomain` é descarregado. O que não deixa de ser o término da aplicação em certo sentido. Certamente no final do `AppDomain` você não poderá mais acessar estes dados. A alocação geral desta área de memória ocorre na carga do `AppDomain`. Mo .NET Core não há mais `AppDoamin`. Mas esse mecanismo foi abandonado na versões recentes do .NET.

Dados estáticos nunca estão no *stack* ou *heap* normal. Não faria sentido já que estes dados não são transitórios (para entender melhor estas áreas leia [O que são e onde estão o stack e heap](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101)). A área especial HFH está dentro do *heap* mas tem um tratamento especial. Evidentemente que dados estáticos (variáveis, códigos, etc.) podem se referenciar para o *stack* ou *heap*.

É importante notar que mesmo dados **por valor** que normalmente estariam na *stack* ou no *heap* (veja mais em [Alocação de memória em C# - Tipos valor e tipos referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/101)) são armazenados nesta área quando são estáticos.

Note que se uma variável estática é um tipo por referência só a referência estará nesta área, o objeto em si estará no *heap* normal. Tem exceções, como a *string* que foi definida por um literal.

Um literal do tipo *string* é um dado estático e ele é armazenado apenas uma vez mesmo que apareça várias vezes no código através de uma técnica chamada [interning](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.intern?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0#System_String_Intern_System_String_).

Vale lembrar que um objeto estático é alocado apenas uma vez e não é realocado por definição.

O [JITter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101) usa esta mesma área para alocar os códigos gerados.

Claro que tudo isto é detalhe de implementação. Nada impede que em futuras versões seja mudado, embora improvável que aconteça. De fato a importância desta informação para o programador é pequena. O mais importante é saber que são armazenados de forma muito rápida (de uma maneira geral comparável com o tempo gasto no *stack* ou um pouco melhor) e como não *desaloca* nem libera, não há outro custo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Você se refere ao termo estático como sendo um valor que não muda, porém não acho que é muito certo dizer isso se tratando do C#, variáveis estáticas, criadas com keyword static podem ter seu valor modificado, e dizer que uma string é um dado estático não é a melhor forma de se definir isso, o termo mais usado para isso é o imutável, já que qualquer modificação na string gera um novo objeto, enquanto o objeto string em si não vai ser modificado sua variável pode passar a referenciar um outro objeto

Comment: @LeandroGodoyRosa não, variáveis possuem valores que mudam e elas podem ser estáticas. Reli e não achei no texto o que você está dizendo. Pode citar onde parece que eu digo isto? Você sabe o que é um literal *string*? Eles não podem ser modificados. Variáveis *string* podem. Caso não entenda do assunto, pode fazer uma pergunta e terei prazer em responder.

Answer (score 1):

As partes de um programa Java (variáveis, métodos e objetos) vivem em um dos dois lugares na memória: *Stack* e *Heap*.

Variáveis de instância e objetos são armazenados no *Heap* (ou estática), e variáveis locais são armazenadas no *Stack* (pilha, automática).

Stack é a pilha de execução. Cada método executado é colocado na pilha. Dessa forma, o código dos métodos e variáveis locais (incluindo parâmetros) são colocados no *Stack*. Se um método encher o *Stack*, a exceção `StackOverflowException` será lançada; isso quer dizer que o *Stack* cresceu tanto que invadiu uma área que não lhe pertence.

Heap é o local onde ficam os objetos instanciados, ou seja, é onde variáveis de instância e referências (objetos) são colocados. Quando um método cria muitas variáveis de instância a ponto de encher o *Heap*, a exceção `OutOfMemoryError` é lançada.

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Agenda {

  //variável de instância - heap
  Date data;

  //método - stack
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        //variável local - stack
        Date dt = new Date();
        Agenda agenda = new Agenda();
        agenda.setData(dt);
  }

  //parâmetro - stack
  public void setData(Date d) {
        data = d;
  }

}
```

Fonte: http://kamilladoria.blogspot.com.br/2010/05/stack-e-heap.html

Comment: Boa resposta. Porém isso não se restringe somente ao Java. É uma caracteristica da arquitetura dos processadores atualmente utilizados. Isso diz respeito ao gerenciamento de memória em tempo de execução de um programa. Mas de maneira bem resumida segue como vc mesmo falou: stack é onde ficam instanciadas as variaveis locais de um método, incluindo parâmetros; e heap é onde ficam instanciadas as variáveis globais; tudo em tempo de execução.

Comment: Antigamente, os erros mais comuns de corrupção de memória eram Stack Overflow e Heap Overflow. Tais erros geram falhas de segurança, que permite a injeção de código e o redirecionamento do fluxo de execução do programa, possibilitando a abertura de shell remota ou escalação de privilégio. E até hoje, falhas desse tipo são exploradas.

Comment: Apenas uma correção semântica: não lembro mais das minhas aulas de Compiladores, mas creio _heap_ e _stack_ são caraterísticas do gerenciamento de memória dos sistemas operacionais e não da arquitetura dos processadores. Pelo menos não encontrei nenhuma instrução assembly x86 referente a _heap_, e não sei se a parte de manipulação de _stack_ é a mesma coisa em ambos.