# Qual é a diferença entre const e readonly?

Tags: c#, .net, característica-linguagem, constantes, tempo-de-vida

Constantes e campos somente leitura não podem ser modificados, como pode ser visto na documentação:

> **[const](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/e6w8fe1b.aspx)**
>   Campos e locais constantes não são variáveis ​​e **não podem ser modificados**.

> [**readonly**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/acdd6hb7.aspx)
>   Quando uma declaração de campo inclui um modificador readonly, este **não poderá ser alterado** salvo como parte na declaração da mesma ou no método construtor da classe pertencente.

Quais são as diferenças entre `const` e `readonly` e quando usar cada uma?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`const` é estático e é resolvido em tempo de compilação. Ou seja, o que será colocado no código que consumir a constante é o valor estabelecido nela. Se por acaso mudar seu valor, tem que compilar tudo que a consumiu para ter o novo valor. Além disso o valor tem que ser constante também, ou seja, tem que poder ser completamente resolvido durante a compilação. Portanto não pode usar pra muita coisa.

Um bom exemplo é `PI`.

Um exemplo ruim para seu uso é `MaxThreads`. Um dia você pode querer mudar e pode ter problemas. Nesse caso é melhor usar:

```
public static readonly int MaxThreads = 4;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/Readonly.cs).

`readonly` pode ser aplicada para campos estáticos ou de instância (há proposta para ter localmente). Ele não é bem uma [constante](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/203151/101), apenas indica que depois de inicializado seu valor não pode mais ser mudado. É [imutável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/101), mas não constante, ainda que normalmente ele acabe sendo considerado assim. Os valores usados nele podem ser resolvidos em tempo de execução porque sua inicialização ocorre só nesse momento, seja no momento que precisa usar o dado estático ou no momento da criação de uma instância dependendo do contexto que ele é declarado.

Como o dado é inicializado em tempo de execução, mesmo que seu valor possa ser resolvido em tempo de compilação não é feito, assim o código consumidor dessas "constantes" ficam seguros de que pegarão sempre o valor atual do código que a criou.

Se precisa inicializar em tempo de execução não tem opção, só pode usar `readonly`. Se precisa que a "constante" seja de instância, também deve usar `readonly`.

A regra básica quando dá para escolher é que se precisa de um dado que pode mudar no futuro, use `readonly`. Se ele é universalmente constante - nunca vai mudar - pode usar `const`.

- Pode ser útil: [Qual o comportamento de variáveis estáticas no .NET?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27776/101)
- Ajuda entender porque deve evitar mudar: [Uma enumeração deve ser constante no tempo de vida da solução?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21997/101)