# Como alterar propriedade final do Java para C#?

Tags: java, c#, propriedade

Qual propriedade em C# é correspondente ao `final` do Java, preciso alterar as minhas variáveis `final String mensagem = "Tokio Marine Seguradora S.A.";`  para algo correspondente em C#.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    public sealed class Criptografia
    {
        private static readonly String ALGORITMO = "AES";

        public static String descriptografar(String mensagem, String chave) 
        {

          //  final Cipher cipher = getCipher(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, chave);

          //  final byte[]
          //  descriptografado = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(mensagem));

                //return new String(descriptografado, "UTF-8");

            return "";
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Mensagem que sera criptografada.
            final String mensagem = "Tokio Marine Seguradora S.A.";

            // Senha definida da operadora.
            final String chave = "JessicaBiel";

            //// Valor criptografado.
            //String criptografado = Criptografia.criptografar(mensagem, chave);
            //Console.Write("Valor criptografado: '%s' %n", criptografado);

            //// Valor original.
            //String descriptografado = Criptografia.descriptografar(criptografado, chave);
            //Console.Write("Valor descriptografado: '%s'", descriptografado);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1327549/5524514

Comment: Usa `const` por exemplo  `private const String Mensagem = xxxxx`

Comment: @MarcoGiovanni `const` não deve seu usado para isso, veja o *link* na minha resposta comparando os mecanismos.

Comment: @bigown não sabia dessa diferença, obrigado!

Comment: @MarcoGiovanni na verdade até que você está certo, eu não tinha me atentado para a pergunta direito, nesse contexto é `const` mesmo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No contexto da pergunta é [`const`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/const?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), mas na verdade não costuma ser útil e praticamente nunca vi sendo usado. "Constantes" dentro de um escopo local ajudam bem pouco (ajuda ligeiramente na performance).

## Outros contextos

Em variáveis de classe ou de instância é o [`readonly`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/readonly?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que equivale ao `final` do Java.

Se fosse em uma classe, o equivalente seria [`sealed`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/sealed?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Em métodos o padrão do C# é o método não ser virtual, então não precisa disso. A não ser que queira impedir a virtualidade em uma árvore onde o método já vinha virtual, aí o uso deve ser `sealed` também, junto do `override`.

## Extra

Idealmente seria bom converter idiomaticamente. Fica esquisito ter um estilo Java em código C#. E é fácil acabar cometendo algum erro por isso.

Veja mais: [Qual é a diferença entre const e readonly?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151721/101)

Comment: Tente fazer isso mas deu erro. The modifier  'readonly' is not valid

Comment: Aí a pergunta já é diferente, teria que ver seu código, o erro exato.

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0106 The modifier 'readonly' is not valid for this item ConsoleApplication C:\Work\stackoverflow\ConsoleApplication\Program.cs 25

Comment: alterei a pergunta com o código completo, dentro do man, estou criando minhas variáveis, e final que é do java por um correspondente do C#.

Comment: É, eu não tinha me atentado para o uso dentro do método, alterei a resposta para isso agora.