# Porque usar readonly para instanciar?

Tags: c#

Li e reli essa [pergunta/resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/151721/qual-%c3%a9-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-const-e-readonly) algumas vezes e entendi a diferença entra `const` e `readonly`. Li também a [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/readonly), porém ainda não consegui entender qual o ganho que tenho ao usar o `readonly`.

**Cenário**
Tenho uma aplicação desenvolvida em `Asp .Net MVC` e nela há uma camada de serviço(service), eu "inicio" esses serviços através de injeção de dependência pelo `controller`:

```
private IMyService _myService;
public MeuConstrutor(IMyService myService)
{
    _myService = myService;
}
```

Vejo algumas pessoas usando o `private readonly IMyService _myService;` e, em uma das ultimas atualizações do `visual studio`(não me lembro qual ao certo) ele passou a sugerir que eu adicione o `readonly` nesses casos. Porém, como dito, não entendo qual o real ganho de usá-lo.

`private IMyService _myService;` vs `private readonly IMyService _myService;`

- Quando usar o `readonly`?
- Há ganho de alguma coisa usando ele?
- Há perda de alguma coisa usando ele?
- Por que usar?
- Por que não usar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O [**`readonly`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/readonly) é apenas um modificador de acesso como todos os outros. Não tem nenhuma magia.

Este modificador de acesso se aplica aos **campos** criados numa classe. Ao usá-lo, o campo só poderá ter um valor atribuído a ele no código que estiver **dentro do construtor** da classe.

Por exemplo, o código abaixo vai gerar um **erro de compilação**.

```
private readonly IMyService _myService;

public HomeController(IMyService myService)
{
    _myService = myService;
}

public ActionResult AlgumMetodoQualquer()
{
    _myService = new Service();
    // ^ Isso não é possível, porque o campo é readonly
}
```

Em contrapartida, o código compila normalmente quando o modificador é removido.

Eu acho isso útil em casos como no exemplo que você mostrou na pergunta, onde um serviço é injetado. Se ele é injetado, o campo não precisa e **não pode** ter seu valor reatribuído.

---

Respondendo os itens: — note que a redundância é proposital

> Quando usar o readonly?

Quando você pretende que a variável não tenha seu valor **reatribuído** em alguma parte da classe que não seja o construtor.

> Há ganho de alguma coisa usando ele?

Há ganho da possibilidade de ter certeza que a variável não terá seu valor **reatribuído** em alguma parte da classe que não seja o construtor.

> Há perda de alguma coisa usando ele?

Há perda da possibilidade de reatribuir o valor da variável em qualquer parte da classe que não seja o construtor.

> Por que usar?

Para evitar que o valor da variável seja reatribuído em qualquer parte da classe que não seja o construtor.

> Por que não usar?

Para **não evitar** que o valor da variável seja reatribuído em qualquer parte da classe que não seja o construtor.

Comment: Legal.. A parte que havia ficado mais com dúvida era sobre a injeção. Sobre duplicada, acho que foi um caso de "mudou a cor da grama, morri de fome" ;)

Comment: @Barbetta Tranquilo, eu sei como é. Deixei explícito porque tem gente aqui no site que vota negativo só de ver que tem resposta pra pergunta dup.