# Por que eu não consigo declarar uma constante usando operador ternário em C#?

Tags: c#, .net, operadores, constantes

Eu tenho uma classe estática onde existe um método privado estático que recebe um parâmetro booleano. Dentro dele, minha intenção é declarar uma constante onde, se o booleano for `true`, terá um valor, e se for `false`, terá outro valor, da seguinte forma:

```
namespace meuprojeto.Models.Utils
{
    public static class MinhaClasse
    {
        // (...)

        private static string MeuMetodoPrivado(string stringNaoFormatada, bool boolArg = false)
        {
            string aux = String.Empty;
            const int MAX_LENGTH = boolArg == true ? 14 : 11;

            // Tratamento do aux onde uso um 'for (...)' usando 'i < MAX_LENGTH'

            return aux;
        }

        // (...)

        public static string MeuMetodoPublico(this string stringNaoFormatada)
        {
            string stringFormatada = MeuMetodoPrivado(stringNaoFormatada, true);
            return stringFormatada;
        }

        // (...)
    }
}
```

Porém ao escrever o código dessa forma, o compilador retorna o seguinte erro: `The expression being assigned to 'MAX_LENGTH' must be constant`. Se eu troco de constante para variável normal, `int MAX_LENGTH...`, dá certo normal, e se eu declaro a constante com um número direto, (por exemplo o 14), também dá certo. Então minha dúvida é: O problema está em declarar uma constante usando operador ternário?

#### EDIT:

Editei o código colocando exatamente como ele é, com namespace e com o método público que uso para chamar o método privado. Outrossim, no método público eu uso o `this`, que me permite chamar a função logo após um ponto de uma string, por exemplo, `minhaString.MeuMetodoPublico()`, sem a necessidade de passar por parâmetro (`MinhaClasse.MeuMetodoPublico(minhaString)`).

Comment: Constantes precisam ser valores literais; constantes, ou seja, apenas valores que sejam previsíveis e que não sejam definidos por expressões ou condições. O conceito de constantes em C# é diferente de algumas linguagens como Javascript por ex.

Comment: Não diretamente relacionado, mas um *booleano* não precisa ser comparado com `true` (e nem com `false`), então a expressão é equivalente a `boolArg ? 14 : 11`

Comment: Obrigado @CypherPotato.

Comment: Obrigado, @hkotsubo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nada impede que valores constantes, ou seja, conhecidos em tempo de compilação, sejam usados para estabelecer um valor de uma constante.

A expressão completa usada precisa ser perfeitamente constante, ou seja, todos os 3 valores usados são conhecidos em tempo de compilação e pode ser resolvido pelo compilador e usar o valor que precisa, portanto poderia resolver.

Se for uma variável, ela deve ter seu valor definido em tempo de execução então só compila o código todo e resolve depois.

Tenta:

```
const int x = true ? 1 : 0;
System.Console.Write(x);
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/HXpgj1). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/B7E7j2). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Operator/Const.cs).

Agora todos os 3 valores da expressão são conhecidos durante a compilação e ele compila, só não faz sentido. Claramente seu código precisa de uma variável e não uma constante. O valor usado varia de acordo com um valor ainda não conhecido durante a compilação.

O problema não é o uso do operador condicional (que por acaso é ternário), está em não ter valores constantes para resolver a expressão. O operador pode ser usado sim, ainda que não faça sentido em quase todas as situações (eu vejo uma que faz).

Se quer garantir que o valor não mude depois de atribuído, faça a variável ser só de leitura, [mande ela ser `readonly`, não `const`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151721/101). Em caso de ser variável local, então deixe como variável normalmente mesmo, é administrável assim, pelo menos até aceitarem `readonly` em variável local.

Comment: Obrigado, @Maniero. Eu editei o código colocando exatamente como ele é, com namespace e com o método público que uso para chamar o método privado. Outrossim, no método público eu uso o `this`, que me permite chamar a função logo após um ponto de uma string, por exemplo, `minhaString.MeuMetodoPublico()`, sem a necessidade de passar por parâmetro (`MinhaClasse.MeuMetodoPublico(minhaString)`).

Comment: E não muda nada na questão, ainda bem.

Comment: Uma última dúvida, por favor: Para usar o `readonly`, ele precisa ser uma das propriedades da classe, certo? Ou seja, fora do escopo do método. Mas sendo uma classe estática, como isso poderia ocorrer? Pois pelo que li o valor inicial dos `readonly` são definidos no construtor e as classes estáticas não têm construtor. Dúvida apenas para curiosidade, pois declarar MAX_LENGTH como variável no método ao invés de constante já vai me servir tranquilo.

Comment: @Diogo `readonly` não é definido no construtor. Você pode ter membros estáticos somente leitura também. `static readonly int MAX_LENGTH = ...`

Comment: @Diogo é verdade, tinha me esquecido desse detalhe, como você está usando localmente, p melhor é deixar como variável normal mesmo, não faz muita diferença, em um código pequeno é administrável.