# É possível declarar um array constante em C#?

Tags: c#, array, .net, constantes

Sei que não existe esta sintaxe, mas poderia ter algo que faça mais ou menos isto?

```
public const int[] array = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A palavra-chave usada para dar uma certa constância em C# é o `readonly`, embora não faça a mesma coisa que o `const`. Isso torna o objeto do *array* imutável, mas não o conteúdo dentro dele, então provavelmente não é o que deseja.

```
public readonly int[] array = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

impedirá que coloque outro *array* na variável `array`. Isso implica que não pode mudar o tamanho do *array* já que este tip ode estrtura não tem essa elasticidade. Porém se você trocar o `1` por `5` vai acontecer sem problemas, não é imutável internamente.

Se deseja realmente que o conteúdo seja imutável a única forma é usar uma estrutura feita especificamente para isto, e não um *array* da linguagem. Geralmente irá usar a [`ImmutableArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablearray-1?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). [Outras coleções imutáveis podem ser mais interessantes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable?view=net-8.0).

Note que ele só impede a mudança do conteúdo, a variável pode ser mudada se não tiver o `readonly`.

E ainda se deseja constância de verdade, da mesma forma que um dado simples, aí não tem como, [veja mais a diferença](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151721/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Collection/ConstArray.cs).

Answer (score -2):

A palavra reservada const é apenas permitida para tipos premitivos.
Use **readonly** para criar um array que não pode ser mudado após a inicialização.