# Boxing está copiando os dados

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos

*Boxing* é pra transformar *value type* em *reference type*, certo?

Mas quando copiamos um reference type em outro *reference type*, ele apenas copia o endereço e não o valor. Mas quando converto `int` pra `object` por exemplo e copio pra outro objeto, não está funcionando do mesmo jeito.

Exemplo:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int x = 10;
            object obj = x; //int vira reference type
            object obj2 = obj; //copia o endereço do obj pro obj2, certo?
            obj = 20; //modifica obj
            System.Console.WriteLine((int)obj2); //mostra obj2, era pra mostrar 20, nao? 
            //por que mostra 10?
            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Boxing* cria uma nova instância de um [tipo por referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/101). *Boxing* não muda a [imutabilidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/101) do tipo do dado sendo armazenado. Pelo contrário, ela garante. Se você tiver um tipo por valor mutável, o que é raro, você não consegue mudar seu valor enquanto ele está encaixotado. Primeiro teria que desencaixotar, mudar o membro desejado e depois encaixotar novamente.

O que seu código está fazendo é simplesmente copiar um valor para um novo objeto usando um tipo por referência. Você tem ali um `object` que concretamente carrega um `int`, portanto apesar dele estar encaixotado em um tipo por referência, no fundo ele tem uma representação interna de um tipo por valor. Então no momento que você copia `obj` para `obj2` está copiando sua referência, como é de se esperar. Neste momento as duas variáveis apontam para o mesmo objeto no [*heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101).

Mas isto vai mudar em versões futuras da linguagem.

Você está fazendo dois *boxings* aí no código. Quando faz `obj = x` e depois quando faz `obj = 20`. Sim, você está encaixotando o valor 20. 20 é um dado de um tipo por valor. Não é só variáveis que possuem tipo. Na verdade dados possuem tipo, variáveis possuem o tipo do seu valor.

Então você acha que `obj` e `obj2` estão apontando para o mesmo objeto, e estão até que você faça um novo *boxing*, aí outro objeto é criado e aquela variável passa apontar para para outro endereço e elas ficam independentes.

Se a linguagem não operasse desta forma ela violaria a imutabilidade do tipo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Então quando faço obj = 20, ele cria outro int na heap? E o obj2 continua sendo o endereço do "int antigo" na heap?

Comment: Exatamente isto. Porque esta é a função do *boxing*. "Cria uma nova instância" é a chave para entender o seu funcionamento. Note que hoje raramente é necessário o *boxing* em C#. Isto era importante no C# 1 antes da existências de *generic*. Continua sendo no Java.

Comment: `"Note que hoje raramente é necessário o boxing em C#"` sem falar na queda de performance que este tipo de operação pode causar. :)

Answer (score 3):

De forma bem simples é o seguinte: o Boxing faz conversão do VALOR que esta na pilha para heap e obviamente o Unboxing é o contrário. Então vamos aos passos que o .Net fez:

- int x = 10 // Isso esta na pilha.
- object obj = x // cria um endereço no HEAP e colocar o valor 10
- object obj2 = obj; //Neste momento existe dois "ponteiros" para o mesmo endereço no HEAP
- obj = 20 // Aqui é o segredo, pois neste momento esta sendo realizado um no novo Boxing ou seja esta criando no novo endereço na memoria HEAP para o objeto obj.