# Qual o comportamento da variável referência e da variável primitiva?

Tags: java, variáveis, memória

Qual o comportamento de uma variável do tipo referência (null) e do tipo primitiva (0) na memória antes de serem inicializadas. Onde elas estão na memória?

Comment: Respondi o que dava, não sei o que quer dizer com comportamento.

Comment: Reparei agora que nunca aceitaste uma resposta às perguntas que fizeste. É boa prática aceitar respostas se elas resolveram o teu problema...

Comment: Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 6):

Primeiro entenda que [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) é um endereço da memória que você deu um nome.

Tanto as variáveis baseadas em classes - que são referências - como as chamadas primitivas - que são por valor - podem estar [na *stack* ou no *heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101). Depende de onde ela pertença.

As variáveis por referência possuem apenas ponteiros e eles podem estar em ambas as áreas da memória dependendo da necessidade. Se a variável é local a um método, ela estará na *stack*, caso contrário estará no *heap*. Só que estas variáveis, a não ser que sejam nulas, sempre apontam para um outro objeto na memória. Este objeto está sempre no *heap* (salvo alguma otimização interna).

No caso das variáveis por valor, os primitivos (na verdade tipo por valor, porque isso vai gerar confusão quando Java ter, e [terá, tipos por valor não primitivos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157994/101)), o próprio objeto está no local da variável. Se ela foi declarada localmente em um método ela estará na *stack*. Mas se ela pertencer a outro objeto por referência (uma classe, um *array*), então obviamente ela estará no *heap*, afinal, o objeto dono dela já está no *heap*.

Já [respondi sobre isso para o C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/101). É bem parecido.

A inicialização das variáveis sempre gerará um valor *default* pré-definido pela linguagem. Não importa o tipo. O valor é sempre 0 e cada tipo pode tratar esse zero de uma forma diferente. No caso dos tipos por referência será nulo, já que este tipo é um ponteiro, mas não deixa de ser um belo zero.

Só um construtor - mesmo que seja o *default* - poderá colocar valor no objeto apontado pela referência, ou seja, precisa construir o objeto e atribuir seu endereço para a variável. Os membros internos deste tipo serão inicializados de acordo com o estabelecido na classe, podendo, é claro, ser o que vem pelo construtor. Algumas pessoas acham que este é o valor da variável, mas conceitualmente falando, não é. Claro que usamos o termo do jeito errado no dia a dia e todo mundo entende.

Então é possível não inicializar o objeto por referência mas todas variáveis serão inicializadas com um valor.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 3):

Não é possível **não** inicializar uma variável primitiva. Veja o teste:

```
public class Teste {

    static int iInstancia;          //inicializada automaticamente, com 0
    static Integer objInstancia;    //não-inicializada

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int iLocal;
        Integer objLocal;
        System.out.println(iInstancia);
        System.out.println(objInstancia);
        //System.out.println(iLocal); //erro de compilação
        //System.out.println(objLocal); //erro de compilação
    }
}
```

Resultado:

> 0
>   null

Para o caso de uma variável primitiva da classe, ela é inicializada automaticamente com um valor padrão. Para uma variável de um método, independente de ser primitiva ou de referência, ela deve ser inicializada, caso contrário o código nem compila. Observe as linhas que dizem `//erro de compilação`, caso você tente *descomentar* essas linhas e compilar o código.

Já onde elas estão na memória, é bem respondida pelo Maniero.