# Devo inicializar strings (ou objetos em geral) com null?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, estilo-de-codificação, null

Tenho percebido que uma prática comum entre programadores é inicializar um atributo de uma classe com `null`. Essa é uma boa prática ou não? Existe alguma diferença entre inicializar com `null` ou não inicializar "at all" ? Exemplo:

```
public class MinhaClasse {

       String str1 = null;

}
```

Comment: Só pode ser prática comum entre os programadores que ainda não compreendem o funcionamento da linguagem. Declarar um campo sem especificar valor já é maneira de especificar que deseja-se a atribuição padrão; então escrever código para isso é repetir-se. Já para as variáveis declaradas no corpo dos métodos, eventualmente, pode ter utilidade atribuir explicitamente o valor padrão (e esta atribuição explícita pode inclusive ser exigida pelo compilador).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Nenhuma diferença, o compilador inicializa os atributos de classe com null por padrão. No caso de tipos primitivos, inicializa com o valor padrão (false para boolean e 0 para double, long, int...)

Answer (score 7):

Na minha opinião não deve, de forma objetiva, tanto faz. Só que está sendo redundante e não acho isto bom, até que me prove que em determinado lugar é o melhor a fazer.

Quase sempre deixar de inicializar uma variável é ruim. Porque deixar para depois o que pode fazer agora? Talvez porque está declarando variáveis cedo demais. Eu vejo muito código que declara todas variáveis e depois vai usando. Esta técnica é arcaica. O estilo moderno é declarar a variável o mais perto possível de onde ela será usada. Claro que em alguns casos pode fazer sentido declarar a variável e não inicializar, mas é raro.

Sempre que possível inicialize os objetos com um valor que sirva para alguma coisa. Não podemos dizer estritamente que dizer que a variável é `null` está inicializando ela, mas há casos que deixá-la como [`null` pode indicar alguma coisa útil para o código](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101).

Não faz muito sentido inicializar variáveis primitivas se o que você precisa é o valor *default* dele. Escrever `int x = 0;` é a mesma coisa que escrever `int x;` (embora em variáveis locais esta forma não é aceita). Claro que pode ser interessante fazer isto para deixar explícito que deseja o 0 de forma consciente. É o mesmo caso do `null`, afinal este é o valor *default* de [objetos por referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Em determinados momentos é preciso inicializar de forma explicita o valor default mesmo que sendo null pois o compilador "xia".  Mas respondendo a pergunta não vejo como uma boa pratica inicializar o objeto como null (inicializar quando decladarado no escopo da classe igual está na descrição da pergunta) nunca vi dessa forma, sempre confiro o código fonte das bibliotecas de terceiros que adiciono nos meus projetos e nunca vi isso, nao que me lembro.

Comment: Curioso. Você tem algum exemplo que o compilador faz isso?

Comment: Sim, crie um método que deve retornar um String, declare o String e somente inicializa ele dentro de um if, e no fim do método coloque para retornar essa String. O compilador xia para você inicializar  a string, pois não há garantia que o if será true.

Comment: O compilador me devolve isso ao tentar executar o código. `java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - variable string might not have been initialized`

Comment: Precisaria ver isto dentro de um contexto. Estou achando coisa horrível. Mas se colocar `null` resolve? Ou seja, tem que fazer para atender *design* ruim dos outros? :)

Comment: @Skywalker O compilador C# também acusa este tipo de erro. É um alerta útil pois se o programador retornou uma variável que pode nunca ter sido atribuída com coisa alguma, pode ser um erro de programação (provavelmente esqueceu de escrever uma linha de código que tinha intenção de escrever); e se o programador deseja mesmo prosseguir com null no caso de não atribuição, o compilador exige que ele declare explicitamente esta intenção.

Answer (score 7):

Em Java, não é obrigatório inicializar atributos de classe. Tipos primitivos recebem valores padrão e objetos são `null` automaticamente.

Entretanto, variáveis declarados dentro do corpo de um método não recebem valores padrão e o compilador vai reclamar se você tentar usá-las sem atribuir um valor antes.

Porém, em geral é uma péssima prática permitir que um programa execute num estado inconsistente. Boa prática é sempre tentar garantir que os valores adequados foram definidos antes de usá-los.

A forma de fazer isso em atributos de classe é sempre que possível inicializar o valor na declaração, quando isso faz sentido. Sempre que possível, ainda use atributos com o modificador `final`, que obrigam o programador a inicializá-las em algum momento até o final do método construtor.

Exemplo:

```
class Configuracao {
    private final String diretorio;
    public Configuracao(Properties properties) {
        this.diretorio = properties.getProperty("diretorio", "/tmp");
    }
}
```

Já variáveis dentro de método, evite completamente inicializá-las com valores aleatórios somente para silenciar o compilador, antes deixe-o ajudar a não deixar brechas no seu programa.

Exemplo ruim:

```
String getNome() {
    String nome = "Valor que nunca deve ser usado";
    if (condicao()) nome = getNomeDeVerdade();
    return nome;
}
```

No exemplo acima, caso a condição não seja satisfeita, o valor que não deveria existir será retornado. Eu sei que parece ridículo, mas já vi várias versões disso por aí porque alguém seguiu a "dica" da IDE ou compilador dizendo para *inicializar a variável*.

O correto seria não inicializar a variável e tratar o outro caso especificamente:

```
String getNome() throws Exception {
    String nome;
    if (condicao()) nome = getNomeDeVerdade();
    else throw new Exception("Nome não pode ser determinado");
    return nome;
}
```

Por outro lado, se nem sempre um valor é retornado, use [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) e não `null` ou `""` para representar tal ausência.

Exemplo:

```
Optional<String> getNome() throws Exception {
    return condicao() ? 
            Optional.of(getNomeDeVerdade()) : 
            Optional.empty();
}
```

Aí quem chamar o método deverá verificar se há um valor retornado:

```
Optional<String> nome = metodo();
if (nome.isPresent()) {
    fazerAlgumaCoisa(nome.ge());
} else {
    tratarSituacaoSemNome();
}
```

Este tipo de técnica praticamente elimina comportamentos estranhos do sistema causados por valores inesperados, além do maior causados de problemas, o `NullPointerException`.

Comment: utluiz sempre com respostas excelentes, muito legal :) Tenho uma dúvida com relação ao uso do Optional em parametros, é interessante começar a fazer uso para ter uma semântica mais clara na hora realizar a verificação?

Comment: @DouglasGaldino Isso vale uma nova pergunta ;) - mas resumindo existem sim alguns momentos em que vale a pena usar isso em parâmetros. Na maioria dos casos você pode simplesmente sobrecarregar o método numa versão sem o tal parâmetro, mas se isso vai obrigar você a fazer `if`s em todo lugar é melhor usar o `Optional`.

Comment: Entendi, mas precisaria ponderar também nas sobrecargas, para evitar multiplos métodos ou isso tem pouca influência na qualidade do código?

Comment: @DouglasGaldino Sim, múltiplos métodos, quando muito variados, também não são legais. Se há muitas variáveis, então há outra alternativa, que é criar um tipo (classe) específica para representar os parâmetros do método. E aí você pode usar um pattern como *builder* com *method chaining* para melhorar isso. Se você usa uma implementação JAX-RS, como Jersey, já deve ter visto isso na hora de retornar uma resposta, tal como `Response.ok(entity).status(200).build()`.

Comment: Sim, conheço o pattern builder. Entendi melhor agora o processo de lidar com múltiplos parâmetros. O intuito das perguntas foi apenas para tentar melhorar o processo, mantendo a qualidade mesmo quando uma opção deixa de ser boa em tal momento. Valeu :]

Answer (score 5):

> Não acredito que seja uma boa prática deixar explicito ou não, mesmo
>   em casos de escopo local em métodos, onde na maior parte das vezes é
>   necessário inicializar.

O motivo é por deixar aberto a possibilidade de termos que lidar com a `Exception` mais comum no desenvolvimento, a `NullPointerException`.

A **boa prática** que conheço é sempre ou sempre que possível **inicializar** a *variável*, seja ela tipo *primitivo* ou um *objeto*.

Assim não tendo um `null` mesmo em casos de atributos *opicionais*, consequentemente evitando o `NullPointerException`.

Ex:

```
public class Endereco {

   private String rua = "";
   private int numero = 0;

   //getters e setters
}
```