# Por que Shortstring consome mais memória do que uma String comum?

Tags: string, delphi, memória, delphi-7

Fiz um exemplo aqui para ver quanto de memória consome cada variável e notei que uma variável do tipo `ShortString` consome 256 enquanto uma variável do tipo `String` consome apenas 4. Segue exemplo para verificação:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    String1: ShortString;
    String2: String;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
   String1 := 'Teste';
   String2 := 'Teste';
   ShowMessage(Format('String1: %d'+#13+'String2: %d',[SizeOf(String1),SizeOf(String2)]));
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ShortString` é um tipo por valor, então o texto está nela. `String` é um tipo por referência, então a variável só terá um ponteiro para o texto que está em outro lugar.

Note que `ShortString` pode ter até 255 caracteres. Ela tem o tamanho total de 2 a 256 bytes, um byte é usado para indicar o tamanho dela. O tamanho não pode mudar nem pra mais, nem pra menos. Exemplo de uso:

```
var texto : string[30]; //ocupará 31 bytes
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Pascal/String.pas).

Ela é considerada obsoleta e não deve ser usada, é difícil fazer ela funcionar corretamente.

- [Alocação de memória em C# - Tipos valor e tipos referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/101) (é outra linguagem mas o conceito é o mesmo)

Comment: É recomendado então não usar shortstrings?

Comment: Exatamente, conforme está na resposta.