# Passar objeto complexo vs objeto mais simples por parâmetro

Tags: c#, .net, desempenho

No método `Log` existe o parâmetro do tipo `HttpClient`. A função só utiliza o parâmetro para acessar a propriedade `BaseAddress`, que é um `Uri`.

```
private void Log(string verb, HttpClient httpClient) {
    var url = httpClient.BaseAddress.ToString();
    Logging.LogInfo(GetType().Name, $"Iniciou requisição HTTP {verb} no endereço {url}");
}
```

Como todos que chamam `Log(string, HttpClient)` também tem acesso ao `HttpClient.BaseAddress`, o método `Log` poderia ser assim:

```
private void Log(string verb, string url) {
    Logging.LogInfo(GetType().Name, $"Iniciou requisição HTTP {verb} no endereço {url}");
}
```

e quem o chama:

```
Log(HttpVerbs.Post, anotherHttpClient.BaseAddress.ToString());
```

Dessa forma, eu não passaria o objeto mais complexo do tipo `HttpClient` mas só o que me interessa, que é uma `string`. Fiz da primeira forma, passando `HttpClient` no caso de no futuro eu precisar de mais informações do cliente HTTP no log.

Considerando `HttpClient` o tipo mais complexo e `string` o mais simples, o que quero saber é se existe diferença na performance e no uso de memória das duas maneiras.

É a mesma coisa fazer com o objeto complexo e o objeto mais simples? Alguma vai consumir mais ou menos memória? Como isso é tratado no .NET?

Comment: É tudo passado por referência, o uso de memória não é relevante.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14490/aloca%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-mem%C3%B3ria-em-c-tipos-valor-e-tipos-refer%C3%AAncia

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De forma geral o consumo não faz diferença. Pode ter consequências colaterais, mas depende de muita coisa e não acho que ainda seria importante. Pelo menos para esse caso não vejo acontecendo.

O que muda é a questão da engenharia.

Quanto mais informações você passa, mais está [acoplando](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101).

Por outro lado quanto mais concreta é a informação passada mais detalhe de implementação você está passando, o que não deixa de ser um acoplamento.

Ou seja, é difícil seguir uma regra. Tem que tentar achar o que faz mais sentido para o caso. Quais as chances de algo mudar e criar uma complicação? Na maior parte das vezes recomenda-se ir no que tem menor risco. Mas sempre pode ter alguma diretriz no projeto que pode exigir fazer diferente.

Algumas pessoas chamarão isso de [obsessão por primitivos](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrimitiveObsession). Assim como abusar disso é errado, nunca usá-lo também é, depende do caso.

Sem conhecer o caso concreto eu diria que passar a informação mais específica é melhor aí porque é ela que você precisa. Vai que ela possa ser obtida por outras fontes que não o `HttpClient`? Claro que não é o fim do mundo, sempre dá para criar uma sobrecarga e se não abusar de primitivos fica fácil ter uma assinatura diferente. Talvez fosse o caso até mesmo de já criar ambos. Mas também duvido que seja um problema adotar o objeto mais completo para abstrair como ele pega o que precisa.

Agora, isso é a teoria. Na prática tem muito caso que isso não é relevante.