# Qual a diferença entre "value types" e "reference types"?

Tags: c#, variáveis, tipagem, memória

Não entendi muito bem essas classificação entre os tipos que uma variável pode conter que são **value types** (*tipos de valor*) e **reference types** (*tipos de referência*) que existe na linguagem C#, no que diz a [especificação](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/types-and-variables):

> Há dois tipos em C#: tipos de referência e tipos de valor. **As variáveis de tipos de valor contêm diretamente seus dados enquanto variáveis de tipos de referência armazenam referências a seus dados**, o último sendo conhecido como objetos. Com os tipos de referência, é possível que duas variáveis referenciem o mesmo objeto e, assim, possíveis para operações em uma variável afetem o objeto referenciado pela outra variável. Com os tipos de valor, as variáveis têm sua própria cópia dos dados, e não é possível que as operações em um afetem a outra (exceto ref para out variáveis de parâmetro e).

Como assim? na parte negritada no meu entender (se eu estiver errado, me corrigem) está dizendo que variáveis *value types* são variáveis que tem o seu valor atribuído claramente, por exemplo:

```
int n1 = 1000; // value types
```

Enquanto variáveis *reference types* são variáveis que referenciam a um dado definido em outro lugar, por exemplo:

```
int n1 = 1000; // value types
int n2 = n1; // reference types
```

Não sei se acima está relativamente certo, se não quais são as diferenças entre estas classificações?

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Alocação de memória em C# - Tipos valor e tipos referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14490/aloca%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-mem%c3%b3ria-em-c-tipos-valor-e-tipos-refer%c3%aancia)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seria interessante ler [Alocação de memória em C# - Tipos valor e tipos referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/101).

Seu exemplo está errado, as duas variáveis possuem tipos por valor, talvez por isso não está entendendo.

Em `n1` você está armazenando um valor em uma posição de memória, que está localizada na pilha e nomeada através de uma [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101). Em seguida o código cria outra variável chamada `n2` e diz que seu valor é o mesmo que estava em `n1` e portanto **uma cópia** é feita (isso é feito com o operador de atribuição `=`). São dois objetos completamente diferentes que por acaso tem o mesmo valor.

Pensa em um carro Fiat 147 branco ano 1978 que você tem. Eu tenho um carro com essas mesmas características, mas não é o mesmo carro.

Quando você cria um tipo por referência, como o objeto está em outro lugar e a variável tem só uma referência para ele aí pode ser que duas variáveis apontem para o mesmo objeto.

```
var s1 = "teste";
var s2 = s1;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Method/Guard.java).

Esse caso haverá um só objeto , que será alocado no *heap*, que contém um texto com a palavra `teste` e uma referência para esse objeto é armazenada na variável `s1`.

Logo em seguida outra variável chamada `s2` é criada e através do operador de atribuição `=` uma cópia do valor da variável é copiada. Mas qual é o valor da variável `s1? É a referência para o objeto com o texto. Então é feita uma cópia igual, mas como o tipo é por referência só isso, a referência, que é copiada. Com a cópia existem duas referências em duas variáveis diferentes que por acaso possuem o mesmo valor, e portanto apontam para o mesmo objeto único.

Se quiser que tenha dois objetos completamente diferentes aí tem que fazer uma cópia do objeto, não só da referência. Quase sempre não quer isso, e hoje não há algo pronto que faça isso que seja considerado seguro e útil (pode fazer manualmente).

Como eu sei que essas variáveis são por referência? Porque o tipo do valor colocado nelas é um tipo por referência. Toda `string` é por referência. Você tem que saber o que é olhando na documentação. Quando cria seus tipos, dependendo da forma que declarar, ele será de um jeito ou de outro. E tem que aprender tudo isso, passo por passo.