# Por que ArrayList não pode ser iniciada com int?

Tags: java, array, tipagem, genéricos

Estou estudando as diferenças entre `Array` e `ArrayList` em Java e notei que a última não pode ser iniciada usando `int`. Por exemplo, o código abaixo roda normalmente:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> MyArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        MyArray.add(1);
        MyArray.add(2);
        MyArray.add(3);
    }
}
```

Mas se eu trocar `Integer` por `int`, o código deixa de funcionar.

Por outro lado, com `Arrays` isso não ocorre, já que o código abaixo funciona com `Integer` ou `int`:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Integer[] MyArray = {1,2,3};
    }
}
```

Por que a diferença?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Integer` é um tipo por referência, e `int` é um tipo por valor. [Veja mais sobre](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/101) C# que é igual, só mais flexível ([veja mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16181/101)). Tem algo [em Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/464539/101).

O Java começou com essa diferença e depois quando veio o tipo genérico fizeram uma implementação que funciona bem, se tiver um ponteiro sendo usado, ou seja, só o tipo por referência é aceito facilmente.

[Java escolheu ter *generics* só em tempo de compilação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/10032/101), então complica dar uma flexibilidade.

É muito mais fácil a linguagem lidar com tudo de forma linear, especialmente sobre o gerenciamento de memória, já que tipo por referência em Java (e C#) sempre vai no *heap*, e tipo por valor vai na *stack* (isso vai mudar). Misturar isso não é tão simples, mas possível.

É possível colocar um tipo por valor se a linguagem desejar, mas não é fácil fazer quando a linguagem começou diferenciando isso de forma tão grande.

De fato eles [estão prometendo que o tipo por valor seja cidadão de primeira classe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157994/101) e possa ser usado em todo lugar, assim como o C# faz desde a primeira versão. Mas não estão conseguindo acertar tudo sem quebrar compatibilidade por causa desse começo. A decisão inicial foi equivocada (eu falo sempre que Java está se esforçando bastante para ser uma excelente linguagem, mas o começo ela não era tão boa e agora paga o preço por esse começo "ruim").

O *array* é especial para a linguagem, ele não usa o sistema de genericidade da linguagem, o tipo é genérico controlado pelo compilador, até porque tem isso desde o começo, os tipos genéricos para as coleções de biblioteca só vieram na versão 5. E justamente por ser possível você criar seus próprios tipos e não ser da linguagem, precisava de um mecanismo diferente.

Em *design* de linguagem, quando você começa errado pode nunca conseguir consertar o problema, ou pode ser bem difícil, a não ser que aceite quebrar a compatibilidade de tudo que já existe.

Poderiam ter feito o genérico ser melhor desde a versão 5? Poderiam, mas teriam que consertar tanta coisa que só sairia na versão 10, e o C# ganhando terreno em cima, não dava para esperar, melhor alguma coisa que nada.

Pode ajudar: [Qual diferença entre Boolean e boolean?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/160914/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).