# Preciso de ajuda com C# / asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

### Estou programando uma calculadora utilizando asp.net e c#. So que estou com um problema nao consigo informar ao meu codigo por meio de uma variável quando e para fazer Adição ou subtração por exemplo.

---

##### E esta e a função do Onclick de um dos botões numéricos (0 a 9).

---

```
public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((textBox.Text == "+") || (textBox.Text == "-") || (textBox.Text == "x") || (textBox.Text == "/") || (textBox.Text == "√"))
        {
            textBox.Text = "";
            textBox.Text = textBox.Text + Button1.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            textBox.Text = textBox.Text + Button1.Text;
        }
    }
```

---

##### Esta e a função do Onclick do botão de um dos operados (+)

---

```
public void ButtonAdi_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        num1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox.Text);
        textBox.Text = "";
        operador = 1;

        if (operador == 1)
        {
            textBox.Text += "+";
        }
    }
```

---

##### E esta e a função do Onclick do botão de igual

---

```
public void ButtonIgu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string num2str;
        float resultado;

        num2str = textBox.Text;

        num2 = Convert.ToInt32(num2str);
        textBox.Text = "";


        if (operador == 1)
        {
            resultado = num1 + num2;
            textBox.Text += resultado;
        }
        else
        {
            textBox2.Text += "erro";

        }




    }
```

---

##### Há 3 variáveis globais ja declaradas no codigo

---

```
    static float num1, num2;

    int operador;
```

---

##### Como descrito anteriormente meu problema esta sendo que a variável operador so aparece como 1 dentro da função do Onclick, quando chamada no if do Onclick Button_igu ela aparece como 0 como declarada primeiramente, nao como 1 como redeclarada no Onclick Button_Adi

---

Answer (score -2):

Luccas isso ocorre porque voce não atribuiu um valor diferente para o contador dentro do botão igu, e quando essa variavel é alterada dentro do botão ADI não reflete no IGU, porque ela a variavel não esta de fato sendo alterada isso ocorre porque voce usa uma variavel do tipo valor e não do tipo referencia, mas o assunto é bastante extenso então acho melhor voce dar uma olhada nesse link caso queira se informar mais [https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/464539/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-value-types-e-reference-types#:~:text=H%C3%A1%20dois%20tipos%20em%20C,%C3%BAltimo%20sendo%20conhecido%20como%20objetos.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/464539/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-value-types-e-reference-types#:%7E:text=H%C3%A1%20dois%20tipos%20em%20C,%C3%BAltimo%20sendo%20conhecido%20como%20objetos.)

mas de maneira resumida a sua variavel do botão adi não tem relação com a do botão igu.