# Métodos e propriedades em C# - vantagens e desvantagens

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, encapsulamento, propriedade

Em C# temos propriedades com getters e setters, o que facilita a inserção e leitura de dados em um objeto quando alguma lógica deve ser realizada. Em outras linguagens, como o Java essas tarefas são feitas com métodos: quando precisamos de lógica para ler um campo ou para escrever nele usamos métodos `getCampo` e `setCampo`, coisas do tipo.

Essa abordagem com métodos também pode ser feita no C# e é ai que ta minha dúvida. Quais são as vantagens e desvantagens no C# dessas duas abordagens? Minha preocupação com essa questão é a seguinte: estive resolvendo exercícios de orientação a objetos e notei que a grande maioria dos métodos que os exercícios pedem pra codificar *podem* se tornar propriedades no C#. O problema é que isso faz a classe parecer anêmica, ou seja, tendo só propriedades e sem lógica.

Dessa forma, existem diferenças entre as duas abordagens? Existe algum tipo de recomendação sobre qual técnica usar?

**EDIÇÃO**: A resposta do @Maniero é muito boa e esclarece algumas coisas com relação a esse tipo de decisão, mas vou adicionar alguns exemplos para ilustar o que estou falando, só pra completar um ponto. Os exemplos são de exercícios em Java. Um dos exercícios que resolvi pedia uma classe `Data` com métodos `getDia`, `getMes`, `getAno` e `isBissexto` para decidir se o ano é bissexto. Os métodos `get` claramente em C# poderiam ser implementados como getters.

Acontece que o `isBissexto` também poderia. Afinal ele devolve uma *característica* do objeto invés de executar um comportamento. Claro que existe uma lógica pra verificar isso, mas me pergunto se isso não seria uma propriedade.

Outro exercício pede uma classe `Prova` que deve ter métodos `respostaAluno` para inserir a alternativa da próxima questão, `acertos` para retornar o número de acertos, `nota` para retornar a nota e `maior` para comparar com outra prova.

Novamente, os métodos `acertos` e `nota` me parecem naturalmente propriedades. Eles são características da prova. Existe novamente uma lógica pra verificar isso, basicamente é preciso comparar cada questão com os dados provenientes de um gabarito informado no construtor, mas por conta de parecerem características achei que deveriam ser propriedades.

Acontece que tirando esses métodos e transformando em propriedades essas classes ficam quase sem funcionalidades, e não só elas mas muitas outras que já vi por ai. Isso indicaria o problema que ouvi dizer se chama "modelo anêmico".

Dessa forma, a decisão de algo como propriedade não depende somente de ser uma característica do objeto? Depende também de haver ou não uma lógica a ser utilizada para ler ou escrever aquele dado? Em casos então como esses que citei, é mais interessante então realmente utilizar métodos?

Comment: No caso, acho que anêmico significa algo bom... se uma classe anêmica faz o mesmo que outra classe mais "gordinha". Eu gosto do conceito de fazer mais com menos, ser mais expressivo com menos complexidade... e por ai vai.

Comment: Uma coisas que não dá pra fazer com propriedades são setters assíncronos. O getter ainda dá, mas eu não acho legal, prefiro um método. Um setter assíncrono seria assim: `async Task SetValueT(T value)`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A **recomendação inicial** é sempre usar o recurso existente na linguagem até que exista um motivo para não usar.

## Funcionamento da propriedade

Entenda que uma propriedade é apenas [*syntax sugar*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar), ou seja, na prática o compilador transforma uma propriedade em dois métodos. Por exemplo, se criar uma propriedade do tipo `string` chamada `Nome`, na verdade internamente terá um campo privado com nome semelhante a `__Nome` e dois métodos com nomes próximos a `string __getNome()` e `void __setNome(string value)`.

A implementação do primeiro deve ser apenas `return __Nome;` e do segundo `__Nome = value;`

#### Otimização

Algumas pessoas devem olhar para isso e achar que chamar um método e fazer o `set` ou `get` é mais lento que acessar o campo direto. Mas isso pode não acontecer porque provavelmente o [compilador JIT](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101) vai otimizar e acabará fazendo o acesso direto ao campo, eliminando a chamada ao método. E se não conseguir fazer a otimização, deve haver um bom motivo para isso.

Então, **inicialmente** não há razão para criar métodos `getNome()` e `setNome()` manualmente. Nenhuma vantagem. Pode ter a desvantagem de alguém não entender porque você fez isso.

## Quando não usar

Existem algumas situações que um método é preferível, mas não necessariamente a troca pura e simples da propriedade por um par de métodos *get* e *set*. A questão é saber se algo deva ser uma uma propriedade simples ou algo mais abrangente.

Uma propriedade:

- deve ser **simples**, não deveria executar operações complexas;
- não deveria lançar exceções explícita ou implicitamente através de chamadas a outros métodos internamente, principalmente o *get* deve fornecer um resultado sempre;
- não pode demorar (provavelmente poucos nanosegundos são recomendados);
- **evita** efeitos colaterais extras (mudar estado de outras propriedades);
- não é uma conversão de dados;
- costuma ser determinística;
- não retorna uma cópia de estado interno a não ser que seja um tipo por valor;
- não retorna um objeto muito grande, em geral um *array*.

O programador espera que uma propriedade seja tão trivial quanto pegar ou colocar um valor em uma variável. Se o código da propriedade não atender as diretrizes acima é **provável** que ela não seja uma propriedade mesmo. Mas nada é tão preto no branco.

#### Acesso a dados grandes ou externos

Se você vai criar uma propriedade chamada `Clientes` que devolve uma lista de clientes obtidos através de uma consulta ao banco de dados. Isto não é uma propriedade.

Algo que é complexo, faz acesso a recursos externos, pode ter várias exceções, é demorado (milissegundos é uma eternidade) não pode ser uma propriedade. Em casos assim, um método é mais adequado porque o programador espera que um método seja algo mais complexo e que muitas coisas podem ocorrer nele.

Então a solução é criar um campo `Clientes` e um método `getClientes()`?

Até pode ser a solução. Mas entenda que não é uma substituição direta da propriedade, é outra operação. Por isso seria bom até ter um outro nome e mais sugestivo do que ele faz. Por exemplo `ObtemTodosClientesNoDB()` ou `ObtemClientesSelecionadosNoDB()`. Se vai guardar o resultado em um campo privado da classe ou só retornar para quem pediu, vai da necessidade.

Se você está pensando em qualquer lógica não trivial de acesso e atribuição do valor, provavelmente não está pensando em propriedade.

#### Mudança de estado

Se uma propriedade não deveria mudar seu valor por conta própria. Muitas vezes vemos até o .NET errando nisto. Por exemplo a propriedade `Now` da classe `DateTime` não tem um valor estável. Então a recomendação seria utilizar um método (provavelmente `DateTime.GetCurrentDateTime()`) e não uma propriedade.

Há controvérsias se um campo de um banco de dados deveria ser representado por uma propriedade. O campo pode ser alterado por outros agentes externos a sua aplicação executando naquele momento. Ele não é estável. Por outro lado um campo tem a cara de uma propriedade. Você não acessa campos em um DB com métodos, você acessa com o nome do campo ou atribuição a este nome. Porém algumas classes representam uma imagem de um dado do banco de dados na memória e não o exato registro. Se pensar desta forma, você não está violando a recomendação da estabilidade do seu conteúdo. De qualquer forma, recomendações foram criadas para serem violadas quando há bom motivo para isto.

Propriedades não deveriam ter estado mutável. Por isso não deveria ser estruturas complexas, especialmente coleções de dados. Mas sempre há exceções.

Pense nos campos (estado) e os métodos (comportamento) que uma classe deve ter. Daí transforme seus campos em propriedades. Essa é uma "regrinha" que ajuda definir o que é o que. Se por acaso sua propriedade exige alguma lógica simples no `get` e/ou no `set`, aí você implementa.

## Uma propriedade é melhor que um campo público

Pelo menos pode dar mais flexibilidade para manutenção futura. Mas nem sempre essa flexibilidade é necessária.

## Contrato e abstração

Um campo público não pode ser substituído sem quebrar o "contrato" da classe. O acesso ou atribuição de valor em um campo não pode ser "interceptado" para executar alguma coisa diferente no processo de obtenção ou atribuição de valor, muito menos colocar uma intervenção dessas depois que o campo já foi disponibilizado publicamente para outros usarem. Não dá para fazer isso sem quebrar o contrato.

Então com a propriedade, que costuma ser pública, você encapsula o campo privado (detalhe de implementação), esconde a implementação concreta e publica apenas a abstração. Mesmo que não tenha nada o que fazer com a propriedade, ter isso desde o início na criação da classe permite que no futuro você possa alterar o comportamento dela sem quebrar nenhum contrato.

Por isto que só o JITter faz a otimização, ela é feita até o último momento, a otimização é feita levando em consideração, inclusive, o versionamento da sua aplicação.

#### O que é válido fazer em uma propriedade

Normalmente o máximo que uma propriedade possui de código é uma validação antes da atribuição, um cálculo simples antes de retornar um resultado, uma gravação no *log*, uma verificação de cache, etc. Quando tem!

Algumas pessoas acham que a utilização de cache em propriedade deveria ser desincentivada porque a primeira execução pode ser lenta. Mas há outra corrente que pensa que todas os demais acessos são muito rápidos e por isso a propriedade cai como uma luva. A propriedade apenas lê o valor armazenado no cache exceto no primeiro acesso que pode executar um processamento mais complexo. Eu gosto desta última, até porque isso já é bem comum em várias classes. Me parece uma boa exceção.

## O que não fazer

Uma propriedade deve ser vista como uma substituta para uma campo público. Não como substituta de métodos. Se esses métodos não estão fazendo **estritamente** operações ligadas de forma direta a um campo privado específico, então eles não deveriam ser pensados como propriedades.

Não há nenhum problema em ter métodos `getIsso()` ou `setIsso()` independentes se eles executam operações que vão além de simplesmente acessar e atribuir valores para um campo.

#### Simplificação

Note que a forma mais comum para declarar uma propriedade é

```
public string Nome { get; set; }
```

Ou seja, praticamente é o mesmo que declarar um campo público, mas tem a vantagem da abstração, isto é, permite que no futuro você adicione alguma lógica no `get` e/ou `set`. É raro usar lógica dentro desses elementos.

Com a propriedade você facilita a compatibilidade de fonte e binária. Além disso ganha capacidade de [reflexão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/154462/101) que um campo não tem. E é mais fácil *debugar* uma propriedade (campos não podem ter *breakpoint*) - recurso melhorado no Visual Studio 2015.

## Contraponto

O que muitas pessoas não percebem é que sistemas muitos simples que serão usados para poucas coisas, que a manutenção dele será quase inexistente e feita por uma pessoa, isso não é tão importante assim. Em sistemas assim pode ser melhor ir na solução mais simples que é deixar o campo público mesmo. A não ser que você saiba de antemão que vá precisar de algum processamento no acesso ou atribuição. Mesmo que um dia você tenha que alterar um acesso, em um sistema simples, mudar todos os locais de uso é bem fácil, ainda mais se estiver usando o Visual Studio e mais ainda com [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/).

Claro que se o sistema complicar um pouquinho vai te obrigar mexer nisso para dar mais tranquilidade de manutenção. Então tenha certeza que o sistema vai permanecer simples antes de fazer acesso direto.

## Seu problema específico

`getDia`, `getMes`, `getAno` e `isBissexto` seriam suas propriedades, certo? Vamos mudar um pouco os nomes delas. `Dia`, `Mes`, `Ano` e `isBissexto`. Pronto, agora fica mais condizente. Onde você guarda o dia chama `Dia`, onde guarda o mês, chama `Mes` e p/ guardar ano, chama `Ano`. Por fim onde você determina se **é** bissexto, chama `isBissexto`.

#### Estilo de código

É padrão adotado por boa parte dos programadores que valores booleanos tenham sempre um "Is" (ou "Eh" para quem gosta de aportuguesar, ou [`É` para quem gosta de acentos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16555/101)) antes do nome da propriedade para deixar claro que ali é um valor binário *true* ou *false*. A propriedade poderia muito bem chamar apenas `Bissexto`, mas um `IsBissexto` ou `EhBissexto` deixa mais claro que o que está guardado lá é se "é ou não é".

#### Exemplo

Então vamos supor que queira que algum código de fora da classe não possa *setar* essas propriedades, elas seriam implementadas assim:

```
public byte Dia { get; private set; }
public byte Mes { get; private set; }
public byte Ano { get; private set; }
public bool IsBissexto { get; private set; }
```

Lembre-se que não convertemos um método para uma propriedade, convertemos um campo para uma propriedade.

#### Raciocínio correto

Seu raciocínio sobre o `IsBissexto` está correto. Mesmo que exista uma lógica para obter se o ano é bissexto ou não, ele ainda é uma propriedade. De fato pode ser que o `IsBissexto` nem tenha o que chamamos de *backing field*, que é um campo privado que guarda um valor. É como se o `IsBissexto` fosse um campo virtual. Ele consegue te dar o resultado calculando algo. Uma implementação simplificada (calcular bissexto é mais complicado que isso) seria:

```
public bool IsBissexto { 
    get {
        return (Ano % 4 == 0);
    }                   
}
```

Na classe da prova, realmente tudo ali parece ser propriedade. Claro que você poderia ter, **hipoteticamente**, um método `AceitarResposta()` que não só colocaria uma valor em `repostaAluno` mas também aproveitaria para atualizar `acertos` e talvez mais uma ou outra coisa que fossem necessárias quando uma resposta é aceita na instância do objeto. Se esse `AceitarResposta` opera em várias propriedades, se ele faz mais que apenas atribuir um valor para uma propriedade específica, ele é claramente um método, um comportamento da classe.

#### Classes pobres (anêmicas)

Não há problema se uma classe tenha só propriedades. Não é tão comum, mas existem casos assim.

Claro que não entramos na questão do [construtor da classe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101). Nestes casos é comum ter pelo menos um construtor para *setar* os valores inciais das propriedades quando um objeto desta classe é criado. Mas aí já é outro assunto.

#### C# moderno

Em C# 6 isso é mais fácil e até pode, em certos casos, dispensar a existência de um construtor específico. [Em C# 6 uma propriedade pode ter um inicializador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108516/101):

```
public Decimal Nota { get; set; } = 0.00M;
```

Em C# 9 é possível deixar a propriedade apenas ser inicializada:

```
public Decimal Nota { get; init; };
```

#### Propriedade que faz processamento

A única ressalva que faço é na questão de haver lógica ou não. Uma propriedade pode ou não ter lógica (conceitualmente ela sempre tem a implementação indicada na segunda seção deste texto).

O que a lógica contida nela executa é que determina se é uma propriedade de fato ou deveria ser um método. Nos casos citados a lógica possível existente é só algo simples para dar acesso a informação, um cálculo com membros da classe. Eventualmente se o `set` estiver disponível você poderia implementar assim:

```
private byte mes;
public byte Mes { 
    get {
        return mes;
    }
    set {
        if (value > 0 && value <= 12) {
            mes = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Note que nos casos que você implementa uma lógica no `set` ou no `get`, não pode usar a forma compacta da sintaxe da propriedade. Neste caso deve declarar um campo privado (normalmente se usa o mesmo nome que a propriedade, só que iniciando com minúscula) e depois declarar o corpo do método (porque esse *set* aí em cima é um método disfarçado).

`value` é uma "variável" de contexto. Dentro de um `set` sempre existe esse `value` e ele sempre é do mesmo tipo da propriedade. Ele é o parâmetro do `set` que recebe o valor que você passou com sintaxe de atribuição.

Então usar:

```
objeto.Mes = 3;
```

internamente será algo parecido com

```
objeto.__setMes(3);
```

## Exemplo de uso errado

Um último exemplo para refletir como uma propriedade pode ser errada se ela está tentando substituir um método:

```
class BoxedInt {
    public int Value { set; get; };
}
```

que é o mesmo que:

```
class BoxedInt {
    int value;
    public int Value {
        set { this.value = value; }
        get { return this.value; }
    }
}
```

Parece tudo ok, mas não é bem o que deveria ser. No fundo não temos um propriedade aí. Neste caso quando você quer colocar um valor neste classe é quando você está criando a instância da classe. Portanto o `set` na verdade é o construtor. E quando você está pegando o valor, você está fazendo mais do que pegar um valor, você deveria deixar explícito qual é a operação que está sendo feita que é o desencaixotamento do valor (*unboxing*), então você pede para fazer o `Unbox`. Assim a intenção fica mais explícita:

```
class BoxedInt {
    int value;
    public BoxedInt(int v) { this.value = v; }
    public int Unbox() { return this.value; }
}
```

## Métodos *getter* e *setter*

Em C# não é comum o uso de método só para fazer o `get` e o `set` de valores. Ainda que as propriedades sejam justamente métodos *getter* e *setter*, não criamos métodos mesmo, como ocorre em outras linguagens.

Tem uma [pergunta sobre isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/133924/101) e lá falo que nem sempre a propriedade é útil.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/MethodXProperty.cs).

Answer (score 14):

A resposta do @Maniero já está perfeita, então vou apenas adicionar alguns pontos que considero boas práticas, e fazer notas sobre as já mencionadas:

- propriedades **forçam o get e o set a permanecerem próximos** visualmente... isso é muito bom, pois permite organizar o código de uma forma clara.
- propriedades podem ter **getter e setter com visibilidades distintas**, sendo que é possível fazer propriedades que são somente leitura para o mundo externo, mas que podem ser setadas internamente:

  ```
  public string Nome { get; private set; }
  ```
- propriedades devem ser minimalistas, e na minha opinião, uma propriedades deve no máximo ser usada para **adicionar aspectos a um campo privado**, ou **servirem de atalho**.

  Quando digo aspecto, estou falando de cache, log, validação, mas nunca interferir de forma drástica com esse pressuposto.

  ```
  private string valorCalculado;
  public string ValorCalculado
  {
      get
      {
          // note que esse ainda é uma caso muito banal para se usar cache
          if (valorCalculado == null)
              valorCalculado = "Nome => " + this.Nome + "; Idade => " + this.Idade;
          return valorCalculado;
      }
  }
  ```

  Entretanto não sou a favor de usar propriedades, mesmo com cache, caso a primeira chamada tenha efeitos colaterais, ou que sejam complexas demais. Neste caso, eu prefiro ter um outro método para inicializar o objeto, cuja chamada é obrigatória, antes de usar a propriedade:

  ```
  private string valorCalculado;

  /// <summary>
  /// Obtém o valor calculado do cache. Não esqueça de chamar 'EnsureValorCalculado'
  /// antes de usar esta propriedade.
  /// </summary>
  public string ValorCalculado
  {
      get
      {
          if (valorCalculado == null)
              throw new Exception("Chame o método 'EnsureValorCalculado' antes de usar 'ValorCalculado'.");
          return valorCalculado;
      }
  }

  public void EnsureValorCalculado()
  {
      // obter o valor a ser colocado em cache
  }
  ```

  E finalmente, quando digo atalho, estou falando de obter informações de objetos aninhados, e somente se isso for algo muito importante para o próprio objeto em si:

  ```
  public string Url
  {
      get { return this.Context.HttpContext.Request.Url; }
  }
  ```
- assim como @Maniero, para obter algo que requer complexidade, gosto de criar métodos ao invés de propriedades: `GetComplexData`, ou então `TryGetComplexData` com um parâmetro `out` quando um método pode falhar mais do que excepcionalmente (ou seja, quando a falha é algo comum, exceções ao meu ver devem ser excepcionais)... entre outros padrões.
- sobre campos públicos, não sou a favor, a não ser em classes de **uso restritíssimo**, ou então em structs, sendo que nesse caso sou mais tolerante, mas gosto de manter o uso restrito. Já campos estáticos read-only, não vejo muita coisa contra dependendo do uso. Geralmente uso para criar constantes.

Comment: Também sou a favor de propriedades pequenas usando LINQ, para obter informações de uma coleção... nesse caso, a técnica usando cache é uma boa alternativa.