# Passar argumentos para o getter da propriedade

Tags: c#, vb.net, característica-linguagem, propriedade

O VB.NET permite que você declare parâmetros no getter da propriedade

```
Public ReadOnly Property Propriedade(param As String) As String
  Get
     Return param & "!"
  End Get
End Property
```

É uma característica estranha e no C# não funciona. Qual é a utilidade prática?

E por que utilizar propriedades com parâmetros ao invés de funções, como:

```
Public Function GetFoo(param As String) As String
    Return param & "!"
End Function
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Existe em C# sim. Elas são [propriedades indexadoras](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/using-indexers?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). E portanto servem justamente para ter um indicador de qual o índice de uma coleção de dados está querendo pegar. É possível ter mais de um parâmetro, mas todos deveriam ser índices de uma matriz.

Em VB.NET é um pouco mais flexível porque pode nomear a propriedade e C# não, então é possível ter mais de um indexador. Mas não devem ser usados como propriedades normais. Se tem que passar argumento para o *getter*, ele não é um *getter*. VB.NET tem decisões questionáveis.

Pode ser usado com o *setter* também que acabaria tendo pelo menos dois parâmetros.

Obviamente que isto pode ser abusado e usar da forma mostrada na pergunta, mas não é recomendado, é fora da semântica para o que foi criado. Só deveria ter uma propriedade assim se o tipo sendo criado for uma coleção de dados.

Note que em VB.NET o acesso a coleções é feito com parênteses igual a funções e dá uma impressão errada de que está chamando um método. Em C# não há esta confusão:

```
propriedade[indice]
propriedade[indice] = 1;
```

Então assim como em VB.NET é possível abusar em C#:

```
public int this[int index] {
    get => 42 + index;
    set => WriteLine($"abusei {index}");
}
```

Em C# é possível dar nome para o indexador para outras linguagens que trabalham com nomes verem este nome:

```
[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IndexerName("NomeDoIndexador")]
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Operator/CustomIndex.cs).

Mas ainda não pode ter mais que um. O nome padrão é `Item`.
Já respondi [porque propriedades costumam ser melhores que métodos em certos cenários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15467/101).