# Diferença entre declaração de propriedades em C#

Tags: c#, propriedade, encapsulamento

Estou estudando C#, bem iniciante, e me deparei com uma coisa, o curso que estou fazendo tem video aulas de 2015, e ele me passa para criar uma classe com atributos e propriedades desta forma: (As tabulações e linhas em branco são uma preferência minha para "me achar" no código)

```
class ProgramaTeste {

       protected int _numero;

       public int numero {
              set{ _numero = value; }
              get{ return _numero; }
       }
}
```

Porém, numa outra pergunta aqui no site, me passaram que estas declarações são ultrapassadas e que eu deveria usar desta maneira:

```
class ProgramaTeste {
       public int numero{ get; set: }
}
```

Com certeza é otimizado e melhor, mas isso não compromete o encapsulamento? Pois não estou declarando a variável como protected.

Comment: Não tem nada de ultrapassado ai, se você precisar de um tratamento especial no `get` ou no `set` somente o primeiro exemplo funcionará. Caso não precise de um tratamento especial o segundo exemplo é melhor. Lembrando que se um dia precisar trocar do primeiro para o segundo, conseguirá numa boa.

Comment: Neste caso em especifico, como não tem nenhum tratamento extra antes de atribuir ou retornar, o segundo exemplo é melhor.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15467/m%C3%A9todos-e-propriedades-em-c-vantagens-e-desvantagens/15474#15474

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NO C# 3.0 foi implementado o recurso das **propriedades auto-implementadas** isso nos dá o poder de declarar as propriedades de uma classe de sem nenhuma lógica adicional nos assessores (get e set) das propriedades.

Nos métodos de acesso às propriedades temos os famosos get/set, onde o acessor get é responsável por retornar um valor de um campo privado da classe e o acessor set é responsável por atribuir um novo valor ao campo.

Ao utilizar a sintaxe das propriedades auto-implementadas o compilador C# gera **automaticamente** os campos privados.

Ou seja: utilizando este recurso temos uma redução na quantidade de código necessária para implementarmos as propriedades das nossas classes e o código fica mais claro e legível.

Dê mais uma lida nesta fonte: [Macoratti](http://www.macoratti.net/11/05/c_pai.htm)