# Condição não funciona em um método setter

Tags: c#, .net, condição, getters-setters

Qual o motivo do meu código dar o seguinte erro:

> O operador '>' não pode ser aplicado a operandos dos tipos `decimal` e `double`.

Código:

```
class Funcionario
{
    public string nome { get; set; }
    public string sobrenome { get; set; }
    private decimal salario { get; set; }

    public Funcionario(string Nome, string Sobrenome, decimal Salario)
    {
        nome = Nome;
        sobrenome = Sobrenome;
        salario = Salario;
    }

    public void sal(decimal Salario)
    {
        if (Salario < 0 && Salario > 20.000)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("ArgumentOutOfRangeException");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Porque `20.000` não é o que imagina ser. Se quer um literal de valor monetário e assim poder comparar com um tipo `decimal` deveria usar então `20M`. Não precisa colocar zeros depois da vírgula, mas pode se achar que fica mais legível, dá na mesma.

Além disso não pode ser o operador `&&`, é impossível algo ser menor que 0 e ao mesmo tempo ser maior que 20, um `||` resolve isso, porque é um ou o outro.

Tem certeza que o salário deve ser menor que 20 reais? Ou você queria fazer `20_000M`? Também pode usar sem separador: `20000M`.

Se é um *setter*, então o correto deveria usar o nome `SetSalario()`? Mas se é um *setter* mesmo, não deveria usar uma [propriedade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15467/101)? De fato já criou uma, porque precisa de um *setter*, quando já tem um, implemente nele. E use o [padrão correto de nomenclatura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31646/101).

Mesmo que queira manter assim , não seria melhor usar `Salario()` para deixar claro que é isso e não um ingrediente de comida? Ou pelo menos usar `Sal()` para usar o padrão que é usado em C#? E poderia acertar a nomenclatura correta para o parâmetro também.

A exceção até faz algum sentido em propriedade, embora ela possa ser eliminada, mas se vai usar um método, não seria melhor usar outro mecanismo? Ver [Por que devemos evitar retornar códigos de erro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101) e [É uma boa prática lançar exceção nesses casos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15261/101).

Se ainda insistir em usar uma exceção não seria melhor criar uma específica que indique o que de fato é o erro e não usar uma pronta que indica outra coisa completamente diferente do que acontece ali?

Não entendendo profundamente o que é, para quem serve, qual o sentido de exceções, não seria melhor não usar? Usar algo errado só treina o erro.

Enfim, procure escrever códigos que façam sentido, evite escrever de forma aleatória, vai dar um resultado muito melhor.

Usou `decimal` para valor monetário, mas acho que foi coincidência, os comentários indicam isso. Veja [Qual a forma correta de usar os tipos float, double e decimal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101).

C# 9 dá para fazer tudo isso de uma forma melhor, mas não vou colocar aqui para não confundir mais.

Comment: Após alterar && para || e 20.000 para 20000 o erro cessou. muito obrigado!  (obs: estou um pouco enferrujado no C# e por esse motivo estou refazendo alguns códigos.)

Comment: O erro parou de acontecer, mas o código continua errado, e preciso tirar os parabéns que dei, agora tem um problema que mostrou que usou o `decimal` por coincidência.