# O que "imutável" realmente significa?

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, imutabilidade

Nessa [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14490/alocacao-de-memoria-em-c-tipos-valor-e-tipos-referencia) que fiz a respeito de tipos valor e tipos referência em C#, foi citado na resposta aceita que instâncias de structs devem ser objetos imutáveis. Lendo no [wikipedia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objeto_imut%C3%A1vel) confirmei que um objeto imutável não deveria ter seu estado modificado depois de criado. Mas isso é confuso, porque afinal, se eu declaro uma variável seja de um tipo struct ou um tipo classe, eu posso modificar seu valor a qualquer momento, ou então ela seria uma constante.

Na realidade, `int` é uma struct pelo que sei, então nesse caso se eu declaro uma variável do tipo `int` ela não deveria ser modificada se instâncias de structs são realmente imutáveis. Mas isso claramente não é verdade, eu posso fazer `int i = 1` e depois `i++` e só nisso já mudei o seu estado.

Dessa forma, o que realmente significa "objetos imutáveis" e como esse conceito é um conceito útil em orientação a objetos?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

## Variável X valor

Os valores podem ser mutáveis ou imutáveis, [variáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) que contém valores são sempre, por definição, mutáveis. Variável remete a algo que varia, que muda, que é mutável.

É comum quem escreve sobre o assunto usar uma linguagem mais solta e não tão acadêmica, o que pode levar a um entendimento errado mesmo. Você tem razão na dúvida. É raro quem escreve com todos os detalhes especificados da forma mais correta possível nestes casos. E foi o que eu fiz lá na pergunta. Por isso cabe esta nova pergunta. Então se alguém diz "a variável x é imutável", leia "o conteúdo da variável x é imutável".

## Constantes

Assim como uma constante, por definição, é imutável. Gostaria de dizer que os valores da constante também são sempre imutáveis. Em C# eles são, mas algumas linguagens conseguiram deixar uma constante ter o valor mutável. É um erro conceitual que o C# não cometeu.

Pelo menos o C# deixa claro que `PI` e o `MaxValue` do tipo `int` são constantes. Enquanto que `MaxThreads` e `PercentualDeDesconto` são `readonly`, ou seja, eles não mudam durante toda a execução de uma instância da aplicação, mas pode mudar de uma execução para outra, ou de uma versão para outra. Existem algumas outras diferenças que não vem ao caso agora.

## [Struct X Class](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16181/101)

É altamente recomendado que `struct`s tenham seus valores imutáveis. Isso está na documentação do C#. É muito estranho ter um objeto por valor que seja mutável. Tecnicamente é possível porque **pode** existir alguma situação que isto seja realmente útil e correto.

`Class`es costumam ser mutáveis. Mas não precisam ser. O maior exemplo é a `string` que é um tipo por referência mas que tem semântica de valor, ou seja, seu valor é imutável.

Mas como? Eu posso mudar o valor de uma `string`. Eu posso fazer:

```
var s = "teste";
s = "mudei";
```

Houve uma mudança no valor da variável e não do valor da *string*. Você não trocou o texto, você criou um novo texto e mudou a referência (que está na variável) para este novo texto.

#### Exemplo de imutabilidade

Veja esta `struct`:

```
struct Point {
    public float X;
    public float Y;
}
```

Ela é mutável. Não deveria. Por que?

Você pode mudar o valor de X e de Y independentemente. Você está mudando o valor em si e não a variável. E uma `struct` não deveria permitir isso.

Não é estranho mudar uma parte do ponto sem que ele seja outro ponto?

```
struct Point {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Já muda tudo. A única forma de mudar um valor da variável é mudar completamente o valor contido nela. Neste caso você cria um novo valor e aloca na variável, você não muda o valor alocado nela. Seu uso seria:

```
var p = new Point(2, 5);
// p.x = 7; seria um erro, você nem consegue acessar os membros individualmente.
p = new Point(7, 5);
```

Percebeu que não pode mudar só um membro do valor? **Tem que criar um novo valor e associar esse novo valor com a variável. Isso é imutabilidade**.

Você muda não só o valor, você muda a identidade dele. O ponto cartesiano 2, 5 é diferente do ponto 7, 5, não é o mesmo ponto com uma característica diferente.

Note que se adicionar propriedades públicas para acessar os membros `x` e `y` não causam problema. Mas se permitir atribuir valores para eles, você cai no mesmo problema que o exemplo anterior de `Point`. Então poderia criar uma propriedade apenas com `get`.

## Exemplo de mutabilidade

Agora veja este código:

```
struct Pessoa {
    public string nome; 
    public int idade;
    public Decimal salario;
    public DateTime CadastradaEm;
}

public class Exemplo {
    static void Main() {
        Pessoa p;
        p.nome = "João";
        p.idade = 18;
        Console.WriteLine("{0} tem {1} anos", p.nome, p.idade);
       
        p.idade = 20;
        Console.WriteLine("{0} tem {1} anos", p.nome, p.idade);
    }
}
```

#### Outro problema

Deixando de lado que isto está expondo campos para acesso direto externo (é só um exemplo simplificado, não preciso seguir as tais das "boas práticas" aqui), qual o problema deste código?

Se isto é uma `struct` deveria ser imutável mas este não é o erro. Do jeito que está, é claramente um objeto mutável, você pode mudar os membros individualmente. Nenhum problema. Isso provavelmente é o que você quer neste caso.

Se essa estrutura tem vários campos, ela fica muito grande. Objetos grandes não ficam bem em uma `struct`. Afinal `struct`s são copiadas por valor. Cópias de objetos grandes são ineficientes. Então já temos dois motivos, ineficiência e mutabilidade para dizer que isto deveria ser uma classe. O erro foi definir esta estrutura como `struct` ao invés `class`. Mais detalhes [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/101).

## Identidade

Neste exemplo acima apesar de mudar a idade da pessoa, a pessoa é a mesma, a identidade do objeto é o mesmo, portanto o objeto é mutável. Características do objeto podem ser mudados sem que o objeto se torne outra coisa. Mesmo que você mude o nome de "João" para "Maria" (muito comum hoje em dia :) ) ainda seria a mesma pessoa. Um nome pode ser trocado por vários fatores, como erro de digitação ou mudança de estado civil, só para citar os mais comuns.

Quando você usa o código:

```
var i = 0;
i = 5;
```

Semanticamente é o mesmo que dizer:

```
var i = new Int32(0);
i = new Int32(5);
```

`Int32` é a tal `struct` que equivale ao `int`. Note que cada alteração do valor, você está criando um novo objeto, com identidade equivalente. Por acaso está sendo "guardado" no mesmo local, está substituindo o valor anterior, mas não só a variável mudou, mas o seu valor como um todo mudou.

Então no exemplo:

```
int i = 0;
i++;
```

é o mesmo que:

```
int i = default(Int32); //só para mostrar outra forma de interpretar a mesma coisa
i = new Int32(i + 1);
```

Não quer dizer que o compilador interpreta exatamente assim, mas é uma forma que ajuda entender.

Note que o valor de `i` está sendo mudado como um todo, conforme a definição que eu dei acima.

Em C# 7 é possível usar [`readonly struct`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/write-safe-efficient-code?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que favorece a imutabilidade.

Em C# 9 fica mais fácil adotá-la com o [`init`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/init?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) nas propriedades.

## Conclusão

Parece estranho à primeira vista, mas se olhar a variável em si e seu valor como coisas distintas fica fácil entender que o valor nunca muda, ele é trocado por outro.

A forma mais fácil de entender imutabilidade é olhar se a mudança pode ocorrer em partes do objeto (campos, propriedades, elementos de um *array*, etc.) ou se pode ocorrer apenas no seu todo.

Imutabilidade não precisa se encaixar em nenhuma definição estrita a orientação a objetos. É um conceito aplicado para qualquer paradigma.

O assunto é bem vasto e é algo que poucos entendem corretamente. Eu acho que não entendo tudo corretamente. Mas aqui já tem uma parte importante sobre ele.

[Mais informações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/103460/101) (a pergunta é sobre Java, mas a ideia é a mesma).

## Exercício

Responda se um telefone que tem o DDD (código de área) e o número em si, pode trocar seu DDD e permanecer com a mesma identidade? E ele pode trocar de operadora e manter a sua identidade?

Se você criar uma variável (do tipo) `int` com valor 0 e depois atribuir o valor 0 nela, ela mudou a identidade?

<sub>Respostas no comentário abaixo</sub>

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Other/Immutability.cs)

Comment: Então a ideia de que um objeto de tipo `struct` representa de fato um valor único vem dessa ideia de imutabilidade? Que não faz sentido alterar atributos sozinhos, mas somente manipular o objeto como um todo?

Comment: @user1620696 Acho que respondi na edição. mas basicamente, sim. Responda e depois eu digo se acertou os "exercícios" que deixei :)

Comment: Uma observação importante (e "pedantic" quase): a struct Point, tal qual definida (a versão com fields private), não é estritamente imutável, embora seja "efetivamente imutável". Esse detalhe pode ter implicações significativas em códigos multi-threading (ie, código completamente errado embora aparentemente correto vs código correto). Fora isso, resposta muito boa! Detalhes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16678416/different-between-immutable-and-effectively-immutable-objects

Comment: @BrunoReis bastante relevante para um entendimento mais completo sim. Eu quis simplificar e focar no que era mais importante para a questão.

Comment: Respondendo as perguntas, me parece que alterar o DDD realmente altera a identidade do telefone. Ja alterar a operadora não altera a identidade. E por fim o `int` vai mudar a identidade sim, levando em conta a forma que entendi que o compilador entende atribuições a tipos valor.

Comment: @user1620696 Sobre o telefone é isso mesmo. Na vida real é assim, no modelo, também deve ser. O caso do `int` é mais complicado. Há quem diga que muda a identidade, há quem diga que não muda. De fato sua lógica está correta, por coincidência o valor é o mesmo, mas a identidade é outra. Mas tem gente que diz que se você não consegue ter nada que diferencie a identidade é a mesma. Isso faz sentido também. Então a não ser que alguém me dê uma referência clara sobre isso, eu deixo ambas como verdadeiras. Até porque nesse caso só tem serventia teoricamente. No telefone tem uma mudança prática.

Comment: Essa ideia de um valor se trocado por outro ao invés de ser alterado ficou mais claro agora.

Answer (score 26):

A grande questão que está confusa para você é sobre **o que é um objeto**.

Objeto, *fisicamente* falando, é um espaço alocado na memória para manter sua referência e utilizá-lo no seu código você precisa de uma variável que o referencie. Portanto perceba que existe uma diferença entre objeto que não muda e variável que não muda.

Uma variável que não muda seria uma constante, ao momento que você atribuir um objeto a ela você não pode mais trocar de objeto.

Um objeto que não muda é um objeto imutável, você não pode mudar seus atributos depois de inicializados pela primeira vez, entretanto você pode a qualquer momento criar um novo objeto e atribuí-lo à mesma variável que referenciava o antigo.

Quando você faz `i++` você está criando um novo objeto incrementado de um do objeto anterior e atribuindo esse novo objeto a mesma variável `i`.

---

<sup>Desculpa eu não me aprofundar muito, mas não sei as sintaxes do C#, sei Java onde o conceito é o mesmo.</sup>

Comment: Este assunto envolve um entendimento muito mais sutil e "alto nível", conceitual, de "objetos" em "programação orientada a objetos" do que uma simplificação tal qual "um espaço alocado na memória" e "bytes que mudam ou não mudam". Veja a resposta do bigown acima.

Comment: Mas não acho que a resposta mereça um negativo. Ela é uma simplificação que ajuda quem não está em busca de todos os detalhes. Aparentemente só o OP e eu gostamos dela :)

Comment: Imutabilidade, identidade e igualdade são tópicos que costumam dar nó na cabeça de alguns alunos meus. Gostei das duas respostas. Sei que isso está um pouco longe do que alguns procuram hoje em dia, mas devo muito do que aprendi sobre OO ao *disassembly* do Visual Studio, que mostrava/depurava todas as instruções do código C++.

Answer (score 2):

Escrevi um artigo sobre isto (https://epxx.co/artigos/imutavel.html). A ideia básica é a seguinte: em algumas linguagens, não existe distinção entre "valor de" e "referência a" um objeto. Por exemplo, em Java uma variável de objeto sempre contém uma referência. Idem Delphi, idem Python... Suponha que 5 variáveis contenham o mesmo objeto do tipo A:

```
a = new A("bla"); b = a; c = b; d = c; e = d;
```

Se o objeto for alterado via qualquer variável, todas as 5 variáveis são afetadas, porque todas contêm referências a um mesmo objeto.

Para algumas classes, faz mais sentido comportar-se como um tipo primitivo, como inteiro ou string. Por exemplo, se eu fizer

```
a = 100; b = a; c = b; d = c; e = d;
```

eu realmente espero que, ao fazer b = 200, as demais variáveis permaneçam com o valor 100, não é mesmo? Idem se se tratasse de uma string; quando atribuímos uma variável de string a outra, o que desejamos é realmente uma cópia da string original, não duas variáveis apontando para a mesma string.

Construir a classe de modo a ser imutável depois da construção permite a seus objetos simular este comportamento dos tipos primitivos. Por exemplo, em Java a String é uma classe imutável. Quando eu faço

```
a = "bla"; b = a; c = b;
```

é verdade que num primeiro momento as três variáveis referem-se a um mesmo objeto String. Porém, como é um objeto imutável, o único jeito de alterar o valor de uma variável é atribuindo-lhe outra String completamente nova. Todos os métodos de manipulação de Strings retornam novas Strings, nunca mexem na original.

Por baixo do capô, classes com String usam diversos truques para melhorar seu desempenho, mas sempre mantendo a aparência de imutabilidade. Por exemplo, se fizermos

a = "bla"; a += "ble";

pode ser que a implementação de String verifique quantas referências existem ao objeto "bla". Se houver só uma, então a concatenação de "bla" e "ble" pode modificar a String original. Se houver duas ou mais referências (b, c...), faz-se o "copy-on-write", ou seja, cria-se uma String nova "blable" apenas para a variável "a".