# Qual o uso de uma variável estática ou final em Java?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, variáveis, declaração-de-variável

Qual a diferença da declaração `private static int var_nome` para `private final int var_nome` para `private int var_nome`? Como essas declarações podem influenciar no meu algoritmo?

Comment: Nada contra a resposta do utluiz, ela é muito boa. Mas você queria saber outras coisas sobre o assunto? Deveria ter colocado na pergunta e todo mundo que respondeu teria a oportunidade de atender todas as suas necessidades. Fica difícil adivinhar que você quer mais do que postou.

Comment: A resposta dele ficou bem completa né, ele explicou tudo sobre o assunto. Além do contexto e de varias outras coisas, mas eu entendo sua reclamação e não sei qual seria a melhor resposta para a pergunta, vou avaliar depois, ok?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Resposta do tipo "Aprendendo por Exemplos".

## Modificadores de Visibilidade

A palavra-reservada `private` modifica a forma como as demais classes do seu programa conseguem ver uma classe ou um atributo de classe.

### Classes

Para classes, podemos ter os modificadores:

#### `public`

Todas as demais enxergam.

```java
public class MinhaClasse { ... }
```

#### `private`

Somente classes no mesmo arquivo fonte enxergam. Use isso quando a implementação serve para algum algoritmo interno da classe principal.

```java
public class MinhaClasse {
    private class MinhaClasseInternaPrivada { ... }
}
private class MinhaClassePrivada { ... }
```

Nota: cada arquivo `.java` pode ter apenas uma classe pública.

#### (default)

Somente classes no mesmo arquivo fonte ou no mesmo pacote (*package*) enxergam. Use quando a implementação serve apenas para sua biblioteca ou para uma determinada parte do seu programa.

```java
class MinhaClasse { ... }
```

### Métodos

Métodos podem ter os seguintes modificadores de visibilidade:

#### `public`

Todas as classes o enxergam, desde que enxerguem a classe também.

```java
public class MinhaClasse {
    public void meuMetodo() { }
}
```

#### `private`

Somente classes no mesmo arquivo fonte enxergam. Use isso quando o método é feito apenas para uso dos outros métodos públicos da classe.

```java
public class MinhaClasse {
    private void meuMetodoSecreto() { }
    public void meuMetodoPublico() {
        meuMetodoSecreto();
    }
}
```

Métodos privados não podem ser sobrescritos.

#### `protected`

Métodos protegidos podem ser vistos pelas classes do mesmo pacote ou por subclasses.

```java
public class MinhaClasse {
    protected void meuMetodo() { }
}
```

Use isso se for fazer algum tipo de biblioteca que permita a outro desenvolvedor estender suas classes e então usar esses métodos especiais, os quais não devem ser chamados por outras classes que **usam** a sua biblioteca.

#### (default)

Métodos sem modificador podem ser vistos apenas pelas classes do mesmo pacote.

```java
public class MinhaClasse {
    void meuMetodo() { }
}
```

Use isso quando um método é usado apenas pelas classes que compõe uma parte do seu programa.

### Atributos

Atributos funcionam praticamente como os métodos.

#### `public`

Todas as classes o enxergam, desde que enxerguem a classe também.

```java
public class MinhaClasse {
    public int atributo = 1;
}
```

É uma má prática ter atributos int, a menos que sejam "constantes" ou você queira simular estruturas como da linguagem C.

#### `private`

Somente classes no mesmo arquivo fonte enxergam. Procure deixar todos os seus atributos privados e dar o acesso encasulado a eles através de *getters* e *setters*.

```java
public class MinhaClasse {
    private int atributo = 1;
    public int getAtributo() {
        return atributo;
    }
    public void setAtributo(int atributo) {
        this.atributo = atributo;
    }
}
```

#### `protected`

Atributos protegidos podem ser vistos pelas classes do mesmo pacote ou por subclasses.

```java
public class MinhaClasse {
    protected int atributo = 1;
}
```

#### (default)

Atributos sem modificador podem ser vistos apenas pelas classes do mesmo pacote.

```java
public class MinhaClasse {
    int atributo = 1;
}
```

---

## Modificador `final`

É usado em vários contextos: classes, métodos, atributos e variáveis.

### Classes `final`

Uma classe com este modificador não pode ser estendida, isto é, não pode ter classes que herdam dela.

Isso é importante para garantir que uma determinada implementação não tenha seu comportamento modificado. Isso tem muito a ver com a **imutabilidade**.

Tipos básicos do Java como `String` e `Integer` são `final` porque se espera que o conteúdo não possa ser modificado. O problema é que seu alguém pudesse criar uma subclasses de `String`, esta implementação poderia passar a ser mutável. Uma `String` mutável seria o caos na terra para implementações, pois vários pressupostos que os desenvolvedores usam no dia-a-dia seriam simplesmente desfeitos.

```java
public final class String
     implements java.io.Serializable, Comparable<String>, CharSequence
{ ... }
```

### Método `final`

É um método que não pode ser sobrescrito nas subclasses.

Use para garantir que um determinado algoritmo não possa ser modificado pelas subclasses.

[Exemplo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/final.html):

```java
class ChessAlgorithm {
    enum ChessPlayer { WHITE, BLACK }
    ...
    final ChessPlayer getFirstPlayer() {
        return ChessPlayer.WHITE;
    }
    ...
}
```

### Atributo `final`

Um atributo `final` de uma classe pode ter seu valor atribuído uma única vez, seja na própria declaração ou no construtor.

```java
public class MinhaClasse {
    final int x = 1;
    final int y;

    public MinhaClasse(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Use isso para garantir que um valor ou referência de objeto não vai mudar. Voltamos à **imutabilidade**.

Se você tem um algoritmo que usa esse variável, você pode armazenar valores calculados sem a preocupação do valor mudar.

Exemplo:

```java
public class MinhaClasse {
    final Cliente cliente;
    final BigDecimal saldo;

    public MinhaClasse(Cliente cliente) {

        this.cliente = cliente;

        //sabemos que saldo não muda
        this.saldo = cliente.chamarOperacaoComplexaQueCalculaOSaldo();

    }

    public BigDecimal getSaldoCliente() {
        //não precisa mais recalcular toda vez
        return saldo;
    }
}
```

### Variáveis `final`

Use para garantir que você não está modificando o valor indevidamente.

```java
final boolean a = lerInputUsuario();
final boolean b = lerInputUsuario();
...
if (a = b) //ops!!!
```

No código acima, suponha que o desenvolvedor queria comparar os valores de `a` e `b`, mas faltou um sinal de igual. Sem o `final`, haveria uma atribuição indevida e o resultado seria o valor booleano de `b`. Mas como `n` é `final`, o compilador vai acusar um erro. Acabamos de impedir uma atribuição involuntária!

### Threads e Classes Internas

Outra vantagem de variáveis e atributos `final` é poder usá-los em classes internas, técnica muito usada em Threads.

```java
public class MinhaClasse {

    public void executarEmParalelo(final int limite, final Processamento proc) {
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < limite; i++) {
                    proc.executar();
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
    }
}
```

---

## Modificador `static`

Ele muda o **escopo** de um método ou atributo. Com o `static`, ao invés deles pertencerem à instância do objeto, eles pertencem à classe.

O modificador também pode ser aplicado para classes, como veremos a seguir.

### Métodos `static`

Os métodos `static` podem ser chamados sem uma instância. São ótimos como utilitários.

```java
public final class Integer extends Number implements Comparable<Integer> {
    public static Integer valueOf(String s, int radix) throws NumberFormatException {
        return new Integer(parseInt(s,radix));
    }
}
```

Você pode chamar assim:

```java
Integer valor = Integer.valueOf("FF", 16);
```

Métodos estáticos não podem acessar variáveis de instância.

```java
public class MinhaClasse {
    int valor = 1;
    public static int estatico() {
        return valor; //erro de compilação aqui!!!
    }
}
```

### Atributos `static`

Os atributos `static` possuem o mesmo valor para todas as instâncias de um objeto (dentro de uma mesma JVM, dentro de um mesmo ClassLoader).

```java
public class MinhaClasse {
    static int valorGlobal = 1;
    public static int getValorGlobal() {
        return valorGlobal;
    }
}
```

Então, podemos fazer o seguinte:

```java
MinhaClasse c1 = new MinhaClasse();
MinhaClasse c2 = new MinhaClasse();
MinhaClasse.valorGlobal = 2;
System.out.println(c1); //imprime 2
System.out.println(c2); //imprime 2
```

### Classes `static`

Classes `static` são classes declaradas dentro de outra classe que podem ser usadas sem a necessidade de uma instância.

```java
public class MinhaClasse {
    public static classe ClasseInterna { }
}
```

Então podemos acessar isso assim:

```java
MinhaClasse.ClasseInterna instancia = new MinhaClasse.ClasseInterna();
```

---

## Juntando tudo

Agora que entendemos o que cada coisa faz individualmente, vamos a uma aplicação prática.

### Padrão de Projeto Singleton

Problema: quero garantir uma instância única de um objeto no meu programa.

Solução:

```java
public class MinhaClasse {
    private static MinhaClasse instancia;
    public static MinhaClasse getInstancia() {
        if (instancia == null) {
            intancia = new MinhaClasse();
        } 
        return instancia;
    }
}
```

Uso:

```java
MinhaClasse instancia = MinhaClasse.getInstancia();
```

Isso vai retornar o mesmo valor em todas as chamadas.

Basicamente, o que fizemos foi isso:

1. Criar um atributo chamado `instancia` que só a `MinhaClasse` pode ver (`private`) e contém sempre o mesmo valor (`static`).
2. Criar um método que pode ser chamado diretamente pela classe, sem precisar da instância (`static`).
3. Então, o método estático retorna o valor estático, que será sempre o mesmo.

Comment: Ótima explicação Chefe, ajudou muito!

Comment: Acho que você deveria arrumar isto: "*É uma má prática ter atributos int, a menos que sejam "constantes" ou você queira simular estruturas como da linguagem C.*" - Já teve gente que não entendeu exatamente o que você queria: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/132272/132 - Eu acho que você queria dizer "*atributos públicos*" ao invés de "*atributos int*". Correto?

Answer (score 25):

Como você está usando `private` vou entender que esteja falando de campos de uma classe e não de variáveis.

Um **campo estático** é aquele que está **disponível em uma classe de forma única** para toda a aplicação. Ele não está vinculado a uma instância da classe. Ele pertence a classe em si e é compartilhado por todas as instâncias (objetos) desta classe criadas durante a execução da aplicação.

Um **campo final** é aquele que **não pode ter seu conteúdo alterado depois de inicializado**. Podemos entender como um campo somente de leitura. O valor do campo é inicializado para cada instância da classe no momento da sua criação e obviamente cada objeto pode ter este campo com valor diferente. O conteúdo pode ser inicializado por um construtor ou por atribuição direta. Se o campo contém uma referência, apenas a referência não pode ser modificada, o conteúdo do objeto referenciado pode. Portanto o `final` não garante por si só a [imutabilidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15510/o-que-imutavel-realmente-significa/15512#15512) do objeto.

Como estes campos estão, no exemplo, declarados apropriadamente como privados, uma modificação, ou mesmo o acesso fora da classe só pode acontecer através de métodos de acesso, por exemplo `getNome` e `setNome`.

Você pode ter uma declaração de campo que seja **estático e final** ao mesmo tempo. Neste caso temos um **campo constante**. Já que você tem uma valor único para toda a aplicação e ele não pode ser modificado. Com `static final` o compilador Java pode substituir o uso do campo pelo seu valor em tempo de compilação alcançando uma otimização.

Quando nem `static` nem `final` estão presentes na declaração do campo, ele tem seu valor individualizado para cada instância da classe e seu valor pode ser modificado.

Existem métodos estáticos que podem acessar campos estáticos. Os métodos estáticos podem servir de acessadores para um campo privado estático. mas se além de estático o campo for final, normalmente pode-se deixar o campo exposto publicamente. Pelo menos se você tem certeza que a semântica dele é de uma constante real e nunca será alterado. Um bom exemplo de campo estático final com semântica de constância é o `PI`. Um exemplo de não constância seria o `MaxThreads` (um dia isso pode mudar, portanto não é realmente constante).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Como um campo estático pode ser privado?

Comment: Nesse caso, só no interior da classe é que ele é acessível. Ninguém citou, mas podemos ter métodos estáticos também. Logo um atributo `static final` pode ser acessado por dentro de métodos estáticos e métodos de instância também.

Comment: @Patrick E qual o problema? Não posso garantir que o Java permite isto (seria muito estranho não permitir), mas não há motivo para não permitir. Apenas membros da classe podem acessá-lo. Me parece um padrão comum em várias situações.

Comment: Java permite campos estáticos privados sim.

Comment: @Piovezan Eu tinha quase certeza, se não permitisse, eu procuraria uma matador profissional para ir atrás do Gosling :)

Comment: Se apenas membros da classe podem acessá-lo, qual o sentido de colocar estático?

Comment: @Patrick, é muito comum utilizar atributos `static final` para configurações. Por exemplo: https://github.com/TheFinestArtist/SimpleYouTubePlayer/blob/master/src/com/thefinestartist/simpleyoutubeplayer/YouTubePlayerActivity.java

Comment: @Patrick acessibilidade nada tem a ver com a propriedade do campo. São conceitos diferentes. Um método estático pode precisar de um estado para sua execução. Um método não pode ter estado. Onde você vai colocar o estado? Em um campo. Se o método é estático, provavelmente você vai querer um estado estático (compartilhado, único).

Comment: `public class Cachorro { private static final String NOME_PADRAO = "Totó"; private String nome; public Cachorro() { this.nome = NOME_PADRAO; } public Cachorro(String nome) { this.nome = nome; } public String getNome() { return this.nome; } }`

Comment: Nota: o exemplo acima está incompleto, mas faz sentido se a variável `NOME_PADRAO` for reutilizada dentro da classe `Cachorro`, por exemplo (forçando a barra um pouco no exemplo) em um método `public boolean isViraLata() { return NOME_PADRAO.equals(nome); }`

Answer (score 17):

O modificador `final` em variáveis quer dizer que você não pode atribuir valor duas vezes à variável.

O modificador `static` quer dizer que a variável pertence à classe, não ao objeto; isso quer dizer que ela pode ser acessada sem necessidade de uma instância (por exemplo, se for privada, todas as instâncias da classe enxergam a mesma variável e, se uma delas modificar o valor, isso vai se refletir em todas as outras instâncias).

Para se declarar uma constante usa-se os dois modificadores porque o mesmo valor vai ser visto por todas as instâncias da classe (`static`) e nunca vai poder ser modificado depois de inicializado (`final`).

Variáveis que não são nem `static` nem `final` são campos normais de um objeto, e que portanto variam de objeto para objeto, por exemplo:

```
public class Pessoa {
   private String nome; // será diferente para cada objeto
   ...
}
```

Adaptado de [um tópico do Javafree](http://javafree.uol.com.br/topic-10740-Definicao-de-static-e-final.html).

Comment: Perfeito! Bela resposta!

Answer (score -2):

Olá, pessoal.

Segue uma explicação genérica sobre a diferença de "static" e "final". Caso haja dúvidas ou tenham alguma correção a fazer, só comentar aqui.

Antes da explicação teórica, observem os exemplos a seguir:

Classe Static:

```
public class Static {
    static int idade = 20;
    }
```

Classe Final:

```
public class Final {

    final double altura = 1.56;
}
```

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Static.idade = 18;
        System.out.println(Static.idade);

        Final joaoCarlos = new Final();
        Final anaLeticia = new Final();
        System.out.println(joaoCarlos.altura);
        System.out.println(anaLeticia.altura);
    }
}
```

Com **static** não se cria um objeto, porque o modificador "static" permite apenas um endereço de memória para o objeto.
Esse endereço está na **classe Static**, por isso quando eu chamo o atributo "idade" não preciso criar mais um endereço de memória, pois há apenas UM atributo "idade".
Cada vez que crio um objeto ou instancio uma classe, estou alocando novos endereços na memória do meu programa.
Mas isso não me impede de mudar o valor do meu atributo ou método aqui na Main,
pois estou apenas alterando um valor e não criando um objeto ou ocupando um espaço a mais na memória.

O **final** é como se fosse um baú valioso com um cadeado que se perdeu a chave, pois existe um tesouro ali (um valor) que não pode ser retirado (alterado). Mas, eu posso criar vários objetos com o mesmo valor. Por exemplo, Ana Leticia tem 1.56 metros de altura, mas não é só ela no mundo que possui essa altura. João Carlos também tem esse mesmo valor.
Sendo assim, é possível criar vários objetos com o "final", mas não se pode alterá-los.

Portanto, o modificador **static** permite alterar o valor do seu atributo ou método, mas o **final** não. Além disso, o **static** não permite que você crie um ou mais objetos, mas o **final** sim.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).