# Diferença entre private static final e private final para o uso da imutabilidade

Tags: java

Um atributo quando declarado com o modificador ***static*** tem a característica de "propagar o seu valor" por todas as instâncias da classe a que pertence, ou seja o seu valor será o mesmo para todas as instâncias. Devido a essa característica estes atributos recebem o nome de variáveis de classe. Estes possuem o seu valor armazenado em um [endereço fixo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) de memória. Eis um exemplo:

```
class Foo {
    public static int count = 0 ;
    Foo() { 
        ++count;
    }
}
```

Um outro uso para o modificador static é quando queremos tornar um atributo imutável, inalterável, conseguido a partir da adição do modificador final, como no exemplo a seguir:

```
class Carro {
    private static final int RODAS = 4;
    ...
}
```

O mesmo resultado temos quando declaramos o atributo sem o modificador static, somente com o modificador final.

```
class Carro {
    private final int RODAS = 4;
    ...
}
```

Em ambas as instruções conseguimos o mesmo objetivo, o de tornar o valor de um atributo imutável. Diante disso, qual a vantagem real em usar o modificador static na criação de variáveis imutáveis? Existe algum ganho real relacionado a desempenho?

Comment: Acho que já foi respondido aqui http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/17136/101 Ou não?

Comment: Só para colocar algo específico: imutabilidade e alcance de uma variável são coisas ortogonais. `static` define que aquilo existirá para todas instâncias da classe. Ponto. Se tem `final` ou não é irrelevante para esta questão. `final` define que o valor não pode ser alterado. Um não depende ou está relacionado com o outro.

Comment: @bigown, você está certo, resposta está no link que você passou. Mas a resposta que procurava não é a que foi marcada como correta neste, e sim, a que você postou no mesmo.

Comment: A pergunta deveria ser relacionada a imutabilidade. Você está certo.

Comment: O meu interesse com o post era saber a diferença entre as duas abordagens para chegar a imutabilidade; com o uso do modificador static e sem o seu uso, por meio do modificador final.

Comment: Eu também achei que a minha respondia melhor :) Mas a aceitação é um critério de cada um e a aceita estava mais completa em termos gerais. Como ninguém respondeu ainda, eu acho que não seria problema mudar a pergunta. Mas não sei se realmente haveria diferença. O `static` não tem **nenhuma** relação com a imutabilidade.

Answer (score 9):

Há algumas premissas falsas na sua pergunta:

> *"Em ambas as instruções [**static** e **final**] conseguimos o mesmo objetivo, o de tornar o valor de um atributo imutável."*

O objetivo de **static** não é implementar imutabilidade mas sim o de declarar o membro (método, "campo", "propriedade", "atributo"...) em uma classe em vez de publicar em um objeto (uma instância da classe).

Você pode ter confundido **static** com imutável ao tomar conhecimento de que uma vez atribuído um valor a um membro estático, a referência permanecerá ao longo de todo o ciclo de vida do aplicativo - o objeto referenciado nunca será recolhido pelo *garbage collector* enquanto o aplicativo estiver rodando.

Mas este membro estático não é imutável, uma vez que a qualquer momento você pode atribuir outro valor a ele (mudar sua referência para a de outro objeto) ou mesmo mudar o estado do objeto que ele referencia.

A palavra chave **final** sim, esta **ajuda** a implementar objetos imutáveis já que só se pode atribuir valor ao membro "final" uma única vez, e já que o compilador exige que este valor seja atribuído já no construtor da classe (caso não tenha sido atribuído já na própria declaração do membro estático).

Então, respondendo diretamente as perguntas:

- **"Qual a vantagem real em usar o modificador static na criação de variáveis imutáveis?"** - Resposta: nenhuma.
- **"Existe algum ganho real relacionado a desempenho?"** - Reposta: não.
- **"Diferença entre private static final e private final para o uso da imutabilidade."** - Resposta: nenhuma diferença no que tange à imutabilidade da variável.

Comment: Caffé, acho que fui mal compreendido. Nos dois exemplos que dei ocorre imutabilidade, justamente pela existência do modificador final nas instruções. Em ambos, a tentativa de alteração do valor da variável RODAS retornará o erro "cannot assign a value to final variable PORTAS" pelo compilador.

Comment: @GeisonSantos Editei a resposta tentando adicionar respostas diretas às suas perguntas.

Answer (score 0):

Quando não utilizar static irá ter a variável criada para cada instância do objeto, já usando o static ela será criada uma única vez (ela será da classe e não da instância). O quanto isso vai impactar em seu sistema depende de muitos outros fatores.

Answer (score 0):

A diferença entre static e final é a seguinte:
Exemplo   private static final int A = 10;
private static int B = 15;

```
      Suponha que a classe que você declarou essas variáveis chama-se (Test)
      ao criar um objeto a partir dessa classe sua variável do tipo static final
      não pode ser alterada o valor por exemplo você não pode fazer isso 
      Test test = new Test(); 
      test.setA(20); Você não consegue mudar o valor da variável.
       
      Já na variável somente static você pode mudar o valor
      Exemplo Test test = new Test();
      test.setB(20); Você consegue altear o valor da variável
      Isso é possível porém se você instanciar outro objeto com outro valor 
      por exemplo Test test2 = new Test();
      test2.setB(30);
      vai prevalecer o valor do ultimo objeto instanciado.
      e test.setB(20); deixa de existir.
      você não pode ter mais de um objeto com valores diferente quando é do 
      tipo statico.
```